# Grepping through an entire texmf tree

Tags: texmf

I always forget the syntax of command-line tools for searching through multiple files. What's the easiest/fastest way to search through, say, all of the `.sty` files distributed in TeX Live for the occurrence of a string, say, `\everypar`? (Let's assume Linux/Mac OS X.)

Comment: hmmm. off topic?

Comment: This isn't really a TeX related question. But `find` is your friend here.

Comment: This would be answered in 5 seconds flat over at stackoverflow...

Comment: I'm certainly not going to argue that this doesn't toe the line of being off-topic. But it's a tool I'd like to have in my belt for LaTeX development, so I figured I'd see if anyone's done this before.

Comment: You don't need find. Just `grep -r --include=*.sty "\\everypar" <DIR>` (Need to escape the backslash.)

Comment: +1 from me: I think that a lot of more advanced TeX users need something like this. Its a bit of a duplicate of [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3777/). I once needed something like this for ConTeXt and wrote the [ConTeXt source browser](http://source.contextgarden.net/).

Comment: I think this has a nice on-topic component-- how do you get a list of every `texmf` folder that should be searched for sty files? Not every distribution sets a value for `TEXMF` in the login shell.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I'm using a script called `texgrep` like this:

```
texgrep everypar sty
```

backslashes should be quoted. Here's the source of the script:

**Search pattern:**

```
#!/bin/bash
# texgrep - searches for a text pattern contained in files
#   located inside the texmf trees
# usage: texgrep pattern [extension]
# usage examples:
#   texgrep phantomsection sty
#   texgrep \\\\def\\\\phantomsection
if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
  echo 1>&2 Usage: texgrep pattern [extension]
  exit 1
fi
for path in TEXMFMAIN TEXMFDIST TEXMFHOME
do
 find `kpsewhich --var-value=$path` -type f -name "*$2" |xargs grep $1
done
exit 0
```

It's valuable for me because I like to read sources and this saves me time. I've put the script on my blog some time ago: [Speed up the work by shell scripts](http://texblog.net/latex-archive/linux/shell-scripts-linux-unix/).

More scripts related to search & work:

**Search and edit:**

```
#!/bin/bash
# texedit - find one or several tex related files
#   and open them in the editor
if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
  echo 1>&2 Usage: texedit file1 [file2] ...
  exit 1
fi
gedit `kpsewhich $@`
exit 0
```

**Search and look around:**

```
#!/bin/bash
# texls - list the content of the directory
#   corresponding to a certain tex related file
if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
  echo 1>&2 Usage:    texls filename [pattern]
  echo 1>&2 examples: texls babel.sty
  echo 1>&2           texls book.cls *clo
  exit 1
fi
ls `kpsewhich $1 | sed 's/\(.*\)\/.*$/\1\//'`$2
exit 0
```

**Search and change to directory:**

```
#!/bin/bash
# texcd - change into the directory
#   corresponding to a certain tex related file
if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
  echo 1>&2 Usage:    . texcd filename [pattern]
  echo 1>&2 examples: . texcd beamer.cls
  exit 1
fi
cd `kpsewhich $1 | sed 's/\(.*\)\/.*$/\1/'`
echo Changed to: `pwd`
```

All could be done by shell functions instead of scripts. Like Michael suggested in my blog:

```
function texcd ()
{
cd $(dirname "$(kpsewhich "$1")");
}
```

I hope it's useful for somebody, even though it goes beyond the question.

Comment: These are great! Briefly trying Willie's suggestion to use grep instead of find seems to show a significant speedup, if you're interested.

Answer (score 3):

Well, my command lines tend to be quite verbose, but I think you could search for all occurances of `foo` in `sty` files on `$TEXMF` by:

```
for texmf in `kpsewhich -expand-path '$TEXMF' | sed 's/:/ /g'`; do 
  find $texmf | grep '\.sty$' | xargs -J% grep -n 'foo' %; 
done
```

Now that I've had my morning vat o' coffee (and read some comments), a more concise version would be:

```
grep -r --include=*.sty -n '\\everypar' `kpsewhich -expand-path '$TEXMF' | sed 's/:/ /g'`
```

Answer (score 2):

This is what I do:

```
ack --tex '\\everypar' /opt/texlive2010
```

has really nice output (and a TextMate bundle as well - but that's not the question) and is quite fast. Make sure you've got everything you need in the `--tex` part by setting in the `~/.ackrc` or on the command line something like this:

```
--type-set=tex=.tex,.sty
```

(you should also include `.mkiv` and `.mkii`, you know ;-))

Comment: I forgot: `ack` is a replacement for `grep -r`. See [the ack homepage](http://betterthangrep.com/) for more info.

Comment: A speed [comparison](http://incise.org/searching-for-a-good-grep.html) of different grep alternatives

Comment: Never seen such a crappy comparison.

Answer (score 1):

It is slightly easier for ConTeXt. Just enter your search phrase in the search box [here](http://source.contextgarden.net/)