# List of Plain TeX macros

Tags: plain-tex, documentation, primitives

Where can I get a list of all Plain TeX macros. In the TeXbook, it is said that Plain TeX adds about 600 macros (to the ~300 TeX primitives). Where are they listed (with their documentation)?

Comment: the texbook is the documentation, the full text of plain tex is in appendix B

Comment: You are right. I did not have a copy of the texbook nearby when I wrote that question. If you make your comment an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: @erreka: The [linked question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4418/is-there-a-printable-version-of-a-reference-manual-for-all-tex-primitives) is about TeX primitives (e.g. [this list](https://www.tug.org/utilities/plain/cseq.html)), while this question is about (non-primitive) macros added by the `plain` format. (E.g. `\quad`, `\nobreak`, `\centerline` etc., which are macros added by `plain`, and you won't find them on the list of primitives.)

Comment: @ShreevatsaR Maybe the question but not the answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The texbook is the documentation, the full text of plain tex is in appendix B

Comment: +1. Possibly worth adding, the source of `plain.tex` is also available [on Knuth's site](https://cs.stanford.edu/~knuth/plain.tex), [on](https://ctan.org/pkg/plain) [CTAN](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/plain/base), and on your local TeX installation (`kpsewhich plain`), though of course without the documentation that is in Appendix B of the TeXbook.

Answer (score 2):

You'll find a capsule summary of commands, primitive and Plain, in chapter 13 of [TeX for the Impatient](http://ctan.org/pkg/impatient); chapters 5-9 are more detailed descriptions of the primitives.