# Feynman Diagrams with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, feynman

I am trying to find some example code for some very simple [Feynman diagrams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feynman_diagram). Something similar to any or all of the pictures below

[image: Simple Feynman diagrams]

I was able to find some example code [on texample.net](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/feynman-diagram/), but being new to TikZ I am not really able to tweak it to produce something simple like the examples above. I would appreciate any help :).

EDIT: I managed to get the code down to a smaller example that is close to what I want:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing,decorations.markings,trees}
\begin{document}

    \tikzset{
    photon/.style={decorate, decoration={snake}, draw=red},
    particle/.style={draw=blue, postaction={decorate},
        decoration={markings,mark=at position .5 with {\arrow[draw=blue]{>}}}},
    antiparticle/.style={draw=blue, postaction={decorate},
        decoration={markings,mark=at position .5 with {\arrow[draw=blue]{<}}}},
    gluon/.style={decorate, draw=black,
        decoration={snake,amplitude=4pt, segment length=5pt}}
     }

\begin{tikzpicture}[
        thick,
        % Set the overall layout of the tree
        level/.style={level distance=1.5cm},
        level 2/.style={sibling distance=3.5cm},
    ]
    \coordinate
        child[grow=left]{
            edge from parent [gluon]
            child {
                edge from parent [particle]
                node [above] {$g$}
            }
            child {
                edge from parent [antiparticle]
                node [below] {$g$}
            }
            node [above=3pt] {$g$}
         }
        % I have to insert a dummy child to get the tree to grow
        % correctly to the right.
        child[grow=right, level distance=0pt] {
            child {
                edge from parent [antiparticle]
                node [above] {$g$}
            }
            child {
                edge from parent [particle]
                node [below] {$g$}
            }
        };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

However, if instead of the coil decoration for the gluon, I want a straight dashed line, I change the line

```
gluon/.style={decorate, draw=black,
        decoration={snake,amplitude=4pt, segment length=5pt}}
```

for

```
gluon/.style={draw=black,dashed}
```

However, this makes the two particles to the left of the gluon become dashed as well. Can someone suggest a way to fix this?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) You don't have to sign with your name since it automatically appears in the lower right corner of your post.

Comment: Thanks for the welcome :). So it does. I'll take a read through your link.

Comment: Oh, no big issue. And again: welcome to TeX.sx!

Comment: @KyleB What in particular do you want to tweak on the texample?

Comment: I suppose mostly I was simply hoping for some hep understanding the code itself, and perhaps have someone use something similar to generate one of the pictures in my post so that I can see how it behaves. The syntax of tikz has a pretty steep learning curve, so seeing examples helps a lot.

Comment: @Kyle B, check this question for resources about learning tikz. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9116/what-is-the-minimum-one-needs-to-know-to-use-tikz

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I understand it, the "dashed" style option is a shorthand that sets `/tikz/dash pattern` to a dashed style (PGF manual v2.1, p157).  That then stays in effect for the rest of the path, until you change the dash pattern again.  Because the other styles don't specify the dash pattern, they'll keep using whatever was in effect.  Try adding "solid" to the definitions of (anti-)particle and gluon, and it should work.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I will give it a shot then I get back to work Monday.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if you are interested, but if you only need to draw "standard" diagrams you can take a look at the `feynmf` package which is designed just for that!

Comment: I have looked, but it seems that it needs quite a bit of extra work on top of just setting up the figure, so I was hoping for something easier with tikz. On the other hand, you may be right. I will look around for resources on the subject.