# Package for typesetting Feynman diagrams (efficiency of `feynmp` and `tikz`)

Tags: tikz-pgf, packages, metapost, feynmf, feynman

> **This question led to a new package:**
>   [`TikZ-Feynman`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz-feynman)

Is there any good package for typesetting lots of [Feynman diagrams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feynman_diagram)?

My question arise because [Feynmp: Circle with three vertices](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86317/feynmp-circle-with-three-vertices) lead me take a look at the documentation for the `feynmf`/`feynmp` package, and didn't like the package very much. In my opinion this package has several draw-backs: it doesn't work with `pdflatex` unless you get help from `@egreg` ([How to use kile with feynmf or feynmp?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20241/how-to-use-kile-with-feynmf-or-feynmp)), the notation is not very intuitive (what do `left=.5` mean?), etc.

I thought that there must be some better package for typesetting Feynman diagram (e.g. something that builds on TikZ rather than `metapost`), but CTAN gave me only [this](http://www.ctan.org/search/?search=feynman&search_type=description).

So do you know something better than `feynmp`?

---

**EDIT:**

Since @cmhughes comment suggest to use `tikz` rather than `feynmp` (and no one has suggested any other packages), the questions are this:

- *Which package is most efficient for typesetting Feynman diagrams, `feynmp` or `tikz`?*
- *Which package produces the best (this means the most beautiful) results?*

In order for `tikz` to really compete with `feynmp` (on this particular battlefield), the code must be approximately as simple as with `feynmp`, and the results must be at least as good. Below you will find some examples of Feynman diagrams made using `feynmp`. How can you typeset diagrams as simple as possible using `tikz`?

[image: Feynman Diagrams]

Code:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{feynmp}

\begin{document}
\unitlength=1mm 
\centering

\begin{fmffile}{photon} % Tree-level interaction
\begin{fmfgraph*}(40,25)
\fmfkeep{photon}
\fmfleft{i1,i2}
\fmfright{o1,o2}
\fmf{fermion}{i1,v1,i2}
\fmf{fermion}{o1,v2,o2}
\fmf{photon}{v1,v2}
\end{fmfgraph*}
\end{fmffile}
~
\begin{fmffile}{gluon}
\begin{fmfgraph*}(40,25)
\fmfleft{i1,i2}
\fmfright{o1,o2}
\fmf{fermion}{i1,v1,i2}
\fmf{fermion}{o1,v2,o2}
\fmf{gluon}{v1,v2}
\end{fmfgraph*}
\end{fmffile}

\plainbreak{1}

\begin{fmffile}{self} % Self-interaction
\begin{fmfgraph*}(40,25)
\fmfleft{i}
\fmfright{o}
\fmf{plain}{i,v1}
\fmf{fermion}{v1,v2}
\fmf{plain}{v2,o}
\fmf{photon,left}{v1,v2}
\end{fmfgraph*}
\end{fmffile}
~
\begin{fmffile}{loop} % Loop correction
\begin{fmfgraph*}(40,25)
\fmfkeep{loop}
\fmfleft{i1,i2}
\fmfright{o1,o2}
\fmf{fermion}{i1,v1,i2}
\fmf{fermion}{o1,v4,o2}
\fmf{photon}{v1,v2}
\fmf{photon}{v3,v4}
\fmf{fermion,right,tension=.2}{v2,v3,v2}
\end{fmfgraph*}
\end{fmffile}

\begin{fmffile}{penguin} % Penguin?
\begin{fmfgraph*}(70,80)
\fmftop{t1,t2}
\fmfbottom{b1,b2}
\fmf{fermion}{t1,v1}
\fmf{fermion}{v2,t2}
\fmf{fermion,tension=.5}{v1,v3,v2}
\fmf{boson,tension=.5}{v1,v2}
\fmf{gluon}{v3,v4}
\fmf{fermion}{b1,v4,b2}
\end{fmfgraph*}
\end{fmffile}

\end{document}
```

Please, note that [Feynman Diagrams with tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22622/feynman-diagrams-with-tikz) and [texample: Feynman diagram](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/feynman-diagram/) do not answer this question.

Comment: I'd use `tikz` or `PSTricks` :)

Comment: It should be possible to use only Lua for those pictures which require it using the `external` library from TikZ. You’ll probably need to adjust the preamble a little bit (encoding, fonts, etc.).

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel - The point should be to avoid Lua completely, since most physicists, I know, don't use Lualatex at all. Actually, I (hardly) never use it myself, and frankly I have no desire to do so, if I can avoid it (call me stubborn).

Comment: I actually prefer feynmp over tikz since the feynmp diagrams look nicer (in my opinion). The syntax and compiling procedure is certainly annoying (Makefiles are good for this), but it works fine with pdflatex and lualatex.

Comment: @xvtk have you ever heard about [`feynmp-auto`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/feynmp-auto) package?

Comment: @xvtk - You can make Feynman diagrams with TikZ, that look just like those produced by `feynmp`, if that's what you desire, but it has a tendency to be somewhat more tedious task. Especially, if have a lot of diagrams.

Comment: @giordano - I have not. Will look into it.

Comment: @Ipsen - The TikZ diagrams are close, but there are some subtle differences. To me it matters, but most people don't mind.

Comment: @xvtk - Could you please specify some of these subtle differences.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The CVS version of TikZ contains a graph layout library, which works surprisingly well for this. Here are a couple of your examples. The syntax could be shortened (`f` instead of `fermion`, for example), this is just to show the idea:

```
\graph [spring layout, nodes=coordinate, horizontal'=c to d]
{
c -- [fermion] a,
b --[fermion] c -- [photon] d,
e -- [fermion] d -- [fermion] f;
};
```

[image]

---

```
\graph [spring layout, nodes=coordinate, horizontal'=c to d]
{
c -- [fermion] a,
b --[fermion] c -- [gluon] d,
e -- [fermion] d -- [fermion] f;
};
```

[image]

---

```
\graph [spring layout, anchor at={(0,-4)}, nodes=coordinate, horizontal'= b to d]
{
a -- [fermion] b -- [fermion] c,
b -- [photon] d -- [left, fermion] e -- [left, fermion] d,
e -- [photon] f -- [fermion] g,
h -- [fermion] f;
};
```

[image]

---

```
\graph [spring layout, anchor at={(0,-5)}, nodes=coordinate, vertical= e to f]
{
a -- [fermion] b -- [photon] c -- [fermion] d,
b -- [fermion] e -- [fermion] c,
e -- [gluon]  f,
h -- [fermion] f -- [fermion] i
};
```

[image]

---

There are some issues with decorating curved paths using waves, and the coils decoration sometimes ends with a straight path segment, but that could be fixed.

Here's the complete code (requires `lualatex`).

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt, border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations, decorations.markings, decorations.pathmorphing, arrows, graphs, graphdrawing, shapes.geometric, snakes}
\usegdlibrary{trees,force, layered}

\pgfdeclaredecoration{complete sines}{initial}
{
    \state{initial}[
        width=+0pt,
        next state=sine,
        persistent precomputation={\pgfmathsetmacro\matchinglength{
            \pgfdecoratedinputsegmentlength / int(\pgfdecoratedinputsegmentlength/\pgfdecorationsegmentlength)}
            \setlength{\pgfdecorationsegmentlength}{\matchinglength pt}
        }] {}
    \state{sine}[width=\pgfdecorationsegmentlength]{
        \pgfpathsine{\pgfpoint{0.25\pgfdecorationsegmentlength}{0.5\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}}
        \pgfpathcosine{\pgfpoint{0.25\pgfdecorationsegmentlength}{-0.5\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}}
        \pgfpathsine{\pgfpoint{0.25\pgfdecorationsegmentlength}{-0.5\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}}
        \pgfpathcosine{\pgfpoint{0.25\pgfdecorationsegmentlength}{0.5\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}}
}
    \state{final}{}
}

\tikzset{
    photon/.style={
        decoration={complete sines, amplitude=0.15cm, segment length=0.2cm},
        decorate    
    },
    fermion/.style={
        decoration={
            markings,
            mark=at position 0.5 with {\node[transform shape, xshift=-0.5mm, fill=black, inner sep=1pt, draw, isosceles triangle]{};}
        },
        postaction=decorate
    },
    gluon/.style={
        decoration={coil, aspect=0.75, mirror, segment length=1.5mm},
        decorate
    }, 
    left/.style={
        bend left=90,
        looseness=1.75
    }
}

\begin{document}%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\graph [spring layout, nodes=coordinate, horizontal'=c to d]
{
c -- [fermion] a,
b --[fermion] c -- [photon] d,
e -- [fermion] d -- [fermion] f;
};

\graph [spring layout, anchor at={(0,-2)}, nodes=coordinate, horizontal'=c to d]
{
c -- [fermion] a,
b --[fermion] c -- [gluon] d,
e -- [fermion] d -- [fermion] f;
};

\graph [spring layout, anchor at={(0,-4)}, nodes=coordinate, horizontal'= b to d]
{
a -- [fermion] b -- [fermion] c,
b -- [photon] d -- [left, fermion] e -- [left, fermion] d,
e -- [photon] f -- [fermion] g,
h -- [fermion] f;
};

\graph [spring layout, anchor at={(0,-5)}, nodes=coordinate, vertical= e to f]
{
a -- [fermion] b -- [photon] c -- [fermion] d,
b -- [fermion] e -- [fermion] c,
e -- [gluon]  f,
h -- [fermion] f -- [fermion] i
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

Comment: These are quite nice diagrams and I like how relatively simple the code for a diagram is. However, I don't have a clue how I could get this running in my own TeX setup. Could you please expand a little (or give a reference) on how to install this CVS version and why you need lualatex? I'm running openSUSE 12.1 with texlive 2011-1.1.2 and tikz v2.10 and I'm afraid that setting this up will take a lot of work and time. And collaboration with others would probably be impossible. Isn't there a way of achieving the same result with a lower tikz version and pdflatex?

Comment: @Lemming: This code need `lualatex` because the graph layout library in the CVS version needs to do some pretty difficult calculations (which lua can do, but the normal pdflatex can't). You can draw the diagrams using a lower version of TikZ, but then you won't get the automatic layout.

Comment: Thanks, okay I guess I'll just wait for the next release of tikz and use manual labour until then. I was able to create a diagram using code like [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/106046/6771). However, I failed to create a diagram with a semicircle over a straight line. Like [here](http://ars.els-cdn.com/content/image/1-s2.0-S0921452609004682-gr1.jpg). I tried `arc`, but it doesn't connect to the correct node. Do you know a good reference for that? I don't have too much time in the moment. But, otherwise I'll make a proper question of that issue when I have time.

Comment: @Jake, when I try to run your example I get a `memoization table filled incorrectly` error from `Path.lua`. Any idea what the problem is?

Comment: I've also tried with latest in TeXLive and CVS and it doesn't work. Something about using `node=coordinate` breaks it (although not using this option looks ugly).

Comment: Looking further into it, it seems to be a result of the following bug: http://sourceforge.net/p/pgf/bugs/319/

Comment: I have found [a fix](https://github.com/JP-Ellis/PGF-TikZ/commit/b580a91) for this bug, and I have created a small package based on this answer if anyone is interested: [tikz-feynman](http://jp-ellis.github.io/tikz-feynman/).  PS: I have tried contacting the developers behind TikZ in many different ways, but none of them have responded regarding this fix...

Comment: What does "CVS version of TikZ" mean? What is CVS? Googling TikZ + CVS doesn't make me a whole lot wiser.

Answer (score 26):

The answer by Jake inspired me to write Ti*k*Z-Feynman, a dedicated package that uses TikZ' graph drawing library in order to draw Feynman diagrams.  It has just recently been uploaded to [CTAN](https://ctan.org/pkg/tikz-feynman) and you can view more information over on the [project page](http://www.jpellis.me/projects/tikz-feynman).

Below is the code to draw three diagrams of increasing complexity which showcase some of the feature of TikZ-Feynman.

```
% A simple tree-level diagram
\feynmandiagram [horizontal=a to b] {
  i1 -- [fermion] a -- [fermion] i2,
  a -- [photon] b,
  f1 -- [fermion] b -- [fermion] f2,
};
```

[image: QED Process]

```
% Penguin diagram with momentum arrows
\feynmandiagram [large, vertical=e to f] {
  a -- [fermion] b -- [photon, momentum=\(k\)] c -- [fermion] d,
  b -- [fermion, momentum'=\(p_{1}\)] e -- [fermion, momentum'=\(p_{2}\)] c,
  e -- [gluon]  f,
  h -- [fermion] f -- [fermion] i;
};
```

[image: Penguin diagram with momentum arrows]

```
% Meson mixing and decay
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{feynman}
    \vertex (a1) {\(\overline b\)};
    \vertex[right=1cm of a1] (a2);
    \vertex[right=1cm of a2] (a3);
    \vertex[right=1cm of a3] (a4) {\(b\)};
    \vertex[right=1cm of a4] (a5);
    \vertex[right=2cm of a5] (a6) {\(u\)};

    \vertex[below=2em of a1] (b1) {\(d\)};
    \vertex[right=1cm of b1] (b2);
    \vertex[right=1cm of b2] (b3);
    \vertex[right=1cm of b3] (b4) {\(\overline d\)};
    \vertex[below=2em of a6] (b5) {\(\overline d\)};

    \vertex[above=of a6] (c1) {\(\overline u\)};
    \vertex[above=2em of c1] (c3) {\(d\)};
    \vertex at ($(c1)!0.5!(c3) - (1cm, 0)$) (c2);

    \diagram* {
      {[edges=fermion]
        (b1) -- (b2) -- (a2) -- (a1),
        (b5) -- (b4) -- (b3) -- (a3) -- (a4) -- (a5) -- (a6),
      },
      (a2) -- [boson, edge label=\(W\)] (a3),
      (b2) -- [boson, edge label'=\(W\)] (b3),

      (c1) -- [fermion, out=180, in=-45] (c2) -- [fermion, out=45, in=180] (c3),
      (a5) -- [boson, bend left, edge label=\(W^{-}\)] (c2),
    };

    \draw [decoration={brace}, decorate] (b1.south west) -- (a1.north west)
          node [pos=0.5, left] {\(B^{0}\)};
    \draw [decoration={brace}, decorate] (c3.north east) -- (c1.south east)
          node [pos=0.5, right] {\(\pi^{-}\)};
    \draw [decoration={brace}, decorate] (a6.north east) -- (b5.south east)
          node [pos=0.5, right] {\(\pi^{+}\)};
  \end{feynman}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Meson mixing and decay]

All that is needed in the preamble to generate these is `\usepackage{tikz-feynman}`.  So in the case of the first diagram:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-feynman}
\begin{document}
\feynmandiagram [horizontal=a to b] {
  i1 -- [fermion] a -- [fermion] i2,
  a -- [photon] b,
  f1 -- [fermion] b -- [fermion] f2,
};
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is beautiful!

Comment: I copied and paste your examples. The resulting layout is weird and different from the figures you present.

Comment: @yarchik Instead of down voting my response, perhaps consider checking whether the error is on your side.  Have you checked for any warnings in your log file?  In all likelihood, you have the same issue as presented [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/290599/26980).  If not, then consider asking a new question on this site.

Comment: The voting is for a particular answer, which I find can be improved by adding important details, such as that it has to be compiled with lualatex, not with pdflatex, not with xelatex etc. In the manual to your package you mention about less steep learning curve as compared to other possibilities. May well be, but if such a hurdle is faced just at the beginning, less persistent people may give up. I revert my down vote, but I have to admit that there are several other examples, even from the manual or this site that are not directly copy-pasteable. Even here, edge labels must be in braces.

Comment: Sorry for this message. Can I have some suggestions for your packages? I have sent you also an email. Thank you very much.

Comment: Can we draw a proton (three lines) with `TikZ-Feynman`?