# How to plot Feynman diagrams with PSTricks

Tags: pstricks, feynman

I need to plot some Feynman diagrams for my research papers. Although I had some experience in plotting with PSTricks, it is still not an easy job to plot Feynman diagrams. Could someone provide some tips to make it easier? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: [Here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86588/package-for-typesetting-feynman-diagrams-efficiency-of-feynmp-and-tikz) you is a good starting point. If you are flexible with choice of package (if you can do it in `tikz`), [here](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/feynman-diagram/) is an example with source code.

Comment: You can consider the [`feynmp`](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/feynmf/fmfman.pdf) package; it's more easily managed with my [`feynmp-auto`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/feynmp-auto/feynmp-auto.pdf) that takes care (on a recent TeX Live distribution) of the Metapost runs.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Remarks**

Here is minimal working example using the `\pssin` command from the `pst-coil` package and the `ArrowInside` option from the `pstricks-add` package.

There is a huge downside with this implementation: You can not preserve the frequency of the sine when shortening the line. The command will always draw as many periods as given in the argument not matter how long the line actually is.
Compare: `\pssin[periods=5](0,0)(2,0)` and `\pssin[periods=5](0,0)(8,0)`.

> [image: sample]

## Samples

Compile with `xelatex`.

### 1.)

Inspired by g.kov's answer, I added some labels.

**Implementation**

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage{pst-coil}
\begin{document}
\psset{arrowscale=2}
\begin{pspicture}(-1.5,-1.5)(4.5,1.5)
    % Particles
    \psline[ArrowInside=->](-1,-1)(0,0)
    \psline[ArrowInside=->](0,0)(-1,1)
    \pssin[periods=9,amplitude=0.1,coilarm=0](0,0)(3,0)
    \psline[ArrowInside=->](4,-1)(3,0)
    \psline[ArrowInside=->](3,0)(4,1)
    % Labels
    \uput[45](-0.5,0.5){$k'$}
    \uput[-45](-0.5,-0.5){$k$}
    \uput[135](-1,1){$e^+$}
    \uput[225](-1,-1){$e^-$}
    \uput[-90](1.5,0){$q$}
    \uput[135](3.5,0.5){$q'$}
    \uput[225](3.5,-0.5){$q$}
    \uput[45](4,1){$\mu^+$}
    \uput[-45](4,-1){$\mu^-$}
    % Arrows
    \psline{->}(-1,0.6)(-0.5,0.1)
    \psline{->}(3.5,-0.1)(4,-0.6)
    \psline{->}(1,0.3)(2,0.3)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

**Output**

> [image: feynman1]

### 2.)

**Implementation**

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage{pst-coil}
\begin{document}
\psset{arrowscale=2}
\begin{pspicture}(-1,-1)(4,1)
    \psline[ArrowInside=->](-1,-1)(0,0)
    \psline[ArrowInside=->](0,0)(-1,1)
    \pssin[periods=3,amplitude=0.1,coilarm=0](0,0)(1,0)
    %No ArrowInside for \psarc :(
    \psarc(1.5,0){0.5}{0}{180}\psarc{->}(1.5,0){0.5}{0}{100}
    \psarc(1.5,0){0.5}{180}{360}\psarc{->}(1.5,0){0.5}{180}{280}
    \pssin[periods=3,amplitude=0.1,coilarm=0](2,0)(3,0)
    \psline[ArrowInside=->](4,-1)(3,0)
    \psline[ArrowInside=->](3,0)(4,1)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

**Output**

> [image: feynman2]

### 3.)

**Implementation**

As you can see in the screenshot, the `\pscoil` thing is a little bit tricky.

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage{pst-coil}
\begin{document}
\psset{arrowscale=2}
\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(3,-4)
    \psline[ArrowInside=->](0,0)(1,-1)
    \psline[ArrowInside=->](2,-1)(3,0)
    \pssin[periods=3.5,amplitude=0.1,coilarm=0](1,-1)(2,-1)
    \psline[ArrowInside=->](1,-1)(1.5,-2)
    \psline[ArrowInside=->](1.5,-2)(2,-1)
    \pscoil[coilwidth=0.2,coilarm=0](1.5,-2)(1.5,-3)
    \psline[ArrowInside=->](0,-4)(1.5,-3)
    \psline[ArrowInside=->](1.5,-3)(3,-4)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

**Output**

> [image: feynman3]

Comment: It is cool. I like this implementation.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. If you like my answer that much, please consider marking it as [accepted answer](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852).

Comment: No `ArrowInside` for `\psellipticarc` as well. :-(

Answer (score 6):

There is also an `Asymptote` module `feynman` that might be of interest.
This is an example demo `eetomumu.asy` from the distribution:

```
import feynman;

// set default line width to 0.8bp
currentpen = linewidth(0.8);

// scale all other defaults of the feynman module appropriately
fmdefaults();

// define vertex and external points

real L = 50;

pair zl = (-0.75*L,0);
pair zr = (+0.75*L,0);

pair xu = zl + L*dir(+120);
pair xl = zl + L*dir(-120);

pair yu = zr + L*dir(+60);
pair yl = zr + L*dir(-60);

// draw propagators and vertices

drawFermion(xu--zl);
drawFermion(zl--xl);

drawPhoton(zl--zr);

drawFermion(yu--zr);
drawFermion(zr--yl);

drawVertex(zl);
drawVertex(zr);

// draw momentum arrows and momentum labels

drawMomArrow(xl--zl, Relative(left));
label(Label("$k'$",2RightSide), xl--zl);

label(Label("$k$",2LeftSide), xu--zl);

drawMomArrow(zl--zr, Relative(left));
label(Label("$q$",2RightSide), zl--zr);

drawMomArrow(zr--yu, Relative(right));
label(Label("$p'$",2LeftSide), zr--yu);

label(Label("$p$",2RightSide), zr--yl);

// draw particle labels

label("$e^-$", xu, left);
label("$e^+$", xl, left);

label("$\mu^+$", yu, right);
label("$\mu^-$", yl, right);
```

[image]