# How does one draw a momentum arrow along a line in feynmf?

Tags: diagrams, arrows, feynmf

When drawing a Feynman diagram, one often wants to label each line and draw the momentum arrows. How can one draw a satisfactory momentum arrow? Take for example electron-muon scattering, where I've tried to draw arrows myself by putting them in the labels.

```
\begin{fmfgraph*}(40,25)
    \fmfleftn{i}{2}
    \fmfrightn{o}{2}
    \fmf{fermion,label=$\longrightarrow$}{i1,v1,o1}
    \fmf{fermion}{i2,v2,o2}
    \fmf{photon,label=$\gamma$}{v1,v2}
    \fmfdotn{v}{2}
    \fmflabel{$e^-$}{i1}
    \fmflabel{$e^-$}{o1}
    \fmflabel{$\mu^-$}{i2}
    \fmflabel{$\mu^-$}{o2}
\end{fmfgraph*}
```

The result is silly at most:

[image: A futile attempt to draw momentum arrows]

If this would be done properly, there would be an arrow parallel to the line, next (in the direction orthogonal to the line and arrow) to which there would be a text like $p_i$. How could this be achieved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't mind switching to plain [Metapost](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107489/what-is-metapost-metafont-and-how-can-i-get-started-using-it) syntax, and making your graphic into an external file, you can import the `feynmp` definitions and use them in a regular MP diagram.  This provides a simple way to do diagrams with layouts that the standard bits of `feynmf` don't support.

Here's my first attempt at what you describe above.

[image]

which was produced with this MP input:

```
prologues := 3;
outputtemplate := "%j%c.eps";

input feynmp

beginfig(1);

z1 = -z2 = 20 up;
z3 = (-60,40); 
z4 = z3 reflectedabout(up,down);
z5 = z3 reflectedabout(left,right);
z6 = z4 reflectedabout(left,right);

draw fermion z3 -- z1;
draw fermion z5 -- z2;
draw fermion z1 -- z4;
draw fermion z2 -- z6;
draw photon  z1 -- z2;

label.lft(btex $\gamma$ etex, .5[z1,z2]);

label.ulft(btex $\mu^-$ etex, z3);
label.urt (btex $\mu^-$ etex, z4);

label.llft(btex $e^-$ etex, z5);
label.lrt (btex $e^-$ etex, z6);

fill fullcircle scaled 4 shifted z1;
fill fullcircle scaled 4 shifted z2;

path a[];

a1 = subpath (0.3,0.6) of (z5--z2) shifted 8 up;
drawarrow a1; label.top(btex $p_i$ etex, point .5 of a1);

a2 = subpath (0.4,0.7) of (z2--z6) shifted 8 up;
drawarrow a2; label.top(btex $p_i$ etex, point .5 of a2);

endfig;
end.
```

However if you would prefer to stick more closely to your original input, then you can use an `fmfcmd` to add a new line style to add the momentum arrows.  Like this:

```
\begin{fmfgraph*}(120,55)
    \fmfleftn{i}{2}
    \fmfrightn{o}{2}
    \fmf{fermion}{i1,v1,o1}
    \fmf{fermion}{i2,v2,o2}
    \fmf{photon,label=$\gamma$}{v1,v2}
    \fmfdotn{v}{2}
    \fmflabel{$e^-$}{i1}
    \fmflabel{$e^-$}{o1}
    \fmflabel{$\mu^-$}{i2}
    \fmflabel{$\mu^-$}{o2}
    % additions here
    \fmffreeze
    \fmfcmd{style_def marrow expr p = drawarrow subpath (1/4, 3/4) of p shifted 6 up
        withpen pencircle scaled 0.4; label.top(btex $p_i$ etex, point 0.5 of p
        shifted 6 up); enddef;}
    \fmf{marrow}{i1,v1,o1}
\end{fmfgraph*}
```

which produces this:

[image]

Note that the `fmffreeze` stops the extra connections messing up the layout.  And I freely admit that the labels are a bit of a hack.

To produce this output, by the way, I found it convenient to put the `fmfgraph` into a LaTeX file like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{feynmp-auto}
\begin{document}
\begin{fmffile}{first}
\begin{fmfgraph*}(120,55)
   ... graph commands here ...
\end{fmfgraph*}
\end{fmffile}
\end{document}
```

Note that I had to change the size of the OP to something that came out readable on my system.

Comment: Especially the `\fmfcmd` approach is beautiful here. There are two problems though. One, you can only have one text. For example, when making the command `\newcommand{\marrow}[2]{\fmfcmd{style_def marrow expr p = drawarrow subpath (1/4, 3/4) of p shifted 6 up withpen pencircle scaled 0.4; label.top(btex #1 etex, point 0.5 of p shifted 6 up); enddef;} \fmf{marrow}{#2}}` and calling `\marrow{$p_1$}{i1,v1}\marrow{$p_2$}{v1,o1}`, the text `p_2` is shown with both lines. Second, it doesn't work on vertical lines. Any thoughts on a possible solution (my Metapost is terrible)?

Comment: The first problem could be solved by giving the arrows names through `\newcommand{\marrow}[3]{\fmfcmd{style_def marrow#1 expr p = drawarrow subpath (1/4, 3/4) of p shifted 6 up withpen pencircle scaled 0.4; label.top(btex #2 etex, point 0.5 of p shifted 6 up); enddef;} \fmf{marrow#1}{#3}}` and `\marrow{a}{$p_1$}{i1,v1}\marrow{b}{$p_2$}{v1,o1}`. But this is far from best practice, and should only be used as last resort by lack of a better solution.

Comment: Or you could simply define another line style with the different text, but again this is a bit of a hack.

Comment: Similarly, for vertical lines, define another line style replacing `up` with `left`...

Comment: Or learn plain Metapost :-)  (or even TikZ...)

Comment: At your first comment: yes, this is actually what is done with the `\newcommand` indirectly. At your second comment: it could be included as a fourth argument to the command, probably easiest solution for now. At your third comment: yes, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86588/package-for-typesetting-feynman-diagrams-efficiency-of-feynmp-and-tikz is perhaps more powerful, but it is less convenient (`feynmp-auto` calculates a lot for you and is very simple).

Comment: Actually, you need 5 arguments as `label.position` has to be defined as well: `\newcommand{\marrow}[5]{\fmfcmd{style_def marrow#1 expr p = drawarrow subpath (1/4, 3/4) of p shifted 6 #2 withpen pencircle scaled 0.4; label.#3(btex #4 etex, point 0.5 of p shifted 6 #2); enddef;} \fmf{marrow#1}{#5}}` with for example `\marrow{a}{up}{top}{$p_1$}{i1,v1}\marrow{c}{right}{rt}{$q$}{v1,v2}`.

Answer (score 5):

Just to recapitulate the discussion that arose underneath [Thruston](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/15036/thruston)'s answer, here's a somewhat hacky approach to drawing momentum arrows next to lines in Feynman diagrams.

The command `\marrow`, essentially a combination of `\fmfcmd` (definition of a new style) and `fmf` (drawing an arrow with this style) is defined with 5 arguments:

```
\marrow{name}{arrow_pos}{text_pos}{text}{nodes}
```

The first argument is needed since essentially a new style is created for each arrow (letter symbols only), the second is any of `up, down, left, right`, the third is any of `top, bot, lft, rt`, the fourth is your text and the fifth is a list of nodes or vertices in your Feynman diagram (e.g. `i1,v1`).

A MWE is the following.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{feynmp-auto}
\newcommand{\marrow}[5]{%
    \fmfcmd{style_def marrow#1
    expr p = drawarrow subpath (1/4, 3/4) of p shifted 6 #2 withpen pencircle scaled 0.4;
    label.#3(btex #4 etex, point 0.5 of p shifted 6 #2);
    enddef;}
    \fmf{marrow#1,tension=0}{#5}}
\begin{document}
\setlength{\unitlength}{1mm}
\begin{fmffile}{marrows}
    \begin{fmfgraph*}(50,30)
        \fmfleftn{i}{2}
        \fmfrightn{o}{2}
        \fmf{fermion}{i1,v1,o1}
        \fmf{fermion}{i2,v2,o2}
        \fmf{photon,label=$\gamma$}{v1,v2}
        \fmfdotn{v}{2}
        \fmflabel{$e^-$}{i1}
        \fmflabel{$e^-$}{o1}
        \fmflabel{$\mu^-$}{i2}
        \fmflabel{$\mu^-$}{o2}
        % Momentum arrows
        \marrow{a}{down}{bot}{$p_1$}{i1,v1}
        \marrow{b}{up}{top}{$p_2$}{i2,v2}
        \marrow{c}{left}{lft}{$q$}{v1,v2}
        \marrow{d}{down}{bot}{$p_3$}{v1,o1}
        \marrow{e}{up}{top}{$p_4$}{v2,o2}
    \end{fmfgraph*}
\end{fmffile}
\end{document}
```

With output:

[image: Momentum arrows]

The lines in `\marrow` are given tension 0 to prevent them from influencing the shape of the graph ([Thruston](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/15036/thruston)'s initial approach was calling `\fmffreeze` before the inclusion of the arrows, but I think it is best practice to avoid that command as one might want to continue adding lines and vertices after the momentum arrows are drawn).

---

For the more adventurous: you could allow the user to choose the spacing himself for every arrow, such as in this loop diagram.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{feynmp-auto}
\newcommand{\marrow}[5]{%
    \fmfcmd{style_def marrow#1
    expr p = drawarrow subpath (1/4, 3/4) of p shifted 6 #2 withpen pencircle scaled 0.4;
    label.#3(btex #4 etex, point 0.5 of p shifted 6 #2);
    enddef;}
    \fmf{marrow#1,tension=0}{#5}}
\newcommand{\Marrow}[6]{%
    \fmfcmd{style_def marrow#1
    expr p = drawarrow subpath (1/4, 3/4) of p shifted #6 #2 withpen pencircle scaled 0.4;
    label.#3(btex #4 etex, point 0.5 of p shifted #6 #2);
    enddef;}
    \fmf{marrow#1,tension=0}{#5}}
\begin{document}
\setlength{\unitlength}{1mm}
\begin{fmffile}{marrow2}
    \begin{fmfgraph*}(50,50)
        \fmfleftn{i}{2}
        \fmfrightn{o}{2}
        \fmf{fermion}{i1,v1,o1}
        \fmf{fermion}{i2,v4,o2}
        \fmf{photon}{v1,v2}
        \fmf{fermion,right,tension=0.4}{v2,v3,v2}
        \fmf{photon}{v3,v4}
        \fmfdotn{v}{4}
        \marrow{a}{down}{bot}{$p_1$}{i1,v1}
        \marrow{b}{up}{top}{$p_2$}{i2,v4}
        \marrow{c}{left}{lft}{$q$}{v1,v2}
        \Marrow{d}{right}{rt}{$k$}{v2,v3}{26}
        \Marrow{e}{left}{lft}{$q-k$}{v2,v3}{26}
        \marrow{f}{left}{lft}{$q$}{v3,v4}
        \marrow{g}{down}{bot}{$p_3$}{v1,o1}
        \marrow{h}{up}{top}{$p_4$}{v4,o2}
    \end{fmfgraph*}
\end{fmffile}
\end{document}
```

[image: Loop diagram]