# Packages for drawing diagrams of Feynman: advantages and disadvantages

Tags: tools, tikz-feynman, feynman, feynmf

My question simply derives from this question:
[Bremsstrahlung process in \feynmandiagram environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/505256/bremsstrahlung-process-in-feynmandiagram-environment)

I have seen into the site TeX.SE. there are many question on the packages to draw a Feymann diagram:

1. `tikz-feynman`;
2. `tikzfeynhand`;
3. `feynmp` a package for drawing Feynman diagrams with `MetaFont`;
4. `feynman`;
5. `axodraw2`;
6. `pst-feyn`, a  pstricks package.

What are some of the advantages and disadvantages for each of these packages?

With lot of sincerity I have seen into web that there is a tool online https://feynman.aivazis.com/ where you can draw any feynman diagram. 
Why, for example, this MWE is not compilable?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{feynman}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{feynman} 
    \electroweak[]{6.00, 8.00}{8.00, 10.00}
    \electroweak[]{9.00, 4.00}{8.00, 6.00}
    \fermion[showArrow=true, flip=true]{4.00, 8.00}{6.00, 8.00}
    \fermion[]{10.00, 6.00}{8.00, 6.00}
    \fermion[]{8.00, 6.00}{6.00, 8.00}
    \text{8.90,4.90}{$\gamma$}
    \text{9.30,3.70}{N}
    \text{3.70,7.70}{$e^+$}
    \text{10.70,5.70}{$e^+$}
    \text{8.50,9.90}{$A'$}
\end{feynman}
\end{document}
```

Using my recent version of MikTeX for OS Windows, or, for example, with Papeeria the code above not is compilable because I have the same error:

```
! LaTeX Error: File `feynman.sty' not found.
```

### ADDENDUM:

I have discovered that exist also another tool online called: [JaxoDraw](https://www.arxiv-vanity.com/papers/0811.4113/) 2.0 that it uses its own version of the axodraw style file, called `axodraw4j.sty`.

Comment: It is not part of any distribution – probably because it is latex 2.09. You forgot `axodraw2` and `pst-feyn`.

Comment: @Bernard Considering the other two packages that you have indicated, for reasons of correctness, could you edit my question?

Comment: 'Tis done, mylord! Is it fine like this?

Comment: IMHO stands for "In my humble/honest opinion", and I have no idea about `feynman.sty`. My above comment was wrong (autocorrection). I use `feynmp`, and my own tikz styles to draw Feynman diagrams. `tikz-feynman` and `tikz-feynhand` are OK but IMHO have some room for improvement, and the other packages should no longer be used IMHO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following are personal opinions. If you do not agree with them, write another answer. I have been working with `axodraw`, `feynmp` and `tikz-feynman`, correspondingly I may not do justice to the other packages. There are three excellent packages that allow you to draw Feynman diagrams.

1. `feynmp`. This package produces beautiful diagrams. It is written by a respected physicist, who knows what he is doing, and correspondingly all elements have very reasonable names. Even though the layout mechanism is oldish, it works great, and the manual explains how one can do manual adjustments, if needed. The only two minor downsides are: you need to run metapost and there is no built-in support for momentum arrows (but possibilities to add them can be found [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/206806/194703)).
2. `tikz-feynman` is a nice package. It uses *some* graph drawing algorithms, which were however not necessarily designed to draw Feynman diagrams. Since these require `lualatex`, which is not available on the arXiv, one may want to use it in the non-automatic mode. I hope that some future version will support bent arrows and remove the nonsensical notion of "anti-Majorana fermions". It may also be worthwhile to combine it with other layout mechanisms. Otherwise the package works great. Note that you could also just use [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/87395/194703) to draw your diagrams. In this case you can set up your own styles. (This is what I have recently been started doing.) In any case, this is an evolving theme, so it is worthwhile to stay tuned.
3. `tikz-feynhand` is another nice package, which is less commonly used than `tikz-feynman`. I have not really been using it.

The `axodraw2` package is IMHO outdated. I never used `feynman`. And frankly I never understood the purpose of `pst-feyn`. It seems to be written by someone who has not too much expertise in high energy physics (see e.g. the diagram on the bottom of p. 4 or the one on p. 12 of the manual), and the output is IMHO much less appealing than what 1-3 have to offer. Also there is the usual problem that `pstricks` restricts your choice of compilers. But this is just an opinion. I will be interested in reading other opinions.

Answer (score 2):

I have solved himself my question to compile correctly my code. Infact, before, I must download the file `feynman.sty` (clicking, after I have created the diagram, where there is written `Download LaTeX package` (IMHO, this style should be changed for some part of code - infact the image is very big and the label are outside of the diagram and them not work correctly -).

It is necessary to put the `.tex` file into the same folder with `feynman.sty` and compile it.

[image]

All the code compile correctly. After to decrease the size of my diagram I have used

```
\scalebox{.5}{
\begin{feynman}
    .....
\end{feynman}}
```

but personally I do not recommend this type of online tool because it is not very efficient.