# How to use the next code in a new feynman package?

Tags: packages, feynman

I used the application here:
https://feynman.aivazis.com/

I downloaded the file feynman.sty to the same directory as my TeX files are in, but it doesn't seem to be working.

Here's the code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{feynman}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{slashed}
\begin{document}

\begin{feynman}
\fermion[showArrow=true, flip=true, label=$k$]{24.00, 9.00}{25.00, 9.00}
\fermion[showArrow=false]{23.00, 8.00}{24.00, 8.00}
\fermion[showArrow=false]{23.00, 9.00}{24.00, 8.00}
\electroweak[]{10.00, 9.00}{11.00, 10.00}
\fermion[]{4.00, 7.00}{5.00, 8.00}
\fermion[showArrow=false]{23.00, 7.00}{24.00, 8.00}
\fermion[showArrow=false]{23.00, 6.00}{24.00, 8.00}
 \electroweak[]{7.00, 7.00}{8.00, 8.00}
 \fermion[]{7.00, 6.00}{8.00, 7.00}
\fermion[]{10.00, 4.00}{11.00, 5.00}
\fermion[showArrow=true, flip=true, label=$k'$]{23.00, 10.00}{24.00, 9.00}
\fermion[showArrow=false, label=$P,M$, lineWidth=1]{24.00, 8.00}{25.00, 8.00}
\electroweak[label=$q$]{24.00, 8.00}{24.00, 9.00}\end{feynman}
\end{document}
```

How to fix this problem?

Edit: Here's my second code of the Feynman diagram:

```
\begin{feynman}
\electroweak[]{8.00, 10.00}{9.00, 11.00}
\fermion[]{7.00, 5.00}{8.00, 6.00}
\fermion[showArrow=false, label=$P,M$, labelDistance=0.50, labelLocation=1.66]{23.00, 10.00}{24.00, 10.00}
\electroweak[label=$q$]{23.00, 10.00}{23.00, 11.00}
\fermion[]{13.00, 7.00}{14.00, 8.00}
\fermion[showArrow=false]{22.00, 11.00}{23.00, 10.00}
\fermion[]{8.00, 4.00}{9.00, 5.00}
\fermion[]{7.00, 5.00}{8.00, 6.00}
\fermion[]{10.00, 11.00}{11.00, 12.00}
\fermion[showArrow=true, flip=true, label=$k'$]{22.00, 12.00}{23.00, 11.00}
\fermion[]{8.00, 7.00}{9.00, 8.00}
\fermion[]{8.00, 5.00}{9.00, 6.00}
\fermion[]{4.00, 7.00}{5.00, 8.00}
\fermion[showArrow=false]{22.00, 10.00}{23.00, 10.00}
\fermion[showArrow=false]{22.00, 8.00}{23.00, 10.00}
\fermion[showArrow=true, flip=true, label=$k$]{23.00, 11.00}{24.00, 11.00}
\fermion[showArrow=false]{22.00, 9.00}{23.00, 10.00}
\fermion[]{7.00, 4.00}{8.00, 5.00}
\end{feynman}
```

from the applicaition in the above website, my problem is that in my Bakom editor the pic is smeared all over the page, how to shrink it?
Here's a pic of how this diagram looks like in the above website:
[image]

Comment: Well, what does "seems not to working" mean? Do you get error messages? Please show us them! And please complete your given code snippet to be complete and compilable (with or without errors) ...

Comment: The diagram doesn't appear in the WYSIWYG screen, and I get the next errors message: ! LaTeX Error: \begin{tikzpicture} on input line 118 ended by \end{feynman}. ! Package tikz Error: Giving up on this path. Did you forget a semicolon?.

Comment: What do you expect? You post a fragment here, which lacks `\documentclass`, `\begin{document}`, `\end{document}` and has no information how you compile it.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat I added the lines of code, I use Bakoma-TeX.

Comment: An obvious error is `label=$P,M$`; type `label={$P,M$}` instead.

Comment: thanks @egreg, do you happen to know how to shrink the diagram such that it will fit the page? currently it doesn't appear as in the webpage of the application.

Comment: @Alan The diagram I get is completely wrong. Please, make a sensible example to begin with.

Comment: @egrer I added a second code from the website, can you please have a look at it? and suggest how to shrink it to fit the page in the editor?

Comment: @Alan I still get nonsense.

Comment: @egreg I added a picture of how this code looks like in the webpage, in my editor it takes all the page, and I want to shrink it a little bit.

Comment: @Alan Hi, when you have a bit of your time see this my question, please. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/505270/packages-for-drawing-diagrams-of-feynman-advantages-and-disadvantages

Comment: @Sebastiano yes I read your post. At least there are some initiatives to help us create feynman diagrams with ease.

Comment: @Alan It is true but for my humble opinion the feynman.sty is old and it should be modified in some parts.

Comment: @Sebastiano if someone can make a new and improved feynman diagrams application I am all for it; but I am not a computer programmer, so don't count on me doing this... haha :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The diagram had a bunch of spurious objects. Upon removing them, I get

```latex
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{feynman}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{showframe} % to show the page frame

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{feynman}
\fermion[
  showArrow=false,
  label={$P,M$},
  labelDistance=0.50,
  labelLocation=1.66
]{23.00, 10.00}{24.00, 10.00}
\electroweak[label=$q$]{23.00, 10.00}{23.00, 11.00}
\fermion[showArrow=false]{22.00, 11.00}{23.00, 10.00}
\fermion[showArrow=true, flip=true, label=$k'$]{22.00, 12.00}{23.00, 11.00}
\fermion[showArrow=false]{22.00, 10.00}{23.00, 10.00}
\fermion[showArrow=false]{22.00, 8.00}{23.00, 10.00}
\fermion[showArrow=true, flip=true, label=$k$]{23.00, 11.00}{24.00, 11.00}
\fermion[showArrow=false]{22.00, 9.00}{23.00, 10.00}
\end{feynman}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Beware that a label containing a comma should be braced:

```
label={$P,M$}
```

[image]

Comment: great!!! thanks