# How can I draw a momentum arrow in feynmf?

Tags: feynman, feynmf, feynmp, feynmp-auto

My question is similar to the one from this post: [How does one draw a momentum arrow along a line in feynmf?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/206799/how-does-one-draw-a-momentum-arrow-along-a-line-in-feynmf).

However, I want to know if it is possible to draw a momentum arrow along a line using the `feynmf` package instead of the `feynmp-auto` one.

I used this solution:

```
\usepackage{feynmp-auto}
\newcommand{\marrow}[5]{%
    \fmfcmd{style_def marrow#1
    expr p = drawarrow subpath (1/4, 3/4) of p shifted 6 #2 withpen pencircle scaled 0.4;
    label.#3(btex #4 etex, point 0.5 of p shifted 6 #2);
    enddef;}
    \fmf{marrow#1,tension=0}{#5}}
\begin{document}
\setlength{\unitlength}{1mm}
\begin{fmffile}{marrows}
    \begin{fmfgraph*}(50,30)
        \fmfleftn{i}{2}
        \fmfrightn{o}{2}
        \fmf{fermion}{i1,v1,o1}
        \fmf{fermion}{i2,v2,o2}
        \fmf{photon,label=$\gamma$}{v1,v2}
        \fmfdotn{v}{2}
        \fmflabel{$e^-$}{i1}
        \fmflabel{$e^-$}{o1}
        \fmflabel{$\mu^-$}{i2}
        \fmflabel{$\mu^-$}{o2}
        % Momentum arrows
        \marrow{a}{down}{bot}{$p_1$}{i1,v1}
        \marrow{b}{up}{top}{$p_2$}{i2,v2}
        \marrow{c}{left}{lft}{$q$}{v1,v2}
        \marrow{d}{down}{bot}{$p_3$}{v1,o1}
        \marrow{e}{up}{top}{$p_4$}{v2,o2}
    \end{fmfgraph*}
\end{fmffile}
\end{document}
```

which is given by @Betohaku as an answer to the question in [How does one draw a momentum arrow along a line in feynmf?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/206799/how-does-one-draw-a-momentum-arrow-along-a-line-in-feynmf) and it worked.

However, when I swap `\usepackage{feynmp-auto}` for `\usepackage{feynmf}`, it doesn't compile. I would like to know which changes should I make so that I can get the same result using the package `feynmf`.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). Please provide a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) to clarify your problem.

Comment: Can you tell us *why* it does not compile?   Did it fail when you ran `latex` or when you ran `mf` ?

Comment: And perhaps you could clarify why you need to use `feynmf` at all?

Comment: @Thruston, it did compile now in Overleaf but the diagram did not appear. I am trying to use `feynmf` because I want to submit to ArXiv and when I tried with feynmp-auto the diagrams did not appear. I found then a question at ArXiv's FAQ about feynmf and I could upload the file with the diagrams but only by removing the momentum arrows.

Comment: Hmmm.  Did you get a chance to read the [user guide](https://ctan.org/pkg/feynmf?lang=en)?  with `feynmf` you have to run `latex` so that it creates a `.mf` file, then run `mf` on that file with an appropriate output mode, then run `dvipdf` (or whatever) to produce the output.  I do not think Overleaf supports this complex flow.

Comment: Your best bet is probably to create your diagrams as separate stand alone PDFs using the `standalone` class, then include them in your main file as graphics.

Comment: @Thruston, I tried to compile this without Overleaf. I think the correct way to compile this is to do `pdflatex feynman.tex` (`feynman.tex` was the name I gave to the file) , then type `mf '\mode:=laserjet; input marrows'` and then type again `pdflatex feynman.tex`. This worked when I commented the `marrow` lines. Thus, I don't think it is a compilation problem.