# How to add vector sign on momentum in Tikz Feynman

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-feynman

I have been following [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/206901), which includes a loop diagram, to incorporate momentum arrows in a Tikz Feynman diagram. I would like to know if it is possible to add a arrow indicating vector sign, e.g. {\huge$\vec{p}_1$}, instead of just displaying $p_1$.

Comment: The linked answer uses feynmp-auto, i.e. Metapost, to render the diagram but your question is tagged and mentions TikZ/`tikz-feynman`. Do you want to use TikZ or Metapost? What happens when you replace `$p_1$`with `\huge$\vec{p}_1$`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use any text for the momentum in `tikz-feynman`.

### Code

```
% !TeX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-feynman}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes}
\tikzfeynmanset{momentum/arrow shorten=.3}
\begin{document}
\feynmandiagram[
  vertical'=b to d,
  node distance=3cm,
]{
  a [particle=$\mu^-$]
    --[fermion, momentum=$p_2$]
  b[dot]
    --[fermion, momentum=$p_4$]
  c[particle=$\mu^-$],
  d[dot]
    --[boson, "$\gamma$"', momentum=$q$]
  b,
  e [particle=$e^-$]
    --[fermion, momentum=$\vec p_1$]
  d
    --[fermion, momentum=$p_3$]
  f [particle=$e^-$]
};
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response. I would also like to inquire if it is possible to include a vector sign for the ```marrow ``` and ```Marrow ``` commands used in the code. For example - ```\Marrow{e}{left}{lft}{$\vec{q}-\vec{k}$}{v2,v3}{26}```
      and ```\marrow{f}{left}{lft}{$\vec{q}$}{v3,v4}```.