# Error when using TikZ-Feynman package

Tags: tikz-pgf, errors, feynman, tikz-feynman

Today I downloaded and installed the new [TikZ-Feynman](http://www.jpellis.me/projects/tikz-feynman/) package to draw Feynman diagrams. I included the packages

```
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usepackage{tikz-feynman}
\tikzfeynmanset{compat=1.0.0}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,positioning,automata,backgrounds,calc,er,patterns}
```

into my preamble (changed them already many times).

However, already a simple sample code like

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{feynman}
\vertex (a) {\(\mu^{-}\)};
\vertex [right=of a] (b);
\vertex [above right=of b] (f1) {\(\nu_{\mu}\)};
\vertex [below right=of b] (c);
\vertex [above right=of c] (f2) {\(\overline \nu_{e}\)};
\vertex [below right=of c] (f3) {\(e^{-}\)};
\diagram* {
(a) -- [fermion] (b) -- [fermion] (f1),
(b) -- [boson, edge label'=\(W^{-}\)] (c),
(c) -- [anti fermion] (f2),
(c) -- [fermion] (f3),
};
\end{feynman}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

directly gives the error:

> `Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/graph drawing/node distance'.`

Can you please help me? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to compile with `lualatex`!

If compiled width `pdflatex`, there's a warning message

```
Package tikz-feynman Warning: LuaTeX is required if you wish to have vertices a
utomatically placed. You can disable this warning by setting /tikzfeynman/warn 
luatex=false on input line 8.
```

However, disabling the warning does not cure the problem.

Unfortunately the `tikz-feynman` manual does not reveal anything about the usage of `lualatex`. It seems to be a hidden feature or the package author relied that this is known.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,positioning,automata,backgrounds,calc,er,patterns}
\usepackage{tikz-feynman}
\tikzfeynmanset{compat=1.0.0}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{feynman}
\vertex (a) {\(\mu^{-}\)};
\vertex [right=of a] (b);
\vertex [above right=of b] (f1) {\(\nu_{\mu}\)};
\vertex [below right=of b] (c);
\vertex [above right=of c] (f2) {\(\overline \nu_{e}\)};
\vertex [below right=of c] (f3) {\(e^{-}\)};
\diagram* {
(a) -- [fermion] (b) -- [fermion] (f1),
(b) -- [boson, edge label'=\(W^{-}\)] (c),
(c) -- [anti fermion] (f2),
(c) -- [fermion] (f3),
};
\end{feynman}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Here's the image produced for that apparent muon-decay

[image]

---

**EDIT**

As mentioned in the comment below, this was a bug in Ti*k*Z-Feynman in v1.0.0.  As of v1.1.0, Ti*k*Z-Feynman issues warnings whenever a feature requiring LuaLaTeX is used.

If you still try using the automatic graph placement algorithms and don't use LuaLaTeX, a very simple algorithm is used which generates something like:

[image]

If you see this output, you'll either need to change compiler to LuaLaTeX, or manually position the location of the vertices.

Comment: I'm the package author.  Happy to see people using it!  Indeed, it was an oversight on my part in the documentation... In the process of revising the documentation I ended up removing all mentions that it must be compiled with LuaLaTeX.  Additionally, the error you mention has been [reported and fixed](https://github.com/JP-Ellis/tikz-feynman/issues/11).  I'm intending to release an update very soon with all the fixes.

Comment: @JP-Ellis: Thanks, that's very nice

Comment: @JP-Ellis I get such warning message even when I explicitly and manually set the position of all points (I start by placing one point at (0, 0) and then specify others points relative to it with `left`, `below`...). So does it mean that LuaLaTeX is always required?