# Disfigured Feynman Diagrams!

Tags: tikz-pgf, feynman, tikz-feynman

I'm trying to draw some Feynman diagrams with LaTeX. So I'm using the TikZ-Feynman package. But my code below:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-feynman}
\begin{document}
\feynmandiagram [large, vertical=e to f] {
  a -- [fermion] b -- [photon, momentum=\(k\)] c -- [fermion] d,
  b -- [fermion, momentum'=\(p_{1}\)] e -- [fermion, momentum'=\(p_{2}\)] c,
  e -- [gluon]  f,
  h -- [fermion] f -- [fermion] i;
};
\end{document}
```

produces the following disfigured diagram!

[image]

What should I do?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.  Thank you for adding your work as MWE.  Actually, I don't understand the exact problem.  (Maybe due to the fact, that I am not a physician and hence are not able to see the problem at once.)  Could you please be so kind, to add a sketch of the diagram, what you want to achieve?  Just a quick pencil sketch shot with your handy cam and inserted as image would be sufficient.

Comment: Well, the TikZ-Feynman package is supposed to give upright diagrams like the ones in the following page:http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86588/package-for-typesetting-feynman-diagrams-efficiency-of-feynmp-and-tikz?newreg=447955660fac46bdb7d08e447b4ddd20

Comment: And physician means a doctor in medicine, we're called physicists, ;).

Comment: thank you for your information.  I am neither a physician nor a physicist, but willing to learn :-)  In my opinion, your diagram is also upright.  Still don't know, what may be wrong with that.

Comment: Please scroll down that page and take a look at the one with the comment %Penguin diagram with momentum arrows, that's the result I'm supposed to get(same code), that's how we draw these diagrams.

Comment: Are you compiling with `pdflatex`/`xelatex`, or `lualatex`? You need to use `lualatex` for the more advanced placement algorithms.

Comment: Cool to see more people using Tikz-Feynman! This is actually a duplicate of [this issue](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/290603/26980) :). I'll vote to close it.

Comment: But there is another problem. Because I want to use xepersian, It seems I need to use xtex to compile my code. Is it possible to compile a code using xepersian, with lualatex?

Comment: I'll just compile the diagrams separately and include them in my main code using \includegraphics.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see you follow up comment.  Compiling the diagrams separately is one way to do it; alternatively, you might want to look at the `externalize` library for TikZ-Feynman.  Have a look at [this snippet](https://github.com/JP-Ellis/tikz-feynman/blob/master/tikz-feynman.tex#L91-L106), though you'll probably want to change the `external/mode` (refer [TikZ manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf) for information about the options).