# tikz-feynman package - lines drawn haphazardly

Tags: tikz-feynman

I use the following code using the tikz-feynman package.

```
\tikzfeynmanset{
    every vertex/.style={red, dot},
    every particle/.style={blue},
    every blob/.style={draw=green!40!black, pattern color=green!40!black},
}
\feynmandiagram [horizontal=a to b] {
    a [particle={\(\gamma, Z\)}] -- [boson] b [blob],
    c -- [fermion] b -- [fermion] d,
};
```

However, I get an output in which the lines are drawn haphazardly.

Is there a way to correct this?

Comment: I suspect it is because you aren't [compiling with LuaLaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/290599/26980).  If you want to use the automatic vertex placement algorithm, Ti*k*Z-Feynman needs access to Lua through LuaLaTeX.

Comment: what are the lualatex package names?

Comment: LuaLaTeX isn't a package, it's actually a completely different implementation of LaTeX.  Instead of typing `pdflatex my_file.tex`, type `lualatex my_file.tex`.  If you're using an editor, there should be an option somewhere to change the compiler (or search this website :) )

Comment: I am using sharelatex

Comment: Yeah, so go into the options, and you should be able to change the compiler from pdfLaTeX to LuaLaTeX.