# problem generating Cyrillic text and Feynman diagrams together

Tags: cyrillic, tikz-feynman

I'm working on this file that has *English* and also passages in *Cyrillic*. I also have Feynman diagrams that I draw with `tikz-feynman`.

The issue is that if I compile with **Latex** I will get the text but the diagrams are not how they should be: The vertices are misplaced.

If I compile with **Luatex** I get the diagrams but not the *Cyrillic* writing.

These are the declarations used:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz-feynman}
```

I'm also using **mactex** with **texshop** as the editor. Perhaps if I define how to write *Cyrillic* that is understandable for **Luatex** everything will be ok but I don't know how to do that.

[image]

[image]

the code is:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz-feynman}

\title{Квантовая теория поле}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\tableofcontents

\part{Часть II}

\chapter{Уравнение Дайсона}

Рассмотрим высшие имеются общие с

this line is just for debugging purposes 

\begin{enumerate}
  \item 
\end{enumerate}

\begin{enumerate} 
  \item фотонные собств - диаграмм (ФСЭД)
\end{enumerate}

\begin{enumerate} 
  \item Вершинные диаграмм (ВД)
\end{enumerate}


\feynmandiagram [horizontal=a to b] {
  i1 -- [fermion] a -- [fermion] i2,
   a -- [photon] b,
  f1 -- [fermion] b -- [fermion] f2,
};
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]! Can you extend you code to include a sample diagram and text in both languages so we can see the problem.  What, if any, font declarations do you make to get cyrillic?  When you say compile with "Latex" do you mean `latex` or `pdflatex`?

Comment: @AndrewSwann I added 2 photos for what happens if I compile with lulatex or latex. by compiling with latex I mean when I choose it from the drop down list in Texshop (top of the picture on the left)

Comment: When providing sample code, please copy/paste it into the question so that we can then copy/paste it ourselves and reproduce the error; but thanks for providing a screenshot of the different PDF outputs.

Comment: @JP-Ellis added the code as well, sorry. not used to stack exchange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LuaLaTeX has a much improved font handling compared to LaTeX; however, it differs somewhat to that of LaTeX.  In particular, LuaLaTeX can handle TrueType and OpenType fonts (`.ttf` and `.otf`) that you have most likely seen before.

The default font used by LuaLaTeX unfortunately does not have the appropriate glyphs to display Russian, but this can easily be changed using the [`fontspec`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fontspec) package.  For example, the Noto font can handle many *many* glyphs and works perfectly fine in LuaLaTeX.  Obviously, you are free to adjust the font to your liking.

```
\documentclass{book}

%% Setup font and change it to one that handle Russian
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Noto Sans}

%% Language setup
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}

%% Graphics
\usepackage{tikz-feynman}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Уравнение Дайсона}

Рассмотрим высшие имеются общие с

this line is just for debugging purposes

\begin{enumerate}
  \item фотонные собств - диаграмм (ФСЭД)
  \item Вершинные диаграмм (ВД)
\end{enumerate}

\feynmandiagram [horizontal=a to b] {
  i1 -- [fermion] a -- [fermion] i2,
   a -- [photon] b,
  f1 -- [fermion] b -- [fermion] f2,
};
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

On the other hand, the reason why [Ti*k*Z-Feynman](http://jpellis.me/projects/tikz-feynman) ([CTAN](http://ctan.org/pkg/tikz-feynman)) is not working in LaTeX is because it doesn't have access to the Lua backend in order to automatically calculate where vertices should go.  There's more information about this over at [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/290599/26980).

Comment: The `CMU Serif` font (Computer Modern Unicode) can be a substitution for the default Latin Modern if Cyrillic or Greek text is to be typeset. It looks very similar.