# How to draw Feynman diagram for Majorana particles?

Tags: feynman

This is what I got.
[image]Here is an example. Can you help me with the second one? I am able to do all but not the cross in the center.

[image: image showing what should be drawn as Feynman diagram]

```
$0\nu\beta\beta$ 


\usepackage{feynmp}

\usepackage{ifpdf}
\ifpdf
  \DeclareGraphicsRule{*}{mps}{*}{}
\fi

\makeatletter
\def\endfmffile{%
  \fmfcmd{\p@rcent\space the end.^^J%
          end.^^J%
          endinput;}%
  \if@fmfio
    \immediate\closeout\@outfmf
  \fi 
  \IfFileExists{\thefmffile.mp}{\immediate\write18{mpost \thefmffile}}{}
  \let\thefmffile\relax
}
\makeatother

\begin{fmffile}{0nu2beta}
\begin{fmfgraph}(200,150)
\fmfpen{thick}
\fmfleft{i1,i4} 
\fmfright{o1,o2,o3,o4}
\fmf{fermion,tension=1}{i1,v1}
\fmf{fermion,tension=0.5}{v1,o1}
\fmf{fermion,tension=1}{i4,v4}
\fmf{fermion,tension=0.5}{v4,o4}
\fmf{fermion,tension=.35}{v2,o2}
\fmf{fermion,tension=.35}{v3,o3}
\fmf{fermion,tension=0.20}{v2,v3}
\fmf{fermion,tension=0.20}{v3,v2}
%\fmf{crossed}{v2,v3}
\fmf{photon,tension=0.5}{v1,v2}
\fmf{photon,tension=0.5}{v4,v3}
\fmfdot{v1,v2,v3,v4}
\end{fmfgraph} 
\end{fmffile}'
```

crossed is not working

(P.S. I know I am not using this copied code but cross should work and its not working with `\fmf{crossed}{v2,v3}` why? and how to solve it?

```
\fmfcmd{%
style_def majorana expr p =
cdraw p;
cfill (harrow (reverse p, .5));
cfill (harrow (p, .5))
enddef;
style_def alt_majorana expr p =
cdraw p;
cfill (tarrow (reverse p, .55));
cfill (tarrow (p, .55))
enddef;})
```

Comment: [Welcome!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/34551) Show us what you've done! The best way to do that is to provide a minimal document that we can compile, a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/34551).

Comment: Please be aware that not everybody is familiar with particle physics! (A majorana particle is a fermion that is its own anti-particle)

Comment: With so little in the way of information, I would suggest you look at this link and see if it solves your issue. If so, let us know. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86588/package-for-typesetting-feynman-diagrams-efficiency-of-feynmp-and-tikz

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of [`feynmp`](http://ctan.org/pkg/feynmp), there is a new package called [`tikz-feynman`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tikz-feynman) ([project page](http://www.jpellis.me/projects/tikz-feynman)) which also allows you to draw Feynman diagram.  In particular, it has support for Majorana particles and mass insertions:

```
\documentclass[convert]{standalone}

\usepackage[compat=1.1.0]{tikz-feynman}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{feynman}
    \vertex (b);
    \vertex [below=of b] (c);
    \vertex [below left=1cm and 0.4cm of c] (d);
    \vertex [above left=1cm and 0.4cm of b] (a);
    \vertex [left=of a] (i1);
    \vertex [left=of d] (i2);
    \vertex[above right of=a] (f1);
    \vertex[right of=b] (f2);
    \vertex[right of=c] (f3);
    \vertex[below right of=d] (f4);

    \diagram* {
      (a) -- [photon] (b) -- [majorana, insertion=0.5] (c) -- [photon] (d),
      (i1) -- [fermion] (a),
      (i2) -- [fermion] (d),
      (a) -- [fermion] (f1),
      (b) -- [fermion] (f2),
      (c) -- [fermion] (f3),
      (d) -- [fermion] (f4),
    };
  \end{feynman}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Answer (score 3):

[image]I just paste the code for feynmp.

```
\begin{fmfgraph*}(50,50)
\fmfleft{i0,i1,i2,i3}
\fmfright{f0,f1,f2,f3}
\fmf{fermion,label=$n$,label.side=right}{i3,v1}
\fmf{fermion,label=$p$,label.side=right}{v1,f3}
\fmf{boson,label=$W$,label.side=right,tension=0.3}{v1,v2}
\fmf{fermion,label=$e^-$,label.side=right}{v2,f2}
\fmf{phantom}{i2,v2}
\fmf{plain}{v2,v3,v4}
\fmf{phantom}{i1,v4}
\fmf{fermion,label=$e^-$,label.side=right}{v4,f1}
\fmf{boson,label=$W$,label.side=right,tension=0.3}{v4,v5}
\fmf{fermion,label=$n$,label.side=right}{i0,v5}
\fmf{fermion,label=$p$,label.side=right}{v5,f0}
\fmfdot{v1,v2,v4,v5}
\fmfv{decor.shape=cross,decor.size=.1w}{v3}
\end{fmfgraph*}
```

Answer (score 1):

I added a cross on a dummy vertex and now the code for neutrinoless double beta decay is:
[P.S. Use Astrek (with fmfgraphs) to use labels!]

```
    \documentclass[paper=a4, fontsize=11pt]{article}
    \usepackage{feynmp}
    %\usepackage{feynmf}
    \usepackage{ifpdf}
    \ifpdf
      \DeclareGraphicsRule{*}{mps}{*}{}
    \fi
    \makeatletter
    \def\endfmffile{%
      \fmfcmd{\p@rcent\space the end.^^J%
              end.^^J%
              endinput;}%
      \if@fmfio
        \immediate\closeout\@outfmf
      \fi
      \IfFileExists{\thefmffile.mp}{\immediate\write18{mpost \thefmffile}}{}
      \let\thefmffile\relax
    }
    \makeatother
    \begin{document}
    \begin{center}
    \begin{fmffile}{0nu2beta}
    \begin{fmfgraph*}(200,200)
    %\fmfpen{thick}
    \fmfleft{i1,i4} 
    \fmfright{o1,o2,o3,o4}
    \fmf{fermion,tension=.8}{i1,v1}
    \fmf{fermion,tension=0.5}{v1,o1}
    \fmf{fermion,tension=.8}{i4,v4}
    \fmf{fermion,tension=0.5}{v4,o4}
    \fmf{fermion,tension=.4}{v2,o2}
    \fmf{fermion,tension=.4}{v3,o3}
    \fmf{fermion,tension=1}{v5,v2}
    \fmf{fermion,tension=1}{v5,v3}
    \fmfv{decor.shape=cross}{v5} % This is the point where I used cross on a dummy vertex
    \fmf{photon,tension=.65,label=$W_L$}{v1,v2}
    \fmf{photon,tension=.65,label=$W_L$}{v4,v3}
    %\fmf{phantom, tension=2}{o1,o2,o3,o4,i1}
    \fmfdot{v1,v2,v3,v4}
    \fmflabel{$v_1$}{v5}
    \fmflabel{u}{o1}
    \fmflabel{$e_L$}{o2}
    \fmflabel{$e_L$}{o3}
    \fmflabel{u}{o4}
    \fmflabel{d}{i1}
    \fmflabel{d}{i4}
    \end{fmfgraph*} 
    \end{fmffile}

    \end{center} 
    \end {document}
```

There is an interesting link I found to help you with Feynman Diagrams:
[Blog for installing feynmf and feynmp packages to Miktex (with some good ref. for using these packages too)](http://adamgetchell.blogspot.in/2012/09/feynman-diagrams-in-latex.html)!

[This particular PDF is very useful to just understand above package for minimal use in Particle Physics.](https://suppiya.files.wordpress.com/2008/02/fmfsamples.pdf) 
Enjoy!

Comment: Are you aware that `feynmp-auto` package avoids you 99% of your preamble?