# Specific Feynman Diagram TikZ-Feynman Drawing

Tags: tikz-feynman

[image]

I'm new to Tex. Please help me with the coding to draw these 5 diagrams in LATEX.

Comment: Maybe https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86588/package-for-typesetting-feynman-diagrams-efficiency-of-feynmp-and-tikz could be a starting point.

Comment: All these diagrams are straightforward, but are you seriously expecting others to punch in the momenta from your hardly readable screenshot?

Comment: I can do the momenta part.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please show us, what you have done so far.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) On this site, a question should typically revolve around an abstract issue (e.g. "How do I get a double horizontal line in a table?") rather than a concrete application (e.g. "How do I make this table?"). Questions that look like "Please do this complicated thing for me" tend to get closed because they are either "off topic", "too broad", or "unclear". Please try to make your question clear and simple by giving a [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228): you'll stand a greater chance of getting help.

Answer (score 4):

I just put random momenta and corrected the directions of some of your arrows.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{tikz-feynman} 
\tikzfeynmanset{compat=1.1.0}
\begin{document}
            \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline,font=\Large]
            \begin{feynman}
            \vertex (a1);
            \vertex[right=2cm of a1] (a2);
            \vertex[right=3cm of a2] (a5); 
            \vertex[right=2cm of a5] (a6); 
            \diagram* {
            (a1) -- [scalar,edge label={\(q\)}] (a2) 
                -- [fermion, half left,fermion,edge label={\(\ell\)}] (a5) 
                -- [scalar,edge label={\(q\)}] (a6),
                (a5) -- [fermion, half left,edge label={\(\ell-q\)}] (a2)
            };
            \end{feynman}
            \end{tikzpicture}~~~
            \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline,font=\Large]
            \begin{feynman}
            \vertex (a1);
            \vertex[right=2cm of a1] (a2);
            \vertex[below=4cm of a2] (a4);
            \vertex[below=4cm of a1] (a3);
            \vertex[below right=2cm and 3cm of a2] (a5); 
            \vertex[right=2cm of a5] (a6); 
            \diagram* {
            (a1) -- [scalar,edge label={\(q_1\)}] (a2) 
                -- [fermion,edge label={\(q_1-\ell_1\)}] (a5) 
                -- [scalar,edge label={\(q\)}] (a6),
                (a5) -- [fermion,edge label={\(\ell2-q_2\)}] (a4)
                -- [fermion,edge label={\(\dots\)}] (a2),
                (a3) -- [scalar,edge label'={\(q_2\)}] (a4);
            };
            \end{feynman}
            \end{tikzpicture}

            \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline,font=\Large]
            \begin{feynman}
            \vertex (a1);
            \vertex[right=2cm of a1] (a2);
            \vertex[below=4cm of a2] (a4);
            \vertex[below=2cm of a2] (a7);
            \vertex[below=4cm of a1] (a3);
            \vertex[below right=2cm and 3cm of a2] (a5); 
            \vertex[right=2cm of a5] (a6); 
            \diagram* {
            (a1) -- [scalar,edge label={\(q_1\)}] (a2) 
                -- [fermion,edge label={\(q_1-\ell_1\)}] (a5) 
                -- [scalar,edge label={\(q\)}] (a6),
                (a5) -- [fermion,edge label={\(\ell2-q_2\)}] (a4)
                -- [fermion,edge label={\(\dots\)}] (a7) --
                [fermion,edge label={\(\dots\)}] (a2),
                (a3) -- [scalar,edge label'={\(q_2\)}] (a4),
                (a7) -- [scalar,edge label={\(\dots\)}] (a5);
            };
            \end{feynman}
            \end{tikzpicture}~~
            \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline,font=\Large]
            \begin{feynman}
            \vertex (a1);
            \vertex[right=2cm of a1] (a2);
            \vertex[right=3cm of a2] (a5); 
            \vertex[right=2cm of a5] (a6); 
            \diagram* {
            (a1) -- [scalar,edge label={\(q\)}] (a2) 
                -- [fermion, half left,fermion,edge label={\(\ell_1\)}] (a5) 
                -- [scalar,edge label={\(q\)}] (a6),
                (a5) -- [fermion, half left,edge label={\(\ell_1+\ell_2-q\)}] (a2),
                (a2) --[scalar,edge label={\(\ell_2\)}] (a5)
            };
            \end{feynman}
            \end{tikzpicture}

            \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline,font=\Large]
            \begin{feynman}
            \vertex (a1);
            \vertex[right=2cm of a1] (a2);
            \vertex[below=4cm of a2] (a4);
            \vertex[right=4cm of a2] (a7);
            \vertex[below=4cm of a1] (a3);
            \vertex[below=4cm of a7] (a5); 
            \vertex[right=2cm of a5] (a6); 
            \vertex[right=2cm of a7] (a9); 
            \diagram* {
            (a1) -- [scalar,edge label={\(q_1\)}] (a2) 
                -- [fermion,edge label={\(q_1-\ell_1\)}] (a7) 
                -- [scalar,edge label={\(q\)}] (a9),
                (a7) -- [fermion,edge label={\(\ell2-q_2\)}] (a5)
                -- [fermion,edge label={\(\dots\)}] (a4) --
                [fermion,edge label={\(\dots\)}] (a2),
                (a5) -- [scalar,edge label'={\(q_2\)}] (a6),
                (a3) -- [scalar,edge label={\(\dots\)}] (a4);
            };
            \end{feynman}
            \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Try this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,lipsum} 
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{tikz-feynman} 
\tikzfeynmanset{compat=1.1.0}
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\mycm}{0.5cm}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{center}
            \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline,font=\Large]
            \begin{feynman}
            \vertex (a1);
            \vertex[right={2*\mycm} of a1] (a2);
            \vertex[right={3*\mycm} of a2] (a5); 
            \vertex[right={2*\mycm} of a5] (a6); 
            \diagram* {
            (a1) -- [scalar,edge label={\(q\)}] (a2) 
                -- [fermion, half left,fermion,edge label={\(\ell\)}] (a5) 
                -- [scalar,edge label={\(q\)}] (a6),
                (a5) -- [fermion, half left,edge label={\(\ell-q\)}] (a2)
            };
            \end{feynman}
            \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\lipsum[2]
\begin{center}
            \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline,font=\Large]
            \begin{feynman}
            \vertex (a1);
            \vertex[right={2*\mycm} of a1] (a2);
            \vertex[below={4*\mycm} of a2] (a4);
            \vertex[below={4*\mycm} of a1] (a3);
            \vertex[below right={2*\mycm} and {3*\mycm} of a2] (a5); 
            \vertex[right={2*\mycm} of a5] (a6); 
            \diagram* {
            (a1) -- [scalar,edge label={\(q_1\)}] (a2) 
                -- [fermion,edge label={\(q_1-\ell_1\)}] (a5) 
                -- [scalar,edge label={\(q\)}] (a6),
                (a5) -- [fermion,edge label={\(\ell2-q_2\)}] (a4)
                -- [fermion,edge label={\(\dots\)}] (a2),
                (a3) -- [scalar,edge label'={\(q_2\)}] (a4);
            };
            \end{feynman}
            \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\lipsum[3]
\begin{center}
            \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline,font=\Large]
            \begin{feynman}
            \vertex (a1);
            \vertex[right={2*\mycm} of a1] (a2);
            \vertex[below={4*\mycm} of a2] (a4);
            \vertex[below={2*\mycm} of a2] (a7);
            \vertex[below={4*\mycm} of a1] (a3);
            \vertex[below right={2*\mycm} and {3*\mycm} of a2] (a5); 
            \vertex[right={2*\mycm} of a5] (a6); 
            \diagram* {
            (a1) -- [scalar,edge label={\(q_1\)}] (a2) 
                -- [fermion,edge label={\(q_1-\ell_1\)}] (a5) 
                -- [scalar,edge label={\(q\)}] (a6),
                (a5) -- [fermion,edge label={\(\ell2-q_2\)}] (a4)
                -- [fermion,edge label={\(\dots\)}] (a7) --
                [fermion,edge label={\(\dots\)}] (a2),
                (a3) -- [scalar,edge label'={\(q_2\)}] (a4),
                (a7) -- [scalar,edge label={\(\dots\)}] (a5);
            };
            \end{feynman}
            \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\lipsum[4]
\begin{center}
            \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline,font=\Large]
            \begin{feynman}
            \vertex (a1);
            \vertex[right={2*\mycm} of a1] (a2);
            \vertex[right={3*\mycm} of a2] (a5); 
            \vertex[right={2*\mycm} of a5] (a6); 
            \diagram* {
            (a1) -- [scalar,edge label={\(q\)}] (a2) 
                -- [fermion, half left,fermion,edge label={\(\ell_1\)}] (a5) 
                -- [scalar,edge label={\(q\)}] (a6),
                (a5) -- [fermion, half left,edge label={\(\ell_1+\ell_2-q\)}] (a2),
                (a2) --[scalar,edge label={\(\ell_2\)}] (a5)
            };
            \end{feynman}
            \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\lipsum[5]
\begin{center}
            \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline,font=\Large]
            \begin{feynman}
            \vertex (a1);
            \vertex[right={2*\mycm} of a1] (a2);
            \vertex[below={4*\mycm} of a2] (a4);
            \vertex[right={4*\mycm} of a2] (a7);
            \vertex[below={4*\mycm} of a1] (a3);
            \vertex[below={4*\mycm} of a7] (a5); 
            \vertex[right={2*\mycm} of a5] (a6); 
            \vertex[right={2*\mycm} of a7] (a9); 
            \diagram* {
            (a1) -- [scalar,edge label={\(q_1\)}] (a2) 
                -- [fermion,edge label={\(q_1-\ell_1\)}] (a7) 
                -- [scalar,edge label={\(q\)}] (a9),
                (a7) -- [fermion,edge label={\(\ell2-q_2\)}] (a5)
                -- [fermion,edge label={\(\dots\)}] (a4) --
                [fermion,edge label={\(\dots\)}] (a2),
                (a5) -- [scalar,edge label'={\(q_2\)}] (a6),
                (a3) -- [scalar,edge label={\(\dots\)}] (a4);
            };
            \end{feynman}
            \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

(I do not recommend it, though.)

Comment: how to remove the arrows of momenta? i don't need it

Comment: Thanks, it makes the momenta little small. Can I enlarge the text?

Comment: Thanks Sir. Another question, How can we make a line bold in these diagrams? So that I can differentiate between mass less and massive propagators.

Comment: Thanks. When I put the diagram in my document is looks larger than text, so is it possible to make the diagram small as a whole? and also make the diagram in the centre of the page?

Comment: I tried using \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.2,baseline, font=\Large] but the image had no effect.
Moreover \begin{figure}\centering\begin{tikzpicture}... this is making the image at the top centre of the page. I want it at centre but in between paragraphs.

Comment: @SumitBanik I made a final update.