# Modifying an edge in a Feynman diagram generated by tikz-feynman

Tags: tikz-feynman

Consider the following Feynman diagram:

```
% !TeX program = lualatex
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-feynman}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}

\feynmandiagram [large, horizontal=a to t1] {
    a  -- [plain,reversed momentum=\(k_1+k_2\)] t1 -- [scalar, momentum'=\(q\),edge label=\(m_1\)] t2 --[plain, momentum'=\(q+k_1\),edge label=\(m_2\)]t3 -- [plain, momentum'=\(q+k_1+k_2\),edge label=\(m_3\)]t1,
    t2 -- [plain,reversed momentum=\(k_1\)] p1 ,
    t3 -- [plain,reversed momentum=\(k_2\)] p2,
};
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image: A Feynman diagram]

Now what I want to have is that the **dotted** edge to become **semi-dotted** together with a way to specify the **orientation**.

The transformed image in one of the two possible orientations should look like:

[image: Feynman diagram with modified edge]

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my machine, your code does not reproduce your screenshot, but an upside-down version of it. However, it is rather straightforward to get the "semidashed" line. Just remember the nodes and draw the solid half-line as an overlay.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-feynman}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}

\feynmandiagram [large, horizontal=a to t1,remember picture] {
    a  -- [plain,reversed momentum=\(k_1+k_2\)] t1 
    -- [scalar, momentum=\(q\),edge label'=\(m_1\)] t2 
    --[plain, momentum=\(q+k_1\),edge label'=\(m_2\)]t3 
    -- [plain, momentum=\(q+k_1+k_2\),edge label'=\(m_3\)]t1,
    t2 -- [plain,reversed momentum=\(k_1\)] p1 ,
    t3 -- [plain,reversed momentum=\(k_2\)] p2,
};
\tikz[overlay,remember picture]{\path (t1) --(t2) coordinate[midway] (m1);
\draw[thick] (m1) --(t2);
}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! But how come it became upside down? This seems really odd.

Comment: @Subho95 I do not know for sure, but `tikz-feynman` gets continuously updated. When did you update your TeX distribution for the last time? (I stress that's just a guess.)

Comment: A while back actually

Comment: Is there a way to make a cleaner diagram? This one will work but the edge looks jagged.

Comment: @Subho95 To tell you the truth, I do not use the layout algorithms myself because I find them hard to control (plus you can't upload these on the arXiv yet). Almost the same diagram without the automatic layout can be found e.g. [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/436969/121799) (except that the OP asked me to spoil it afterwards ;-). It would be much nicer if one could adjust the tension between the vertices (which should be possible, but I never tried to find out how that works).