# Very common question: Feynman Diagrams in LaTeX

Tags: luatex, tikz-feynman, feynman

I know about a lot of solutions how to draw Feynman diagrams in `LaTeX`. Unfortunately, none of them is perfect. I know about `TikZ-Feynman` and it is the best variant (may be) but I do not understand how to work with `LuaLatex` using cyrillic and latin at the same document. Moreover, as I understand, some of math and fonts packages do not work in `LuaLatex`.

So, my questions:

1. Are there any simple & good packages for diagrams which use `pdflatex`?
2. Can anyone please give reference to source with `TikZ-Feynman & LuaLatex` where I can find all the information about math & fonts in `LuaLatex`?

If it is the duplicate question, sorry.

Comment: Have a look at [package-for-typesetting-feynman-diagrams](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86588/package-for-typesetting-feynman-diagrams-efficiency-of-feynmp-and-tikz)

Comment: My thesis was compiled with pdflatex and the (only 6 in one figure). Feynman diagram were just drawn in tikz.  They're similar to those in [Cardona and Yu]( https://www.amazon.co.uk/Fundamentals-Semiconductors-Materials-Properties-Graduate/dp/3642007090) section 7.2.5, so pretty simple.   You don't have to use a special package if you don't want to

Comment: If you read the [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/tikz-feynman/tikz-feynman.pdf) carefully you will find that you can use `tikz-feynman` without LuaTeX.

Comment: @HenriMenke , to be honest, I do not find any info about pdflatex and lualatex in the manual. Can You please give more detailed ref?

Comment: Hi, have you find a solution for your problem?

Comment: @Sebastiano yes. There are two possible way and I add the answer

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible ways to work with Tikz-Feynman in pdf-latex:

1. The simplest way is to use standalone,

```
    \documentclass{standalone}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{calc,decorations.markings,decorations.pathmorphing}
    \usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,positioning,automata,backgrounds,calc,er,patterns}
    \usepackage[compat=1.1.0]{tikz-feynman}
```

and then just use produced pdf as picture

2. The second way for me is unconvenient and unstable (I use Overleaf), it uses externalization (can be found in manual),

```
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{external}             
    \immediate\write18{mkdir -p pgf-img}
    \tikzexternalize[                    
      prefix=pgf-img/,                    
      system call={                       
        lualatex \tikzexternalcheckshellescape -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode -jobname="\image" "\texsource"
      },
    ]
```

I noticed that it does not work sometimes (especially when your file contains large number of diagrams).

Comment: Please, can you add a minimal working example of your answer adding a screenshot?