# Drawing simple Feynman diagrams with feynhand.sty

Tags: overleaf, tikz-feynman

I just started TeXing feynman diagrams using Overleaf. I am using [tikz-feynhand.sty](https://ctan.org/pkg/tikz-feynhand?lang=en) which allows me to compile with pdflatex. I would like to write the following graph

```
\documentclass[reqno]{amsart}
 \usepackage{tikz-feynhand}
 \begin{document}
 \begin{equation}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{feynhand}
   \vertex[ringdot,label=above:{s}] (v) at (0,0) {};
    \vertex[right=of v] (f1) ; 
    \vertex [above left=of v] (i1);
    \vertex [below left=of v] (i2);
    \propag [fermion, momentum'=\(p_1\)] (i1) to (v);
    \propag [anti fermion,momentum'=\(p_2\)] (i2) to (v);
    \propag [boson, momentum'=\(p_3\)] (v) to (f1);
 \end{feynhand}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

In shorthand notation, similarly as it can be found in [this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86588/package-for-typesetting-feynman-diagrams-efficiency-of-feynmp-and-tikz). The reason, I'm not using `tikz-feynman` is that it requires `luatex`. I tried using `\graph`, but I struggle getting vertices displayed correctly, including the above used ringdot-style, e.g.. Thank you very much in advance!
P.S.: How can I display latex output, including `tikz` in this forum?

Comment: Welcome. I get [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dfqLN.png). What's the problem?

Comment: I’d like to write it in shorthand notation like `\graph{ (i1) — [fermion] (v)[ringdot] — [boson](f1),(i2)—[anti fermion] (v)};`.  Unfortunately, this doesn’t give me the correct output.