# drawing diagram from the circle

Tags: tikz-pgf, circles, feynman

I am trying to wrap the following diagram in a circle and I am facing some problems. I am using the some codes from, [Wrapping a Feynman diagram in an ellipse or a circle?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/106073/wrapping-a-feynman-diagram-in-an-ellipse-or-a-circle) , but I cannot make the lower line touch the perimeter. How can I make it look nice and symmetric?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,arrows,fit}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{
particle/.style={thick,draw=blue, postaction={decorate},
    decoration={markings,mark=at position .5 with {\arrow[blue]{triangle 45}}}},
gluon/.style={decorate, draw=black,
    decoration={coil,aspect=0}}
 }

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1.5cm and 1.5cm]
\coordinate[label={[xshift=-2pt]left:$e^{-}$}] (e1);
\coordinate[below right=of e1] (aux1);
\coordinate[above right=of aux1,label={[xshift=6pt]right:$e^{-}$}] (e2);
\coordinate[below=2cm of aux1] (aux2);


\draw[particle] (e1) -- (aux1);
\draw[particle] (aux1) -- (e2);

\draw[gluon] (aux1) -- node[label=right:$\gamma$] {} (aux2);
\node[draw,line width=2pt,circle,fit=(e1)(e2) (aux2),inner sep=.5\pgflinewidth] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Any help would be useful.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Answer (score 3):

The `fit` command fits the text box inside the `circle` node, which is rectangular in shape and only coincides with the circle outline at its corners (try replacing `circle` with `rectangle` in your code to see the shape of the text area).

You could work around this by drawing the circle manually using some trigonometry:

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,arrows,fit}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{
particle/.style={thick,draw=blue, postaction={decorate},
    decoration={markings,mark=at position .5 with {\arrow[blue]{triangle 45}}}},
gluon/.style={decorate, draw=black,
    decoration={coil,aspect=0}}
 }

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1.5cm and 1.5cm]
\coordinate[label={[xshift=-2pt]left:$e^{-}$}] (e1);
\coordinate[below right=of e1] (aux1);
\coordinate[above right=of aux1,label={[xshift=6pt]right:$e^{-}$}] (e2);
\coordinate[below=1/cos(45)*1.5cm of aux1] (aux2);


\draw[particle] (e1) -- (aux1);
\draw[particle] (aux1) -- (e2);

\draw[gluon] (aux1) -- node[label=right:$\gamma$] {} (aux2);
\draw  [ultra thick] (aux1) circle [radius=sqrt(1.5cm^2+1.5cm^2)];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I am new to tikzpicture. Thanks for the great pointers. Another thing I am struggling with is to put two figures adjacent to one another by perhaps putting an arrow sign ->.  Is there a simple way?

Comment: @Diagramsandlines [Welcome to TeX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) You should ask this as a [new question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) and accept this answer if it solved the original question.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with the new [`tikz-feynman`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tikz-feynman) package (see also the [project page](http://www.jpellis.me/projects/tikz-feynman/)), based on [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/87395/31416).  The only requirement for using automatic positioning of the vertices is to compile the document with `lualatex`:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage[compat=1.1.0]{tikz-feynman}
\begin{document}
\tikzfeynmanset{
  every fermion={blue},
  every anti fermion={blue},
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{feynman}
    \vertex (a);
    \vertex [above left=of a] (b) {\(\textup{e}^{-}\)};
    \vertex [above right=of a] (c) {\(\textup{e}^{-}\)};
    \vertex [below=of a] (d);
    \diagram*{
      (b) -- [fermion] (a),
      (c) -- [anti fermion] (a),
      (a)  -- [photon,edge label=\(\gamma\)] (d),
    };
    \draw[red,thick] (a) circle (1.518);
  \end{feynman}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: I'm the author of [Ti*k*Z-Feynman](http://www.jpellis.me/projects/tikz-feynman)!  It's amazing to see it being used.  Thanks @giordano!