# To wrap the external lines so that it can touch the perimeter

Tags: diagrams, circles

Similar to this, [Wrapping a Feynman diagram in an ellipse or a circle?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/106073/wrapping-a-feynman-diagram-in-an-ellipse-or-a-circle/106078?noredirect=1#comment231051_106078), I am having some in tikz problem making sure the legs of these diagrams touching the perimeter. I tried the following, but I am not quite able to do it. Will somebody kindly help me draw these kind of diagrams?

```
\begin{center}
\tikzset{
particle/.style={decorate, draw=black,
    decoration={aspect=0.08,segment length=3pt,amplitude=3pt}}}\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1cm and 1.5cm]
\coordinate (e1);
```

\coordinate[below left=of e1] (aux6);
\coordinate[below right=of aux6] (aux7);
\coordinate[below left=of aux7] (aux8);

\coordinate[below=1cm of aux1] (aux);

\draw[particle] (aux7) -- (aux6);
\draw[particle] (aux7) -- (aux8);
\draw[particle] (aux7) -- (aux);
\draw[particle] (aux7) -- (aux8);
\draw[particle] (e1) -- (aux1);
\draw[particle] (aux1) -- (e2);
\draw[particle] (e3) -- (aux2);
\draw[particle] (aux2) -- (e4);
\draw[particle] (aux1) -- node {} (aux2);
\node[draw,name path=circle,line width=3pt,circle,fit=(e1) (e4) (aux7) (aux8),inner sep=.5\pgflinewidth] {};
%\path[name intersections={of=circle and diameter, by={aux3}}];% find the intersection
\draw[particle] (aux) -- (aux3);
%\draw[particle] (aux2) -- (aux3);
%\draw[particle] (aux3) -- (aux1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
[image: I am interested in having these diagrams touching the perimeter]

Comment: Please complete your code to a *complete* document.

Comment: You have a line `\coordinate[below=1cm of aux1] (aux);` that says "Put node `aux` 1cm below the node `aux1`", but you haven't defined the node `aux1` already. There are several other instance of this type of error in your code.

Comment: With an incomplete MWE and errors, this is not going to be answered. Could be either 'unclear' or 'off topic' for those reasons.