# Drawing specific Feynman diagram with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, feynman

I would like to draw the Feynman diagram shown in the picture below with [TikZ](http://arxiv.org/abs/1601.05437).

Edit: The code I have so far is

```
\tikzfeynmanset{
every vertex/.style={red, dot},
every blob/.style={draw=green!40!black, pattern color=green!40!black},
every crossed dot/.style={blue},
}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{feynman}
\vertex (a) {\(\nu\)};
\vertex [below right=of a] (b);
\vertex [below left=of b] (f1) {\(\bar{\nu}\)};
\vertex [above right=of b] (f2);
\vertex [below right=of b] (f3);
\diagram* {
(a) -- [fermion] (b)[blob] -- [fermion] (f1),
(b) -- [anti fermion,bend left,edge label=\(\bar{\nu}\)] (f2)[crossed dot],
(b) -- [anti fermion,bend left,edge label=\(\bar{\nu}\)] (f3)[crossed dot],
(b) -- [fermion,bend right,edge label'=\(\nu\)] (f2)[crossed dot],
(b) -- [fermion,bend right,edge label'=\(\nu\)] (f3)[crossed dot]
};
\end{feynman}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

However, where the blob and the crossed dots should be, there are still simple vertices. How can I implement the blob and the two "condensate" vertices? Thanks for your help!

[image]

Comment: Neutrino - pair annihilation?

Comment: The blob is an instanton, the crosses are condensates.

Comment: Suggest you both search this site for "feynman diagram" as there are nearly 100 results.  A useful one could be http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22622/feynman-diagrams-with-tikz.   And there is a nice Feynman example in this gallery http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/area/physics/

Comment: I know how to draw simple Feynman diagrams, but I haven't found this specific one anywhere.

Comment: Since you already know how to draw simple diagrams, can you post same sample code of where exactly are you stuck?  In any case, the commented examples in [github.com/fliptanedo/tikzfeynman.sty](https://github.com/fliptanedo/tikzfeynman.sty) might help you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the "invisible edges" strategy suggested in `tikz-feynman` manual.  Compile with LuaLaTeX

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-feynman}
\begin{document}
\feynmandiagram [vertical=f1 to f2] {
  anu [particle=\(\overline{\nu}\)] -- [fermion] b [blob],
  nu  [particle=\(\nu\)] -- [fermion] b,
  b   -- [fermion,bend right=10,edge label'=\(\nu\)] f1 [crossed dot],
  b   -- [fermion,bend left=10,edge label=\(\overline{\nu}\)] f1,
  b   -- [fermion,bend right=10,edge label'=\(\nu\)] f2 [crossed dot],
  b   -- [fermion,bend left=10,edge label=\(\overline{\nu}\)] f2,
  % In the picture below I used "[opacity=0.2]" in place of "[draw=none]" to
  % show where the edges are.
  nu  -- [draw=none] anu,
  f1  -- [draw=none] f2,
};
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I get an error when compiling it with LuaLaTex: `! LuaTeX error ./tikzfeynman.patch.lua:966: unknown phase`

Comment: Which version of the package do you have?  How did you install it?

Comment: It's the current version v1.0.0 downloaded [here](https://github.com/JP-Ellis/tikz-feynman/releases/tag/v1.0.0). I put the .sty file into the folder where I have my .tex document, that's it. When I compile the version you can see in my edit, everything works perfectly fine.

Comment: The package is on CTAN, you can install from your package manager.  That's what I'm using.

Comment: Unfortunately I have to use a Mac and don't find any package manager here... Shouldn't it also work the way I did it?

Comment: I meant the package manager of your TeX distribution.  I guess you have Mac TeX, right?

Comment: Yes. How do I install the package? I tried the suggestions [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Installing_Extra_Packages) but it didn't work.

Comment: I'm not familiar with OS X and I'm not going to help you (simply because I don't know it), but try to see here: http://mactex-wiki.tug.org/wiki/index.php/TeX_Live_Manager  If you don't find anything else on the Internet ask another question for how to install a package with MacTeX.  You may also ask to `tikz-feynman` author  on GitHub why you get that error.

Comment: I managed it to install the package, but the error is still there. Are you sure that there is no mistake in the code? My own one works perfectly...

Comment: Yes, I'm sure, I copied and pasted the code I used, now I copied and pasted the code above (just to make sure I didn't introduce typos while copying before posting), compiled it, and works just fine (no error), the result is the picture above.  I'd suggest you to open an issue on GitHub.

Comment: Try also the [first version](https://tex.stackexchange.com/revisions/290825/1) of the answer, it was worse looking but the idea is the same.  Does it work for you?

Comment: I updated all packages, and finally all your versions work - thanks a lot for your help!