# TikZ exercises

Tags: tikz-pgf, xy-pic, exercises

I am not sure that this is a right fit for SE, but I will risk it.

I was recently acquainting myself with the [`xy-pic` package](http://xy-pic.sourceforge.net/), and I found the included exercises very helpful in getting up to speed with the package.

It made me think how great it would be to have a set of TikZ exercises that aided getting used to the TikZ package since the size of that package has always daunted me.

I have been collecting TikZ examples over time, but I don't think it would provide the logical development that a set of well-constructed, consistent exercises might provide.

Any pointers to resources welcome.

Comment: The first part of the manual is "Tutorials and Guidelines". You could treat it as an exercise by typing along the tutorials.

Comment: For more advanced users [TeXample](http://www.texample.net/) might be nice. Another option is to look up things done in PSTricks (including this site) and recreate them in TikZ, then post the answer and wait for feedback.

Comment: I find the tutorials in the PGF manual much better than those especially for the `\xymatrix` part of the `xy` package. Besides the manual, TeXample and {[tag:tikz-pgf]} do we need another place for TikZ examples? There was also this: [Summary of Tikz commands](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/84753)

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15779/materials-for-learning-tikz, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9116/what-is-the-minimum-one-needs-to-know-to-use-tikz

Comment: As it stands, I think this is too broad. TikZ is bif, but we can't hope to cover a tutorial-like approach to the entire thing in one question. Perhaps focus on one area.