# TikZ - Four Colored Circle Split

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs

Following @Alain Matthes's reply on [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55594/tikz-two-colored-circle-split), wa can get a picture like this:

[image]

I am not good enough to adapt the code to split the circle into 4 quarters. Can you help me?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,backgrounds,calc}

% Two Colored Circle Split 
\makeatletter
\tikzset{circle split part fill/.style  args={#1,#2}{%
 alias=tmp@name, 
  postaction={%
    insert path={
     \pgfextra{% 
     \pgfpointdiff{\pgfpointanchor{\pgf@node@name}{center}}%
                  {\pgfpointanchor{\pgf@node@name}{east}}%            
     \pgfmathsetmacro\insiderad{\pgf@x}
      \fill[#1] (\pgf@node@name.base) ([xshift=-\pgflinewidth]\pgf@node@name.east) arc
                          (0:180:\insiderad-\pgflinewidth)--cycle;
      \fill[#2] (\pgf@node@name.base) ([xshift=\pgflinewidth]\pgf@node@name.west)  arc
                           (180:360:\insiderad-\pgflinewidth)--cycle;            
         }}}}}  
 \makeatother  


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[minimum size=4cm, 
    shape=circle split,
    draw=blue!70,line width=2mm,
    circle split part fill={blue!50, red!50}
    ] at (0.5, 1.5) {1\nodepart{lower} 2};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you want/need a node shape with four node parts? Maybe [Basic geometric shapes, sections, shading](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/119344) is related (my answer anyway).

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel:Yes, I would like a node shape with four node parts. I will have a look there. Thanks!

Comment: How should the text boxes be aligned horizontal? (Consider text boxed with different widths.)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The following code defines a `circle cross split` shape with the node parts and their short-hands

- `text`,
- `two` = `tr`,
- `three` = `br`, and
- `four` = `bl`.

It requires the `shapes.multipart` library (which also provides the PGF node part boxes which are `\let` to the corresponding short-hands) and needs:

- the list processor `\pgf@lib@sh@rs@process@list`;
- the macros `\pgf@lib@sh@getalpha` and `\pgf@lib@sh@toalpha` to convert `1`, `2`, … in `one`, `two`, …;
- `\pgf@lib@sh@rs@nonetext` which simply contains `none` so that one can selectively disable the filling for one of the quarters.

The text boxes are “center-aligned”. This means that one of the corners of the text boxes will be stuffed in the center corner from the cross (the inner separators are included).

The two upper parts and the two lower parts are base-aligned respectively.

#### Further improvement:

- Align options for node parts that are below/above each other.
- The third example and the second example with `inner sep=+0pt` show that the dimension of the text boxes are not really correctly used in the calculation of the radius of the circle. With empty inner separators, the shape border will cross the boxes.
- ?

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}
\makeatletter
\let\pgfnodeparttrbox\pgfnodeparttwobox
\let\pgfnodepartblbox\pgfnodepartthreebox
\let\pgfnodepartbrbox\pgfnodepartfourbox
\newif\ifpgfcirclecrosssplitcustomfill
\tikzset{%
  circle cross split part fill/.code=%
    \def\pgf@lib@sh@ccs@list@fill{#1}\pgfcirclecrosssplitcustomfilltrue,%
  circle cross split uses custom fill/.is if=pgfcirclecrosssplitcustomfill}
\pgfdeclareshape{circle cross split}{%
  \nodeparts{text,two,three,four}%
  \savedanchor\centerpoint{%
    \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@xa{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner xsep}}%
    \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@ya{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner ysep}}%
    \pgf@x =\wd\pgfnodeparttextbox
    \pgf@yb=\dp\pgfnodeparttextbox
    \pgf@y=\dp\pgfnodeparttwobox
    \ifdim\pgf@yb>\pgf@y
      \pgf@y=\pgf@yb
    \fi
    \advance\pgf@x\pgf@xa
    \advance\pgf@y-\pgf@ya
    \advance\pgf@x.5\pgflinewidth
    \advance\pgf@y-.5\pgflinewidth
  }%
  \savedanchor\twoanchor{%
    \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@xa{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner xsep}}%
    \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@ya{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner ysep}}%
    \advance\pgf@x.5\pgflinewidth
    \advance\pgf@x\pgf@xa
    \advance\pgf@y.5\pgflinewidth
    \advance\pgf@y\pgf@ya
    \pgf@yb\dp\pgfnodeparttextbox
    \pgf@yc\dp\pgfnodeparttwobox
    \ifdim\pgf@yb>\pgf@yc
      \pgf@yc\pgf@yb
    \fi
    \advance\pgf@y\pgf@yc
  }%
  \savedanchor\threeanchor{%
    \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@ya{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner ysep}}%
    \pgf@x\wd\pgfnodeparttextbox
    \pgf@yb\dp\pgfnodeparttextbox
    \pgf@yc\dp\pgfnodeparttwobox
    \ifdim\pgf@yb>\pgf@yc
      \pgf@yc\pgf@yb
    \fi
    \advance\pgf@y-\pgf@yc
    \advance\pgf@y-2\pgf@ya
    \advance\pgf@y-\pgflinewidth
    \pgf@yb\ht\pgfnodepartthreebox
    \pgf@yc\ht\pgfnodepartfourbox
    \ifdim\pgf@yb>\pgf@yc
      \pgf@yc\pgf@yb
    \fi
    \advance\pgf@y-\pgf@yc
    \advance\pgf@x-\wd\pgfnodepartthreebox
  }%
  \savedanchor\fouranchor{%
    \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@xa{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner xsep}}%
    \advance\pgf@x\wd\pgfnodepartthreebox
    \advance\pgf@x2\pgf@xa
    \advance\pgf@x\pgflinewidth
  }%
  \saveddimen\radius{%
    % height:
    \pgf@y\ht\pgfnodeparttextbox
    \pgf@yb\ht\pgfnodeparttwobox
    \ifdim\pgf@yb>\pgf@y
      \pgf@y\pgf@yb
    \fi
    \pgf@yc\dp\pgfnodeparttextbox
    \pgf@yb\dp\pgfnodeparttwobox
    \ifdim\pgf@yc>\pgf@yb
      \advance\pgf@y\pgf@yc
    \else
      \advance\pgf@y\pgf@yb
    \fi
    \pgf@yb\ht\pgfnodepartthreebox
    \ifdim\pgf@yb<\ht\pgfnodepartfourbox
      \pgf@yb\ht\pgfnodepartfourbox
    \fi
    \pgf@yc\dp\pgfnodepartthreebox
    \ifdim\pgf@yc<\dp\pgfnodepartfourbox
      \advance\pgf@yb\dp\pgfnodepartfourbox
    \else
      \advance\pgf@yb\pgf@yc
    \fi
    \ifdim\pgf@yc>\pgf@y
      \pgf@y\pgf@yc
    \fi
    \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@ya{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner ysep}}%
    \advance\pgf@y2\pgf@ya
    %
    \pgf@x\wd\pgfnodeparttextbox
    \pgf@xa\wd\pgfnodepartthreebox
    \pgf@xb\wd\pgfnodeparttwobox
    \pgf@xc\wd\pgfnodepartfourbox
    \ifdim\pgf@xa>\pgf@x
      \pgf@x\pgf@xa
    \fi
    \ifdim\pgf@xb>\pgf@x
      \pgf@x\pgf@xb
    \fi
    \ifdim\pgf@xc>\pgf@x
      \pgf@x\pgf@xc
    \fi
    \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@xa{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/inner xsep}}%
    \advance\pgf@x2\pgf@xa
    \ifdim\pgf@y>\pgf@x
      \pgf@x\pgf@y
    \fi
    \advance\pgf@x.5\pgflinewidth
    %
    \pgfmathsetlength{\pgf@xb}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/minimum width}}%
    \pgfmathsetlength{\pgf@yb}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/minimum height}}%
    \ifdim\pgf@x<.5\pgf@xb
        \pgf@x=.5\pgf@xb
    \fi
    \ifdim\pgf@x<.5\pgf@yb
        \pgf@x=.5\pgf@yb
    \fi
    %
    \pgfmathsetlength{\pgf@xb}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer xsep}}%
    \pgfmathsetlength{\pgf@yb}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer ysep}}%
    \ifdim\pgf@xb<\pgf@yb
      \advance\pgf@x\pgf@yb
    \else
      \advance\pgf@x\pgf@xb
    \fi
  }%
  \inheritanchorborder[from=circle]%
  \inheritanchor[from=circle]{north}%
  \inheritanchor[from=circle]{north west}%
  \inheritanchor[from=circle]{north east}%
  \inheritanchor[from=circle]{center}%
  \inheritanchor[from=circle]{west}%
  \inheritanchor[from=circle]{east}%
  \inheritanchor[from=circle]{mid}%
  \inheritanchor[from=circle]{mid west}%
  \inheritanchor[from=circle]{mid east}%
  \inheritanchor[from=circle]{base}%
  \inheritanchor[from=circle]{base west}%
  \inheritanchor[from=circle]{base east}%
  \inheritanchor[from=circle]{south}%
  \inheritanchor[from=circle]{south west}%
  \inheritanchor[from=circle]{south east}%
  \anchor{two}{\twoanchor}%
  \anchor{three}{\threeanchor}%
  \anchor{four}{\fouranchor}%
  \inheritbackgroundpath[from=circle]
  \beforebackgroundpath{%
    \pgfutil@tempdima=\radius
    \pgfmathsetlength{\pgf@xb}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer xsep}}%
    \pgfmathsetlength{\pgf@yb}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer ysep}}%
    \ifdim\pgf@xb<\pgf@yb
      \advance\pgfutil@tempdima by-\pgf@yb
    \else
      \advance\pgfutil@tempdima by-\pgf@xb
    \fi
    \advance\pgfutil@tempdima by-.5\pgflinewidth%
    \pgfsetshortenstart{0pt}%
    \pgfsetshortenend{0pt}%
    \pgfsetarrows{-}%
    \pgfpathmoveto
      {\pgfpointadd{\centerpoint}{\pgfqpoint{-\pgfutil@tempdima}{0pt}}}%
    \pgfpathlineto
      {\pgfpointadd{\centerpoint}{\pgfqpoint{\pgfutil@tempdima}{0pt}}}%
    \pgfpathmoveto
      {\pgfpointadd{\centerpoint}{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{-\pgfutil@tempdima}}}%
    \pgfpathlineto
      {\pgfpointadd{\centerpoint}{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{\pgfutil@tempdima}}}%
    \pgfusepathqstroke
  }%
  \behindbackgroundpath{%
    \pgfutil@tempdima=\radius
    \pgfmathsetlength{\pgf@xb}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer xsep}}%  
    \pgfmathsetlength{\pgf@yb}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer ysep}}%  
    \ifdim\pgf@xb<\pgf@yb
      \advance\pgfutil@tempdima by-\pgf@yb
    \else
      \advance\pgfutil@tempdima by-\pgf@xb
    \fi
    \advance\pgfutil@tempdima by-.5\pgflinewidth%
    \ifpgfcirclecrosssplitcustomfill%
      \pgf@lib@sh@rs@process@list{\pgf@lib@sh@ccs@list@fill}{4}%
      {%
        \pgfmathloop
           \ifnum\pgfmathcounter>4%
           \else%
             \pgf@lib@sh@getalpha\pgf@lib@sh@rs@number{\pgfmathcounter}%
              \edef\pgf@tempa
                {\csname pgf@lib@sh@rs@\pgf@lib@sh@rs@number @item\endcsname}%
              \ifx\pgf@tempa\pgf@lib@sh@rs@nonetext\else
                \pgfsetfillcolor{\pgf@tempa}%
                \pgf@lib@sh@ccs@angles{\pgfmathcounter}%
                \pgfpathmoveto{\centerpoint}%
                \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointadd{\centerpoint}
                  {\pgfqpointpolar{\pgf@lib@sh@ccs@angle}{\pgfutil@tempdima}}}%
                \pgfpatharc{\pgf@lib@sh@ccs@angle}{\pgf@lib@sh@ccs@angle@}
                  {\pgfutil@tempdima}%
                \pgfpathclose
                \pgfusepathqfill
              \fi
        \repeatpgfmathloop
      }%
    \fi}}
\def\pgf@lib@sh@ccs@angles#1{%
  \ifcase#1\or\def\pgf@lib@sh@ccs@angle{90}%
           \or\def\pgf@lib@sh@ccs@angle{0}%
           \or\def\pgf@lib@sh@ccs@angle{180}%
           \else\def\pgf@lib@sh@ccs@angle{270}%
  \fi
  \edef\pgf@lib@sh@ccs@angle@{\number\numexpr\pgf@lib@sh@ccs@angle+90\relax}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\tikz {
  \node at (3,2) [
    line width=6pt,
    circle cross split,
    draw=gray!50,
    minimum size=5cm,
    circle cross split part fill={green,blue,red,yellow!90!black}
  ] (s) {text \nodepart{two} two \nodepart{three} three \nodepart{four} four};
\foreach \anchor/\placement in {
    north west/above left, north/above, north east/above right,
    west/left, center/left, east/right,
    mid west/left, mid/above, mid east/right,
    base west/left, base/below, base east/right,
    south west/below left, south/below, south east/below right,
    text/left, two/below right, three/below, four/below right}
  \draw[shift=(s.\anchor)] plot[mark=x] coordinates{(0,0)}
    node[\placement] {\scriptsize\texttt{(s.\anchor)}};
}

\fboxsep=-.4pt
\fboxrule=.4pt
\tikz
  \node [
    circle cross split,
    draw,
    circle cross split part fill={green,blue,red,yellow!90!black},
%    inner sep=+0pt
  ] (s) {\fbox{text} \nodepart{tr} \fbox{two} \nodepart{bl} \fbox{three} \nodepart{br} \fbox{four}};

\tikz\node[opacity=.5,text=blue,draw,circle cross split,inner sep=+0pt] {
                \rule{4em}{4em}
  \nodepart{tr} \rule{4em}{4em}
  \nodepart{bl} \rule{4em}{4em}
  \nodepart{br} \rule{4em}{4em}};
\end{document}
```

### Output

#### Example 2 and 3

[image] [image]

#### Example 1 (the anchors)

[image]

Comment: Using the exact code from the link but using \node at (4,,4) instead of just \node leads to the text node label not being shifted accordingly. In fact, the entire mid anchor refuses to get shifted. How do I correct this?

Comment: @TushantMittal I know it has been quite a while but I fixed the mistake. The dimension `\pgf@y` was never initialized inside the definition of `\centerpoint`.

Answer (score 6):

### PSTricks

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\psset{dimen=medusa}
\begin{pspicture}(-3,-3)(3,3)
    \psclip{\pscircle{3}}
        \psframe*[linecolor=red](-3,0)(0,3)
        \psframe*[linecolor=green](0,0)(3,-3)
    \endpsclip
    \pscircle{3}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

### Tikz

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=12pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \clip (0,0) circle (3);
    \begin{scope}
        \fill[red] (-3,0) rectangle (0,3);
        \fill[green] (0,0) rectangle (3,-3);
    \end{scope}
    \draw (0,0) circle (3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Although this draws a circle with four parts, it doesn't really achieve the same thing as the original answer which creates a circle node with two parts, each of which is a node.

Comment: Thanks, this looks great. However, @Alan is right. For the moment, I only upgrade, and I will accept your nice answer if nothing else really fits my request.