# A question about the \draw command

Tags: tikz-pgf

The following code is not compiled.  I got it out of the manual.  Please tell me what is wrong with it. Also, please tell me where in the manual the options in the command `node(b)[circle, draw]{A circle};` are explained.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles,positioning,intersections,quotes,decorations.markings}


\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\path (0,0) node(a)[ellipse, rotate=10, draw]{An ellipse} (3,-1) node(b)[circle, draw]{A circle};
\draw[thick](node cs:name=a) -- (node cs:name=b);
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Comment: `\usetikzlibrary{shapes}`

Comment: In the manual, usually the commands in the code examples are liked to their explanation and by clicking them you will jump right to the page where they are explained.

Comment: @Jake That should be an answer. :P

Comment: @Jake  Yes, adding the `shapes` package allowed the code to be compiled.

Comment: @Benedikt Bauer   I got the code from page 136 of the manual.  No links to the options.  What does the option `draw` do to the declaration `node`?  I did not find it in the manual.

Comment: @PaulGessler Do you have a duplicate for the other part of the question? Or are you suggesting the user should ask that separately?

Comment: @cfr sure, how about [Summary of Tikz commands](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/84753) ?

Comment: @PaulGessler That's awesome, though a cheat sheet would be really nice...