# how to control the labels' position precisely in flowchart?

Tags: tikz-pgf, flow-charts

I want to draw a flow chart like this:
[image]

but I can only draw the following picture:

[image]

I can not control the labels position precisely, and I don't know how to draw a arrow from one  node to the middle of the other arrow; how to draw line between labels(the left red line between labels.
And this flowchart looks not beautiful, who have more beautiful flowchart example?

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{inputenc}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,chains}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,matrix,scopes}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    [auto,
        decision/.style={rectangle, draw=blue, thick, fill=blue!20,text width=5.2em, text centered, rounded corners,minimum height=1.2em},
        block/.style={rectangle, draw=blue, thick, fill=blue!20,text width=10.2em, text centered, rounded corners,minimum height=1.2em},
        block1/.style={rectangle, draw=blue, thick, fill=blue!20,text width=11.2em, text centered, rounded corners,minimum height=1.2em},
        line/.style={draw, thick, -latex', shorten >=2pt},
        cloud/.style={rectangle, draw=red, thick, fill=red!20,text width=1.2em, text centered, rounded corners,minimum height=4.2em}]
    \matrix [column sep=5mm,row sep=5mm,ampersand replacement=\&]
      {
      % row 1
          \&  \node [block] (r1){abcdefghi}; \& \\
        % row2
        \node [block] (r21){abcd}; \&
         \node [decision] (r22){abcdef}; \&
        \node [decision] (r23){abcdefg}; \\
      % row 3
        \node [block] (r31) {abcdefgh}; \& 
        \node [decision] (r32) {abcdefghijkl}; \&
        \node [decision] (r33) {abcdegfhij}; \&\\
      % row 4
          \node [block] (r4){abcedef}; \&\\
          % row 5
          \node [block] (r5) {abcdefgh}; \& \\
      % row 6
       \node [block] (r6) {abvdfasdfsdfdsafsadf}; \& \\
      % row 7
       \& \hspace{-3em} \node [block1] (r7){sdfsdfsdfs}; \& \\
          % row 8
          \node [block] (r8){dfassdfsdf}; \& \\
         % row 9
          \node [block] (r9){dfsdfsdf}; \& \\
         % row 10
        \node [block] (r10){dsfasdf}; \& \\
      };
\begin{scope}[every path/.style=line]
  \path   (r1)-- (r21);
  \path   (r1)-- (r22);
    \path   (r1)-- (r23);
      \path   (r21)-- (r31);
  \path   (r22)-- (r32);
    \path   (r23)-- (r33);
      \path   (r31)-- (r4);
  \path   (r4)-- (r5);
    \path   (r5)--node[right]{abce} (r6);
      \path   (r6)-- (r8);
  \path   (r8)-- (r9);
    \path   (r9)-- (r10);
  \path   (r5)-| node[near end]{bded} (r32);
\end{scope}
% the labels on the left
    \begin{scope}[node distance=7mm]
\node[cloud,below left=-50mm of r1.north west]{a\\b};         
\node[cloud,below left=-50mm and 11mm of r31.north west]{a\\b\\d\\d};
\node[cloud,below left=-50mm and 11mm of r6.north west]{a\\e\\f\\g\\h};
\node[cloud,below left=-50mm and 11mm of r9.north west]{a\\b\\c\\d};
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to understand following solution. It's just one possibility.

```
  \path (r7)->(r7-|r6); %<---- New line
```

draws a line from `r7` to intersection between `r7` and `r6` centers.

```
\node[cloud, above left=0mm and 7mm of r21.south west] (ab) {a\\b};
```

draws a cloud node 7mm left of `r21.south west` using `south east` (due to `above left`) as node anchor.

```
\node[cloud] at (ab|-r4) (abdd) {a\\b\\d\\d};
```

this one is easy if you understood the first.

For red lines, play a little bit until you obtain the desired result:

```
\draw[thick, red] ([shift={(3mm,-2mm)}]ab.south east)--+(180:13mm);
```

[image]

This is the complete code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{inputenc}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,chains}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,matrix,scopes}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    [auto,
        decision/.style={rectangle, draw=blue, thick, fill=blue!20,text width=5.2em, text centered, rounded corners,minimum height=1.2em},
        block/.style={rectangle, draw=blue, thick, fill=blue!20,text width=10.2em, text centered, rounded corners,minimum height=1.2em},
        block1/.style={rectangle, draw=blue, thick, fill=blue!20,text width=11.2em, text centered, rounded corners,minimum height=1.2em},
        line/.style={draw, thick, -latex', shorten >=2pt},
        cloud/.style={rectangle, draw=red, thick, fill=red!20,text width=1.2em, text centered, rounded corners,minimum height=4.2em}]
    \matrix [column sep=5mm,row sep=5mm,ampersand replacement=\&]
      {
      % row 1
          \&  \node [block] (r1){abcdefghi}; \& \\
        % row2
        \node [block] (r21){abcd}; \&
         \node [decision] (r22){abcdef}; \&
        \node [decision] (r23){abcdefg}; \\
      % row 3
        \node [block] (r31) {abcdefgh}; \& 
        \node [decision] (r32) {abcdefghijkl}; \&
        \node [decision] (r33) {abcdegfhij}; \&\\
      % row 4
          \node [block] (r4){abcedef}; \&\\
          % row 5
          \node [block] (r5) {abcdefgh}; \& \\
      % row 6
       \node [block] (r6) {abvdfasdfsdfdsafsadf}; \& \\
      % row 7
       \& \hspace{-3em} \node [block1] (r7){sdfsdfsdfs}; \& \\
          % row 8
          \node [block] (r8){dfassdfsdf}; \& \\
         % row 9
          \node [block] (r9){dfsdfsdf}; \& \\
         % row 10
        \node [block] (r10){dsfasdf}; \& \\
      };
\begin{scope}[every path/.style=line]
  \path   (r1)-- (r21);
  \path   (r1)-- (r22);
    \path   (r1)-- (r23);
      \path   (r21)-- (r31);
  \path   (r22)-- (r32);
    \path   (r23)-- (r33);
      \path   (r31)-- (r4);
  \path   (r4)-- (r5);
    \path   (r5)--node[right]{abce} (r6);
      \path   (r6)-- (r8);
  \path   (r8)-- (r9);
    \path   (r9)-- (r10);
  \path   (r5)-| node[near end]{bded} (r32); 
  \path (r7)->(r7-|r6); %<---- New line
\end{scope}
% the labels on the left
\node[cloud, above left=0mm and 7mm of r21.south west] (ab) {a\\b};         
\node[cloud] at (ab|-r4) (abdd) {a\\b\\d\\d};
\node[cloud] at (ab|-r7) (aefgh) {a\\e\\f\\g\\h};
\node[cloud] at (ab|-r10) (abcd) {a\\b\\c\\d};

%red line
\draw[thick, red] ([shift={(3mm,-2mm)}]ab.south east)--+(180:13mm);
\draw[thick, red] ([shift={(3mm,2mm)}]aefgh.north east)--+(180:13mm);
\draw[thick, red] ([shift={(3mm,2mm)}]abcd.north east)--+(180:13mm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I searched the help from pdfmanual.pdf a long time, but I have not found the answer, what shoud I learn besides pdfmanual.pdf?

Comment: What's missing in `pgfmanual`? `-|` coordinate: [13.13.1 Intersections of perpendicular lines](http://texdoc.net/pkg/pgfmanual#page=137); `above left`: [17.5.3 Advanced Placement Options](http://texdoc.net/pkg/pgfmanual#page=229), `([shift={(x,y)}]...)`:[13 Specifying coordinates](http://texdoc.net/pkg/pgfmanual#page=130)

Comment: Everything you need is in `pgfmanual` but sometimes it's difficult to find it. My best suggestion would be to carefully read all introductory tutorials. You'll have a good starting point. Later on you can dive into other manual sections as you need it. You can find some other interesting references not far away: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84753/summary-of-tikz-commands/297085#297085, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15779/materials-for-learning-tikz

Comment: And this: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9116/what-is-the-minimum-one-needs-to-know-to-use-tikz