# Drawing with latex

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I'm writing my final year mathematics project in latex and am deriving Keplers laws of planetary motion, i need some diagrams to explain the geometry I am using. I have already used tikz to draw an the areas for Keplers second law, from a model i found online, I am not entirely sure how to use the program. Is there an book or online guide to help me draw the diagrams?
Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.sx. The [manual](http://texdoc.net/pkg/tikz) is the obvious thing to mention, it starts with several tutorials. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9116 and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15779 for some additional resources.

Answer (score 1):

It is too short as a comment. You can easily illustrate Keppler's second law (that implies  his first law as well) by using `pstricks-add`. The following screenshot shows the example taken from `pstricks-add` documentation.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This isn't TikZ, but a completely different option for drawing figures for LaTeX that I've found helpful is Ipe:

http://ipe7.sourceforge.net/

It is a stand-alone program, but you can use LaTeX code in its graphics. It might fit your needs well. Hope this helps!