# Typesetting Triangulations

Tags: lyx, diagrams

On page 49 of [these notes](http://www.cs.duke.edu/courses/fall06/cps296.1/Lectures/sec-III-1.pdf) appears the following diagram of a triangulation of a torus:

[image]

Noting I work in LyX,

1. Can anyone give code to reproduce this beautiful diagram?
2. Where can I learn how to make such diagrams?

***Added:***

I would also much like code that would generate the following diagrams:
[image]

Comment: Somehow related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9116 and http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/15779. This post appears a bit off topic, as it is not clear, what you want to have, where your problems are and what you have tried. There is no research effort in this 'question' and btw most of these graphs are already around this place. Please use the search-field in the upper right.

Comment: I'd start with the [TikZ manual](http://www.texample.net/media/pgf/builds/pgfmanualCVS2012-11-04.pdf). You may also want to visit [TeXample](http://www.texample.net/) for inspiration.

Comment: You could also use Asymptote or Metapost, or any tool that generates output in a form that can be included in LaTeX - which is more or less anything.  Both [Asymptote](http://asymptote.sourceforge.net/) and [Metapost](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107489/what-is-metapost-metafont-and-how-can-i-get-started-using-it) have good introductions.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a starter in [Metapost](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107489/what-is-metapost-metafont-and-how-can-i-get-started-using-it), showing you one way to organize a drawing with related sub-elements.

[image]

```
prologues := 3;
outputtemplate := "%j%c.eps";

beginfig(1);

picture t[], c;

z0 = origin;
z1 = 55 right rotated -5;
z2 = 60 right rotated 60;
z3 = 65 right rotated 20;

c = image(fill fullcircle scaled 3 withcolor background; draw fullcircle scaled 3;);
t1 = image(draw c shifted z1;);
t2 = image(
  draw z1--z2; 
  draw c shifted z1; 
  draw c shifted z2;
);
t3 = image(
  fill z0--z1--z2--cycle withcolor .9[red,white];
  draw z0--z1--z2--cycle;
  draw c shifted z0; 
  draw c shifted z1; 
  draw c shifted z2;
);
t4 = image(
  fill z0--z1--z2--cycle withcolor .9[red,white];
  fill z3--z1--z2--cycle withcolor .7[red,white];
  draw z0--z3 dashed withdots scaled .3 withcolor .7 white;
  draw z0--z1--z2--cycle; draw z1--z3--z2;
  draw c shifted z0; 
  draw c shifted z1; 
  draw c shifted z2;
  draw c shifted z3;
  );

for i=1 upto 4:
  draw t[i] shifted(80i-80,0);
endfor

endfig;
end.
```