# Defining vectors in TikZ through components

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have been trying to reproduce this image in tex, but I'd like to create it using $A_1$ and $A_2$ coordinates, but \def is not working.

Could anybody tell me the best way to do it?
[image]
thanks!

## EDIT 1

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [<->] (0,10) node[left] {$m_{2}$} -- (0,0) node[below left] {$0$} -- (10,0) node[below] {$m_{1}$};

    %\def{\vA1}{(3,4)}
    %\def{\vA2}{(5,2)}

    \draw[->, thick]     (0,0) -- ++ (3,4) node[below right] {$A_{1}$};
    \draw[shift={(0,4)}] (2pt,0pt) -- (-2pt,0pt)    node[left]  {$A_{1,1}$};
    \draw[shift={(3,0)}] (0pt,2pt) -- (0pt,-2pt)    node[below] {$A_{2,1}$};

    \draw[->, thick]     (0,0) -- ++ (5,2) node[below right] {$A_{2}$};
    \draw[shift={(0,2)}] (2pt,0pt) -- (-2pt,0pt)    node[left]  {$A_{1,2}$};
    \draw[shift={(5,0)}] (0pt,2pt) -- (0pt,-2pt)    node[below] {$A_{1,2}$};

    \draw [-, blue, thick] (5,10) -- (5,4) -- (10,4);
    \node[draw,circle,minimum size=1cm,inner sep=0pt, blue] at (9,9) {$\textbf{III}$};

    \draw [-, red, thick] (3,10) -- (3,4) -- (5,4) -- (5,2) -- (10,2);
    \node[draw,circle,minimum size=1cm,inner sep=0pt, red] at (4,9) {$\textbf{I}$};
    \node[draw,circle,minimum size=1cm,inner sep=0pt, red] at (9,3) {$\textbf{II}$};

    \draw [-, green, thick] (0,10) -- (0,4) -- (3,4);
    \draw [-, green, thick] (10,0) -- (5,0) -- (5,2);
    \node[draw,circle,minimum size=1cm,inner sep=0pt, green] at (1.5,9) {$\textbf{V}$};
    \node[draw,circle,minimum size=1cm,inner sep=0pt, green] at (9,1) {$\textbf{VI}$};

    \node[draw,circle,minimum size=1cm,inner sep=0pt, black] at (2.5,2) {$\textbf{IV}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Limiting random walk diagram}\label{figlimitingrw}
\end{figure}
```

In my code, most of the measures are direct functions of $A_1$ and $A_2$ coordinates. In the commented lines I tried to define the vectors, so I could use their coordinates as parameters for the illustration.

(I'm writing the document still, I know the color scheme is bad!)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have.  See [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Comment: And to add a slightly more human comment, there are lots of ways you could go about drawing this, but if you are having specific problems with some code, why not show us what you;ve got so far?

Comment: If you want to start learning Tikz, [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9116/what-is-the-minimum-one-needs-to-know-to-use-tikz) provides some starting points.

Comment: Dear @Thruston. Thank you for the manual, but this won't help me into this particular case. In fact, the question above was not about how to draw the image, but how to do it using the vectors coordinates as pameters.

Comment: Glad to hear you are quite OK in tex; perhaps you could edit your question to make it clear that you want some specific help on using vector coordinates?  An example of what you have done already is always useful for this.

Comment: Can you show us the code you have tried so far?  Coordinates in `tikz` are usually `(A1)` rather than `$A1$` and set via the `\coordinate` command.

Comment: Why you don't just use `\coordinate (A_1) at (0,0)` ?

Comment: @AndrewSwann, I post it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One example making use of a few defined coordinates and the `-|`/`|-` operators for defining coordinates and drawing lines.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=4mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\coordinate (A1) at (3,4);
\coordinate (A2) at (5,2);
\coordinate (O) at (0,0);
\coordinate (topleft) at (0,10);
\coordinate (botright) at (10,0);

    \draw [<->] (topleft) node[left] {$m_{2}$} -- (O) node[below left] {$0$} -- (botright) node[below] {$m_{1}$};

    \draw[->, thick]     (O) -- (A1) node[below right] {$A_{1}$};
    \draw[shift={(topleft|-A1)}] (2pt,0pt) -- (-2pt,0pt)    node[left]  {$A_{1,1}$};
    \draw[shift={(botright-|A1)}] (0pt,2pt) -- (0pt,-2pt)    node[below] {$A_{2,1}$};

    \draw[->, thick]     (O) -- (A2) node[below right] {$A_{2}$};
    \draw[shift={(A2-|topleft)}] (2pt,0pt) -- (-2pt,0pt)    node[left]  {$A_{1,2}$};
    \draw[shift={(A2|-botright)}] (0pt,2pt) -- (0pt,-2pt)    node[below] {$A_{2,2}$};

    \draw [blue, thick] (A2|-topleft) |- (A1-|botright);
    \node[draw,circle,minimum size=1cm,inner sep=0pt, blue] at (9,9) {$\textbf{III}$};

    \draw [red, thick] (A1|-topleft) |- (A2|-A1) |- (A2-|botright);
    \node[draw,circle,minimum size=1cm,inner sep=0pt, red] at (4,9) {$\textbf{I}$};
    \node[draw,circle,minimum size=1cm,inner sep=0pt, red] at (9,3) {$\textbf{II}$};

    \draw [green, thick] (topleft) |- (A1);
    \draw [green, thick] (botright) -| (A2);
    \node[draw,circle,minimum size=1cm,inner sep=0pt, green] at (1.5,9) {$\textbf{V}$};
    \node[draw,circle,minimum size=1cm,inner sep=0pt, green] at (9,1) {$\textbf{VI}$};
    \node[draw,circle,minimum size=1cm,inner sep=0pt, black] at (2.5,2) {$\textbf{IV}$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

For comparison, here is a version of the chart in [Metapost](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107489/what-is-metapost-metafont-and-how-can-i-get-started-using-it), where the two vectors are defined at the top, and everything else is positioned relative to them (which I think was the OP intention).  Notes below.

[image]

```
prologues := 3;
outputtemplate := "%j%c.eps";

beginfig(1);

z1 = (120,42);
z2 = ( 60,84);

path xx, yy;
xx = origin -- (3x1,0);
yy = origin -- (0,3y2);

drawoptions(withcolor .5 white);
draw xx;
draw yy;

drawoptions(withcolor .7 white);
draw xx shifted (0,y1) cutafter  yy shifted (x1,0) dashed withdots scaled 1/2;
draw xx shifted (0,y1) cutbefore yy shifted (x1,0);
draw xx shifted (0,y2);

draw yy shifted (x1,0);
draw yy shifted (x2,0) cutafter  xx shifted (0,y2) dashed withdots scaled 1/2;
draw yy shifted (x2,0) cutbefore xx shifted (0,y2);

drawoptions();
path a[];
a1 = origin -- z1;
a2 = origin -- z2;
drawarrow a1;
drawarrow a2;

draw btex $A_1$ etex shifted 4 up 
                     rotated angle direction 0.6 of a1 
                     shifted point 0.6 of a1;

draw btex $A_2$ etex shifted 4 up
                     rotated angle direction 0.6 of a2 
                     shifted point 0.6 of a2;

label.bot(btex $A_{1,1}$ etex, (x1,0));
label.bot(btex $A_{2,1}$ etex, (x2,0));
label.bot(btex $m_1$ etex, point 1 of xx);
label.lft(btex $A_{1,2}$ etex, (0,y1));
label.lft(btex $A_{2,2}$ etex, (0,y2));
label.lft(btex $m_2$ etex, point 1 of yy);

vardef do_region_label(expr s, p) = 
   draw superellipse(8 right, 6 up, 8 left, 6 down, 0.82) shifted p withcolor .67 blue;
   label(s,p) withcolor .67 blue;
enddef;

do_region_label("I",  ((x1+x2)/2, 2y2));
do_region_label("II", (2x1, (y1+y2)/2));
do_region_label("III",(2x1,2y2));
do_region_label("IV", 0.5[z1,z2]);
do_region_label("V",  (x2/2, 2y2));
do_region_label("VI", (2x1, y1/2));

endfig;
end.
```

### Notes

- Plain MP defines `z$` to be equivalent to `(x$,y$)`, where `$` is any valid suffix.  So when you define `z1 = (120,42)`, you create variables `x1` and `y1` which you can use independently.
- The units are PostScript points, but you can use others if you prefer.  So you could write `z1 = (5cm,2cm)`, and so on.
- Multiplication by a numeric constant is "implicit", so `3x1` means `3 * x1`.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `\coordinate` inside the Tikz picture. For example,

```
\coordinate (O)   at (0,0);
\coordinate (A_1) at (3,4);
\draw[->, thick]  (O) -- ++ (A_1) node[below right] {$A_{1}$};
```

Comment: How could I use this same form to add the value marker in the axis?

Comment: I've made an edit but I think i was wrong so rolled back. sorry for that

Comment: @GuilhermeThompson, I don't understand your question. Do you want to show the actual values rather than the symbols?

Comment: @percusse, no worries.

Comment: In this line, for instance, `\draw[shift={(0,4)}] (2pt,0pt) -- (-2pt,0pt)    node[left]  {$A_{1,1}$};`. How could I retrieve the values of A_1 to insert the marker into the axis?

Comment: Take a look at the **Let** operator to extract the values (page 153 ) http://www.texample.net/media/pgf/builds/pgfmanualCVS2012-11-04.pdf