# Is there a good and complete materials to learn tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have always found tikz difficult to learn. But now, I want to write my thesis and I need a good software for drawing. I am a complete beginner.

Do you know good materials to learn tikz?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Look at the answers here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15779/materials-for-learning-tikz

Comment: The manual has several tutorials. And it is big. Huge. It is tour best learning source.

Comment: I don't know if it's the best, but it's advised by the authors of pgf-tikz http://cremeronline.com/LaTeX/minimaltikz.pdf

Comment: Also this one: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9116/what-is-the-minimum-one-needs-to-know-to-use-tikz?noredirect=1&lq=1