# Which package is used for typesetting this? (theoretical computer science)

Tags: packages

With which package can I achieve the below picture?[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) With `tikz`.

Comment: @dexteritas Thanks! Do you happen to know whether there exists some tutorial on how to create things like in the picture? I see that one can do a lot with tikz.

Comment: It's mainly learning by doing. You can look for examples with source code on [texample](https://texample.net/tikz/examples/), the minimal introduction PDF and of couse the extensive documentation (it contains some tutorial sections) of the package on [ctan](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf).

Comment: You also can use `pstricks`, which  uses a latex syntax.

Comment: You can also use blox: https://ctan.org/pkg/blox

Comment: [documentation - What is the minimum one needs to know to use TikZ? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9116/what-is-the-minimum-one-needs-to-know-to-use-tikz)