# Where can I find a documentation for low-level tex conditionals like \if?

Tags: tex-core, conditionals, documentation

I want to understand low-level stuff like `\if` better. I'm not looking for some random examples off Google showing me some statements but a specification of some sort - something mean and unforgiving. But it's hard searching for the phrase "if" because it doesn't match what I'm looking for.

Note: I am not talking about `\ifthen`.

Comment: Have a look into Knuths TeXbook or Eijkhouts “TeX by Topic“. Both awesome books about how things work “under the hood”.

Comment: Special case of [macros - Where do I find out how a command/environment is defined? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4327/where-do-i-find-out-how-a-command-environment-is-defined/).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You should probably have a look at Chapter 20 of the *TeXBook* and at Chapter 13 of Eijkhout's book [TeX by Topic](http://mirror.ctan.org/info/texbytopic/TeXbyTopic.pdf). (The latter book is probably also included in your TeX distribution -- try typing "texdoc texbytopic".)

Answer (score 11):

Since you ask "where can I find ...", I believe that posting a link is a valid answer. I really like this page that explains all TeX primitives, with comments and examples:

http://www.tug.org/utilities/plain/cseq.html#Logic-fam

Answer (score 2):

As another quick reference I have used [Tralics](http://www-sop.inria.fr/marelle/tralics/) extensively. Although some of the commands do not appear in TeX it is of great help. Mainly due to its many low-level examples.

There are many examples. For instance for the `\edef` command:

> `\edef`
>
> You can say `\edef\foo{bar}`. The syntax is the same as `\def`, but the token list in the body is fully expanded (tokens that come from
>   `\the` are not expanded).
>
> You can put the prefix `\global` before `\edef`, note that `\xdef` is the same as `\global\edef`. In the example that follows, the `\ifx` is
>   true.
>
> ```
> {\catcode`\A=12 \catcode`\B=12\catcode`\R=12\gdef\fooval{ABAR}}
> {\escapechar=`\A \edef\foo{\string\BAR}\ifx\foo\fooval\else \uerror\fi}
> ```
>
> Another example is the following. The `\meaning` command returns a token list, of the form `macro:#1#2->OK OK`, and `\strip@prefix` removes
>   everything before the `>` sign. What we put in `\Bar` is a list of five
>   tokens, a space, and four letters of catcode 12.
>
> ```
> \makeatletter
> \def\strip@prefix#1>{}
> \def\foo#1#2{OK OK}
> \edef\Bar{\expandafter\strip@prefix\meaning\foo}
> ```
>
> For a non-trivial example, see [`\aftergroup`](http://www-sop.inria.fr/marelle/tralics/doc-a.html#cmd-aftergroup).