# Can I redefine a command to contain itself?

Tags: macros, patching

I'd like to "add to" an existing command by writing something like

```
\renewcommand{\somecommand}{\begin{something}\somecommand\end{something}}
```

but (not surprisingly) I get errors about being "too deeply nested".

Is there a way to take an existing command, add to it (by appending or prepending additional commands or text), and then have that "augmented" command replace the existing command?

Answer (score 159, accepted):

You can use `\let` to save a command under another name, and then use that new name in the `\renewcommand`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\let\oldemph\emph
\renewcommand{\emph}[1]{\textbf{\oldemph{#1}}}

\begin{document}
\oldemph{Old emph}
\emph{New emph}
\end{document}
```

(Edit: the [TeX FAQ](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-patch) has much more information about "patching" commands. Edit2: egreg's answer below describes some of the gotchas of `\let`)

Answer (score 132):

### Important update

The LaTeX kernel from the 2020-10-01 release has `\NewCommandCopy` that does the same job of `\LetLtxMacro` and better. It also provides `\ShowCommand` to obtain the internal definition also of robust commands. So the code below should now be

```
\NewCommandCopy{\oldemph}{\emph}
\renewcommand{\emph}[1]{\textbf{\oldemph{#1}}}
```

The analysis below about the problems with `\let` is still valid.

### Original answer

While something such as

```
\let\oldemph\emph
\renewcommand{\emph}[1]{\textbf{\oldemph{#1}}}
```

seems to work, it really doesn't, because `\emph` is defined with `\DeclareRobustCommand`. Where doesn't it work? suppose you write that code and then use `\emph` in a caption:

```
\caption{This is \emph{emphasized}}
```

what is written in the `.aux` file is

```
\@writefile{lof}{\contentsline {figure}{\numberline {1}{\ignorespaces This is \textbf  {\emph  {emphasized}}}}{1}}
```

This is because the original expansion of `\emph` is

```
\protect\emph§
```

(where with `§` I'm denoting a space in the name). So the `\emph{emphasized}` in the caption gets expanded successively into

```
\textbf{\oldemph{emphasized}}
\protect\textbf§{\protect\emph§{emphasized}}
\textbf§{\emph§{emphasized}
```

and written as

```
\textbf  {\emph  {emphasized}}
```

(because TeX adds a space after a command name when writing). In this case, when reading the file for building the List of Figures or Tables, TeX will find

```
\textbf{\textbf{\oldemph{emphasized}}}
```

which is innocuous. But it's not very difficult to imagine situations where this can lead to infinite loops.

The package `letltxmacro` prevents this problem:

```
\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\LetLtxMacro{\oldemph}{\emph}
\renewcommand{\emph}[1]{\textbf{\oldemph{#1}}}
```

would be a safer way to proceed.

***Never*** use `\let` on commands defined with `\DeclareRobustCommand` or commands defined with `\newcommand` and having an optional argument.

The former can be recognized by the fact that `\show\command` returns

```
> \command=macro:
->\protect \command  .
```

The latter are distinguished by the fact that `\show\command` returns

```
> \command=macro:
->\@protected@testopt \command \\command {...}.
```

(where `...` is actually the default for the optional argument).

Comment: Although you say "it's not very difficult to imagine situations where this can lead to infinite loops", it is a bit difficult to think of one MWE to make the infinite loop. Could you please offer one with some comments about how the loop is caused? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @zgc `\let\oribfseries\bfseries\DeclareRobustCommand\bfseries{\oribfseries\itshape}`

Comment: I wonder if there is a way to abstract this pattern with `NewCommandCopy` to a new command. Imagine I would like to redefine a couple of commands and not just one (e.g., to add a new textcolor to them or make them italic). Could we make a macro `\colorize{\llbracket}{blue}` that redefines `\llbracket` to be wrapped in `\textcolor` but so we do not have to spell out the two lines again and again? I tried something like `\expandafter\NewCommandCopy\csname old#1\endcsname{\csname #1\endcsname}` to generate the name for the old macro but it didn't work.

Comment: @PaulProgrammerNoob Yes, but using just `\NewCommandCopy` and similar commands is clumsy. You can make a new question. Leave a comment here when you do it.

Comment: @egreg Thank you. :) I posted a new question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/713699/command-to-renew-other-commands).

Answer (score 21):

Yes, this is possible using `\g@addto@macro` or some expanded definition (using `\expandafter`). Here are some examples:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}% Just for this example
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\somecmd}{some \textbf{text}}
\somecmd \par
\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\somecmd{ and some \textit{more} text}
\makeatother
\somecmd

\renewcommand{\somecmd}{some \textbf{text}}
\somecmd \par
\makeatletter
\expandafter\def\expandafter\somecmd\expandafter{\somecmd{} and some \textit{more} text}
\makeatother
\somecmd
\end{document}
```

The latter example, just like the former, appends contents to a macro. The placement of `\somecmd` in the latter could be used to prepend something.

However, nothing prevents you from making a new command that includes the old command as part of its expansion, since memory problems tend to be a thing of the past.

You run into problems when the contents of the newly-defined macro does not expand properly. Using your case as an example: although `\somecommand` may expand as expected, the `center` environment does not.

Comment: This answer is actually much better than the currently higher voted ones if one needs to add to the same macro more than once, in which case using a temporary variable will not work, unless new temporary variable names are used every time.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, you need to use the original name of the command, and you cannot use an environment because of some undesirable side effects. I have the case with `\LettrineFontHook` which is not directly called in my code. Here, the only solution I have found is to use `\let` to store and restore the command:

```
\let\tempLettrineFontHook\LettrineFontHook
\renewcommand{\LettrineFontHook}{\fontseries{bx}}
\lettrine{F}{}
\let\LettrineFontHook\tempLettrineFontHook
```

If I try to define an environment like this:

```
\newenvironment{boldLettrine}{%
\renewcommand{\LettrineFontHook}{\fontseries{bx}}%
}{}
% let's use this environment in the document now:
\begin{boldLettrine}
\lettrine{F}{}
\end{boldLettrine}
```

For reasons I ignore, the indentation of the lettrine is broken.

EDIT: From egreg remark, in your example, this method cannot apply since the new command is defined with the help of the original one, leading to possible infinite loops. So I cancel the application to your use case.

Comment: not that I follow like a detective all your moves but viz _For reasons I ignore, the indentation of the lettrine is broken._ : there must be a `\par`. Because the closing of the environment cleans up the `\parshape` set up by `lettrine package`. Please always post complete MWE rather than just a few lines of code. Apart from that this uses your own `\Lettrine` from some other question but should be with `\lettrine`. (but then one needs a second, possibly empty, argument `{}`)

Comment: In my answer I tell exactly why `\let\oldemph\emph` is to be avoided.

Comment: @egreg, in the case you detail, the copied command is used in the definition of the original one, what can makes infinite loops in the conditions you precise. I think it is not the case in my use case, but I should not have generalized.

Comment: @jfbu: you are welcome, I do appreciate your help. I can reword my post with only *lettrine*.

Comment: @lalebarde Follow `\lettrine{F}{}` by a `\par` before closing the environment if you want to get the indentation as expected. Did you notice that the original post dates back to `Mar 9 '12 at 5:31`?

Comment: Thanks *jfbu*. I did notice yes, but as far as I have understood stackexchange, it is also a knowledge & know-how repository.

Answer (score 1):

#### Append to a defined command

If you want to simply append something to a command after it, you can use the LaTeX kernel `\g@addto@macro`:

```
\def\authors{}
\def\addauthor#1{%
    \g@addto@macro\authors{
        \begin{tabular}[t]{c}%
            #1
        \end{tabular}%
    }
}
```

Then in the preamble you can:

```
\addauthor{Cristiano Ronaldo}
\addauthor{Lionel Messi}
```

The `\authors` will contain a printable list of authors that you can use in your `maketitle`, for example.

#### Append and Prepend to a defined command

I have not test it, but try:

```
\def\aroundto#1#2#3{\toks0={#2}\toks1=\expandafter{#1}\toks2={#3}\edef#1{\the\toks0 \the\toks1 \the\toks2}}
```

**References**: both solutions were found in [The Hacks blog](http://texhacks.blogspot.com/2009/09/appending-to-macro.html).