# Redefine a built-in math command

Tags: math-mode, macros

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I redefine a command to contain itself?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47351/can-i-redefine-a-command-to-contain-itself)

I'm trying to redefine the `\int` command so that it will always do `\int \!`. So here's my attempt at that:

```
\renewcommand{\int}{\int \!}
```

But then I'd get this error:

```
\! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].
\int ->\int
```

On the other hand, I looked up `\show\int`, which got me `\intop \nolimits .` So I tried to use it in a `\renewcommand`:

```
\renewcommand{\int}{\intop \nolimits . foobarbaz}
% The foobarbaz is for testing if the \renewcommand is effective
```

But no, I don't see `foobarbaz` in the output.

How do I redefine math commands?

Answer (score 10):

Make a copy of the old command using `\let`, then use the copy to create the new command.

```
\let\oldint\int
\renewcommand\int{\oldint\!}
```