# Align numerator of fraction to the center

Tags: math-mode, amsmath

Following LaTeX displays the numerator to the left. **Question**: How can we align the numerator (just like the denominator is) to the center:

```
\frac{\pi^2}{6}
```

**Display of the above LaTeX**:

[image]

I tried [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/84245/22810) suggestion from `@DavidCarlisle` for another scenario - and it (as asked by the OP there) displays the denominator to the left that makes both numerator and denominator look aligned to the left. But, in my case, I would like the numerator to be aligned to the center (with the denominator).

```
\frac{\pi^2}{6\hfill}
```

**Display of the above LaTeX**:

[image]

**Desired output:**

[image]

Comment: numerator and denominator are centred `\pi^2` is wider than `\pi`, if you want a `^2` that has no width then `\pi\rlap{^2}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle On MikTex, `$$\frac{\pi\rlap{^2}}{6}$$` giving error: `! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.8 $$\frac{\pi\rlap{^2}}{6}
                            $$`

Comment: Use `\mathrlap` and place the `^` before it.  Also (off topic), use `\[...\]` rather than `$$`.  (The fraction line may be too narrow.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton `\[\frac{\pi^{\mathrlap{2}}}{6}\]` gives error: `! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \pi ^{\mathrlap{2}}
l.6 \[\frac{\pi^{\mathrlap{2}}}{6}  \]`

Comment: I failed to mention that `\mathrlap` requires `mathtools`.  But the third example in @Werner's answer looks better anyhow.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thank you for pointing it out. After using `mathtools` package, I tested your suggestion - and it worked, as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some options:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\[
  \frac{\pi^2}{6} \quad % Default
  \frac{\hphantom{^2}\pi^2}{6} \quad % Symmetric exponent around \pi
  \frac{\!\hphantom{^2}\pi^2\!}{6} % Reduced horizontal width of numerator
\]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `\!` at the end of the numerator. Sometimes we need to correct the math spacing to get visually better results. For example:

```
{\pi^2\! \over 6}, \quad \Gamma\!_2.
```

Answer (score 1):

To get a zero-width ², you'll want to define

```
\newcommand\zwe[1]{\rlap{${}^{#1}$}}

\[
  \frac{\pi\zwe{2}}{6}
\]
```

although this will have the superscript extending beyond the fraction bar. An alternative definition for `\zwe` would be to take both the base and exponent as arguments and use an `\hphantom` on the left to balance the superscript on the right:

```
\newcommand\zwe[2]{\hphantom{{}^{#2}}#1^{#2}}

\[
  \frac{\zwe{\pi}{2}}{6}
\]
```