# Left-align the date for all cvitems

Tags: macros, horizontal-alignment, moderncv

All contents (mostly dates) of the first argument of `\cvitem` should left-align in Austria - as explained to me in the career center. I want to redefine the command `\cvitem` (like in [Can I redefine a command to contain itself?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47351/can-i-redefine-a-command-to-contain-itself)).

```
\let\oldcvitem\cvitem
\renewcommand*{\cvitem}[3][]{\oldcvitem}
```

My MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

\let\oldcvitem\cvitem%
\renewcommand*{\cvitem}[3][]{\oldcvitem[#1]{\flushright{#2}}{#3}}%

\moderncvstyle{casual}
\firstname{First}
\familyname{Last}

\begin{document}
 \section{Some examples}
 \cvitem{Year}{Entry}
 \cvitem{2001--2013}{I am a dark knight}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @jon: I thought the first argument #1 is by default the optional argument!? I am aware that '\cvitem' by default takes two arguments and an optional one. But it did not solve my problem.

Comment: OK, I looked into it.  The problem is that each CV item sets its own `tabular`, which kind of reminds me of bad HTML.  I'd be inclined to skip the whole thing and write a new command using `\parbox`....

Comment: That would be brilliant if you could write your idea more explicit, as I do not exactly know how you would implement this command by using '\parbox'. Is it really so robust in the sense of arrangement and alignment?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A MWE for `moderncv` requires adding the choice of `\moderncvstyle`, `\firstname` and `\familyname`.

The easiest way to tweak `\cvitem` is to copy its definition from one of the moderncvstyle files:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

\moderncvstyle{casual}
\firstname{First}
\familyname{Last}

\renewcommand*{\cvitem}[3][.25em]{%
 \begin{tabular}{|@{}p{\hintscolumnwidth}|@{\hspace{\separatorcolumnwidth}}|p{\maincolumnwidth}@{}|}%
    \raggedleft\hintstyle{#2} &{#3}%
  \end{tabular}%
  \par\addvspace{#1}}

\begin{document}
\makecvtitle
 \cvitem{Year}{Entry}
\end{document}
```

I have added some bars to the `tabular` environment, to make it clear how each `\cvitem` is typeset.

[image]

From here you can either customise the `tabular` environment or it entries. 
I'm not sure I understood exactly what your requirements are, but you can left-align the year by removing `\raggedleft` from the tabular entries.

[image]

**Edit:**

In the version above, the year column is clearly too wide (`0.15\textwidth`). The width of the column may be controlled using `\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{width}`.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

\moderncvstyle{casual}
\firstname{First}
\familyname{Last}

\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{0.1\textwidth}
\renewcommand*{\cvitem}[3][.25em]{%
 \begin{tabular}{@{}p{\hintscolumnwidth}@{\hspace{\separatorcolumnwidth}}p{\maincolumnwidth}@{}}%
    \hintstyle{#2} &{#3}%
  \end{tabular}%
  \par\addvspace{#1}}

\begin{document}

\makecvtitle
\cvitem{Year}{Entry}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

First, I would like to point out that @Pedro's answer works just fine as long as you remove the `\raggedleft` from the re-definition (so +1).  However, I find the way `\addvspace` used in `moderncv` rather unintuitive, so if I were to mimic what the class does with `\parbox`-es, I'd do it a little differently.  Example:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}% to show a \parbox in use

\moderncvstyle{casual}
\firstname{First}
\familyname{Last}

% Create our lengths
\newlength\boxsize
\newlength\boxgap
% Set them to current moderncv lengths
\setlength{\boxsize}{0.175\textwidth}% == maincolumnwidth
\setlength{\boxgap}{0.025\textwidth} % == separatorcolumnwidth

\newcommand\mycvitem[3][0.25em]{%
  \strut%  I prefer \strut; but it will be trumped by a
  % sufficiently large value for #1 (default of 0.25em is from
  % moderncv).  In fact, I'd get rid of it entirely, since you use #1
  % to set the space that *follows* the entry, which I find counter-intuitive
  \parbox{\boxsize}{#2}%
  \hspace{\boxgap}%
  \parbox[t]{\dimexpr\textwidth-\boxsize-\boxgap\relax}{#3}
  \par\addvspace{#1}%
}

\newcommand\mynewcvitem[3][0.25em]{%
  \addvspace{#1}%
  \strut%  \strut can still be trumped, and we're keeping the default 
        %  value just for fun; but now at least the space is added in
        %  a way that, to me, makes more sense
  \parbox[t]{\boxsize}{#2}%
  \hspace{\boxgap}%
  \parbox[t]{\dimexpr\textwidth-\boxsize-\boxgap\relax}{#3}%
  \par
}
% ... but really, I'd probably get rid of the optional argument entirely

\begin{document}
\makecvtitle

\section{Original}%   <-- for comparison
 \cvitem{Year}{Entry}
 \cvitem{Year}{Entry}
 \cvitem{Year}{Entry}

\section{Some examples}
 \mycvitem[1cm]{Year}{\lipsum[2]}%                          <-- N.B.: #1 affects what follows
 \mycvitem{2001--2013}{I am a dark knight}
 \mycvitem{2001--2013}{No, I am a dark knight}
 \mynewcvitem[1.5cm]{2001--2013}{I, too, am a dark knight}% <-- N.B. #1 affects what precedes
 \mynewcvitem{2001--2013}{Who cares?}

\section{A New Section}% <-- Just to give a sense of the spacing

\end{document}
```

**Edit.** If you want instead to have a flexible size for the size of the 'year' box, what you could do is the following:

```
% command to set \boxsize; must be a valid length
\newcommand{\setboxsize[1]{\setlength{\boxsize}{#1}}

% now we set the default \boxsize to moderncv's 0.175\textwidth, 
% but allow it to be reset as an optional argument
\newcommand\revisedcvitem[3][0.175\textwidth]{%
  \setlength{\boxsize}{#1}%
  \strut
  \parbox[t]{\boxsize}{#2}%
  \hspace{\boxgap}%
  \parbox[t]{\dimexpr\textwidth-\boxsize-\boxgap\relax}{#3}%
  \par
}
```

Then use it like so:

```
\revisedcvitem[1cm]{Year}{\lipsum[2]}
\revisedcvitem{2001--2013}{I am a dark knight}
\revisedcvitem{2001--2013}{No, I am a dark knight}
\revisedcvitem[2.5cm]{2001--2013}{I, too, am a dark knight}
\revisedcvitem{2001--2013}{Who cares?}
```

Or you can set it for a whole suite of \revisedcvitem's like so:

```
\boxwidth{2.5cm}% set \boxsize to 2.5cm
\revisedcvitem{Year}{\lipsum[2]}
\revisedcvitem{2001--2013}{I am a dark knight}
\revisedcvitem{2001--2013}{No, I am a dark knight}
\revisedcvitem{2001--2013}{I, too, am a dark knight}
\revisedcvitem{2001--2013}{Who cares?}
```

Comment: On the first catch, it looks fine. But my doubt was confirmed on the closer view: The contents "Year" and "Entry" (in second section) are not vertically aligned (position) anymore in contrast to the original (first section). `\addvspace` is nice but I don't need it for this purpose. The optional argument should change the width for the "year" box.

Comment: @strpeter -- That's because I forgot a `[t]` in the first `\parbox`.  I think a flexible 'width' that has to be controlled by the the optional argument would be very annoying to use: if you have ten items, you'd need to write it each time; but there is a way to fix that.