# How to see which package define a particular command/macro?

Tags: macros

We often encounter multiple definitions of certain commands/macros. Then, we often get the error, e.g.:
! LaTeX Error: Command \P already defined.
               Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H   for immediate help.
 ...

l.225 \newcommand{\P}{{\mathcal P}}

When we get such an error, is there anyway to know which package or file predefined that particular command/macro?  I'm talking about general cases, not the particular case of '\P' listed above.
It is quite cumbersome if we have to go through all possible files via 'grep' manually. I hope that there's a way to see which file already defined the command that produces the conflict/error.

Thanks a lot!

BVP

Comment: grep is your friend, sorry:-)

Comment: For people (like me) who come here later: `\P` is the command to get the paragraph symbol.

Answer (score 16):

You can add

```
\show\P
```

to your document as in

```
 \show\P
\documentclass{article}
 \show\P
\usepackage{graphics}
 \show\P
\usepackage{foo}
 \show\P
\usepackage{bar}
 \show\P
\begin{document}
 \show\P
```

This will make the TeX stop and show the definition of `\P` at each step, if it is already defined in the format the first one will show the definition, otherwise it will show undefined until the package that defines it is loaded. (The definition might be delayed with `\AtBeginDocument` which is why I put the final `\show` at that point.

Comment: When I did `\show\vref`, I get:

`> \vref=macro:` \
`->\protect \vref  .` \
`l.234 \show\vref`

Is there a solution to seeing the underlying definition?

Comment: `\ShowCommand` (if you have a recent latex) @Gus

Comment: According to https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/47372/1362 , it needs to be "The LaTeX kernel from the 2020-10-01". Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The command-line utility [`latexdef`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/texdef) shows not only the definition, but also the location of the definition.

For example, I wanted to see the definition of `\url` in my document. To be sure, this is not defined by default:

```sh
$latexdef --find \url

\url:
undefined

$
```

but it is defined by `hyperref`:

```sh
$latexdef --package hyperref --find \url
\url first defined in "/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty".

\url:
macro:->\protect \url

\url  first defined in "/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty".

\url :
macro:->\hyper@normalise \url@

$
```

and that package is loaded by some document classes:

```sh
$latexdef --class tufte-book --find \url
\url first defined in "/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty".

\url:
macro:->\protect \url

\url  first defined in "/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty".

\url :
macro:->\hyper@normalise \url@

$
```

See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/17840/1362

Comment: wow! this is amazingly useful.

Comment: How do you use this in a document?  I don't understand if you're doing command line how do you get what a command is in the middle of running a tex file?

Comment: @HaoS, this answer doesn't address that use case, as far as I can tell.