# How to re-define \space using \space in its definition

Tags: macros, patching

I am trying to implement a counter that counts the white spaces in order to give a rough estimate of the number of words contained in a paragraph.

In order to do so, I set a new counter

```
\newcounter{spacenumber}
```

and I would like for it to step forward every time a `\space` command is invoked.

Looking at [`@egreg`'s answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47351/can-i-redefine-a-command-to-contain-itself#answer-47372) in this post: [Can I redefine a command to contain itself?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47351/can-i-redefine-a-command-to-contain-itself), I wrote

```
\LetLtxMacro{\oldspace}{\space}
\renewcommand{\space}{\oldspace%
  \stepcounter{spacenumber}
}
```

but it doesn't work so far.

Here is the complete code:

```
\documentclass{article}% it does NOT work

\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\newcounter{spacenumber}
\LetLtxMacro{\oldspace}{\space}
\renewcommand{\space}{\oldspace%
  \stepcounter{spacenumber}%
}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{spacenumber}{0}
This is an example. \thespacenumber
\end{document}
```

I took a look at the `etoolbox` package, but I still didn't find an answer because I don't know how `\space` is defined. In fact, I get

```
> \space=macro:
-> .
```

The question is: Am I wrong about the whole counter setup or am I wrong about how `\space` has to be re-defined?

Comment: Just note that you don't need `\space`, just don't comment the end of line after `\def\space{`. You are calling `\space` zero times. If you want to call `\space` on each space, you need something like `\obeyspaces`.

Comment: @Manuel: Could you please be a little more clear? I don't understand the `\def\space{` part...

Comment: A space in input does not execute `\space`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{spacenumber}
{\catcode`\ =\active\relax\gdef {\space\stepcounter{spacenumber}}}

\begin{document}
\begingroup
\setcounter{spacenumber}{0}
\obeyspaces%
This is an example. \thespacenumber
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

As egreg says, a space doesn't call `\space` command, so in your example the number of `spacenumber` is obviously zero. If you want the spaces to call `\space` you need `\obeyspaces` (to be used carefully).

Comment: Redefining `\space` is useless, since `\obeyspaces` uses the *old* definition of `\space` (it's done via a `\let =\space`). So you need to redefine the space itself rather than `\space`. By the way, this should be used carefully, so the best would be to make it only work inside an environment.

Comment: Thanks! Works like a charm. I have a question, though: in the first version of the answer you didn't use `\begingroup`, `\obeyspaces` and `\endgroup` but it still worked. Why the change?

Comment: @PierPaolo I forgot a closing brace. If I added the missing closing brace, you need `\obeyspaces`. However, since I think it's not “safe” to use `\obeyspaces` freely, I used it inside a group, so outside that group, spaces work as usual.