# Hyphens in mathmode

Tags: math-mode

Whenever I write a hyphenated word inside `\mathit` or `\mathbf` or whatever ...

```
\mathit{long-variable-name}
```

... I *always* intend for the hyphens to be hyphens, not minus signs. There is a webpage giving several workarounds for this (http://www.logic.at/staff/salzer/etc/mhyphen/), but I would like a proper solution where I don't have to write monstrosities like

```
\mathit{long\mhyphen{}variable\myhyphen{}name}
```

My vision is to redefine the `\mathit` command (and its cousins) so that when `-` appears in its argument, it is automatically replaced with whatever command is necessary to produce a hyphen.

- Is this possible?
- Might doing so cause problems? I mean, do people ever put a whole *formula* inside `\mathit`? ('Cause then you *would* want the `-` to produce a minus.)

Comment: Is the text and math fonts different in your document?, because then I'd just use `\textit`. BTW: long function names should be typeset upright not italic.

Comment: @daleif Thanks, I've changed it from 'function-name' to 'variable-name'. Yeah, my document (regrettably) uses different fonts for math and non-math.

Comment: @JohnWickerson -- what's regrettable about using different fonts for math and non-math?  having different fonts allows a one-letter variable *a* to be distinguishable from the article "a" in an italicized theorem (english; other possibilities in other languages).

Comment: Heh, I thought that might be contentious! I dislike having different fonts for math and non-math, mainly because I think `{rm,it,tt,sf,sl,bf}x{math/nonmath}` is just too many fonts to have in one document. (And I'm never sure whether to write $42$ or just 42; if it's the same font then I don't have to worry!)

Answer (score 7):

You can use `\newmcodes@` from `amsopn`, which is used for `\operatorname`. I would not redefine `\mathit` and similar commands.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % actually amsopn

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\varname}[1]{\begingroup\newmcodes@\mathit{#1}\endgroup}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
$\varname{long-variable-name}-\varname{short}=0$
\end{document}
```

[image]

You *could* change the meaning of `\mathit`, but I strongly advise you not to:

```
\usepackage{letltxmacro,amsmath}

\LetLtxMacro\ORImathit\mathit
\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\mathit}{%
  \begingroup\newmcodes@\ORImathit{#1}\endgroup
}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Super, thanks. I'll just add that if anyone *did* want to go ahead and meddle with `\mathit` despite your advice, they should write `\makeatletter` 
`\let\oldmathit\mathit` 
`\renewcommand\mathit[1]{\begingroup\newmcodes@\oldmathit{#1}\endgroup}` `\makeatother`

Comment: Note, that the first version of @egreg's solution didn't solve the protecting of `\varname` from `\write` too.

Comment: @egreg You are not precisely right. Try my solution with TOC without protecting. The line includes somethig like: `...${\mathcode `-=`- \mathit{var-name}}$...` in the `.toc` file and this is readable again without problems. It means: my solution needs not protecting because it is very simple based on primitives. Simplicity is power. And now, try the solution from your first version with `\varname` in the title. The `.toc` line includes garbage and the sedond run crashes. And crash all consecutive runs until somebody remove `.toc` file.

Comment: @wipet I can't understand what you're after. I showed you that `\let\mathitori=\mathit` is wrong (it is notwithstanding the fact that one test makes it work) and changed my answer to protect `\varname` because I realized the problem. Simplicity is *not* power: writing ``\mathcode`-=`-`` in the `.aux` file doesn't seem the best idea and, if you think about it, you'll get *two* of these assignments in the `.toc` file and you'll do *three* of them when typesetting the TOC.

Comment: @egreg The `\let\mathitori=\mathit` isn't wrong if the user exactly knows what happens and how TeX works inside. And believe me: I know about it.

Comment: @wipet No, I don't think that in this case you know enough. Doing `\let` with a command defined with `\DeclareRobustCommand` is always wrong.

Comment: @egreg Doing `\let` with a command `\matit` isn't _always_ wrong. The contradiction is my example below. It works. My first intervention about "you are not precisely right" was about the fact that there isn't infinite loop. Only twice setting of the same `\matcode`. And I _know_ about this, because the new name declared by `\let` expands to the original name during `\write` (this is one of the bad concept of LaTeX).

Answer (score 4):

The typesetting of all characters in math mode depends on `\mathcode` of such character. You can simply re-set mathcode of `-`.

```
\let\mathitori=\mathit
\def\mathit#1{{\mathcode`-=`- \mathitori{#1}}}
```

Comment: Thanks wipet. The extra `{`...`}` in your `\def` -- is that the same as egreg's `\begingroup`...`\endgroup`?

Comment: Yes, we create variable as Ord math object, this means `{...}`. Moreover this localizes the `\mathcode` setting. If you dislike this, you can type ``\def\mathit#1{\mathitori{\mathcode`-=`- #1}}`` because the argument of `\mathit` is typeset in the group.

Comment: It's exactly what `\newmcodes@` does, but it changes also other mathcodes (closing quote `'`, asterisk `*`, period `.`, slash `/` and colon `:`). Note also that `\let\orimathit\mathit` is quite dangerous if `\mathit` gets in a `\protected@write`, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/47372/4427

Comment: @egreg The question was about hyphen only. I did show how TeX works inside by mentioning the `\mathcode` primitive. And I didn't use any `@` in control sequences. Of course, protecting from `\write` is implemented in LaTeX no very ideal, so I didn't solve this. I have much better `\write` protecting in my OPmac, for example:)

Comment: @JohnWickerson If you really needs to use `\mathit` in `\chapter/\section` parameters then you can replace `\def\mathit...` by `\protected\def\mathit...`. The `\protected` primitive is from eTeX.