# Shorter line for math-mode?

Tags: math-mode

I have

```
$A-V$
```

but the line "-" is shown too long:

[image]

I would like to have shorter line.

How can you have a shorter line there in the math-mode?

Comment: Is it not a minus sign? Load `amsmath` and use `$A\text{ - }V$`

Comment: `$A{-}V$` will reduce the spacing, while `$A\mbox{-}V$` will change the font and therefore not set `-` as a minus.

Comment: Do you want `\textit{A-V}`?

Comment: `$A$\nobreakdash-$V$` (requires `amsmath`). Or `$A\text{-}V$`, but it's wrong to begin with.

Comment: Related:  [Hyphens in mathmode](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/196526/21053)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A hyphen in math mode is interpreted as a minus sign. If you mean to have a variable named *A-V* in math mode, with a hyphen in between, you need to define a “math hyphen” or resort to `$A\text{-}V$`.

For defining a math hyphen you can do

```
\DeclareMathSymbol{\mh}{\mathord}{operators}{`\-}
```

Full example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareMathSymbol{\mh}{\mathord}{operators}{`\-}

\begin{document}

$A\mh V$

$A\text{-}V$

\end{document}
```

[image]

The first option, with `\mh` (or the name you prefer), is better.

Of course, if this is not a variable, but you're referring to two variables in some text, the correct input would be

```
$A$\nobreakdash-$V$
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I love "\mh", very convenient!