# How to set default footnote linespacing?

Tags: header-footer, line-spacing

How to set default footnote linespacing? Now for each footnote I have to write

```
\footnote{\onehalfspacing ...}
```

But I would like to set the line spacing once.

I guess its possible to use `\renewcommand{\footnote}{...}`. But I don't know how to redefine the command.

Comment: All packages that make line spacing changes easy take care, that this does not happen in footnotes. There is good reason for that. Are you sure, you want to alter this?

Comment: @Johannes_B Yes, I am sure, because this is a strange requirement for documents in my university.

Comment: So, the simplest solution would be to *not* use package `setspace` and change it by hand for the whole and complete document. Depending on the pointsize, you can set in the preamble `\setstretch{1.25}` (10pt), `1,213` for 11pt or `1.241` for 12pt basesize.

Comment: @Johannes_B But ```\setstretch``` command is imported from ```setspace``` package. I am defining document class, so it would be best to set default footnote line spacing in it, not in the main document.

Comment: I thought this might be a declaration for the whole document. University specs are very strange, just as if they never noticed that typewritters have gone. Try [Can I redefine a command to contain itself?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/47351)

Comment: @Johannes_B Thank you! I used this solution: ```\let\oldfootnote\footnote``` ```\renewcommand{\footnote}[1]{\oldfootnote{\onehalfspacing #1}}```. Works like a charm (:

Comment: I provided an answer and marked it as duplicate. This makes it easier for others to find similar solutions with better explanations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something very similar to [Can I redefine a command to contain itself?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/47372/37907)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\begin{document}
\blindtext
\footnote{\blindtext}
\LetLtxMacro{\niekasFootnote}{\footnote}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\footnote}[1]{\niekasFootnote{\def\baselinestretch{1.25}\@currsize#1}}
\makeatother
\footnote{\blindtext}
\end{document}
```

[image: niekasFootnote]

As you will place that in a class file, the `\makeatletter` `\makeatother` combo can be omitted. The definition comes form the source of package `setspace`. If this package is loaded anyways, you can use `onehalfspacing` (or any other of the spacing comands defined by `setspace`). Advantage: Those commands are aware of the current font size, since different sizes need different spacing to *look right*.

Comment: Why do you need ```\@currsize```? Omitting it does not require ```\makeatletter``` and ```\makeatother``` commands anymore.

Comment: @niekas That is the originaldefinition in `setspace`. If you load setspace anyway, you can savely use `onehalfspacing` which is aware of the type size