# Patching a command with an optional argument or declared with \DeclareRobustCommand

Tags: macros, document-classes, optional-arguments, patching

To re-define a command to contain itself (*patching* in TeX parlance) you usually use `\let`. [This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/47372/65924) by @egreg says:

> **Never** use `\let` on commands defined with `\DeclareRobustCommand` or commands defined with `\newcommand` and having an optional argument.

So a natural question is what *should* we do in such cases?

For example, how do I re-define `\bibitem` to add another command after it? This:

```
\let\old@bibitem\bibitem
\def\bibitem{\old@bibitem\it}
```

does not work, and \show\bibitem shows why:

```
> \bibitem=macro:
->\@ifnextchar [\@lbibitem \@bibitem .
```

What should I do to achieve the effect?

I would prefer not to use packages such as `xpatch` because I am modifying a class which others will use, and I try to use as few pacages as possible to minimize possible conflicts.

Comment: In this case find the source and reuse it.

Comment: \LetLtxMacro from the package with the same name

Comment: @touhami Do you mean I should use `show` and copy the modified contens? In this case, I should modify `\@lbibitem` and `\@bibitem`, right? This is not robust as to future changes or may not be compatible with other packages, no?

Comment: If you want robust patching, use one of the packages for that (`etoolbox`, `xpatch`, `letltxmacro`, etc.). In my view it is foolish to make a class load `tcolorbox` (say, which is a great package), but not so when it is a utility/programming package. Such utility packages are likely already getting loaded behind the scenes anyway (`letltxmacro` loads `etoolbox`, e.g.; so do many other packages nowadays). On the other hand, you seem to be asking for "high-level" and "generic" solutions for a very "general" question; in some ways these are in conflict with one another.

Comment: You simply have to go deeper into the definitions; if the aim is to print the citation label in italics, patching `\bibitem` is surely the wrong choice independently of any package you may load.

Comment: yes you need to change `\@lbibitem` and `\@bibitem` or as @egreg said you need to go deeper into the definitions. this is safe but ... using packages is faster, cleaner,...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The command `\bibitem` has *no* argument, much less an optional one. The commands I refer to in the quoted part of my answer are those defined with

```
\newcommand{<macro>}[<args>][<default>]{...}
```

not others defined in an indirect way with `\@ifnextchar` or `\@ifstar` like `\bibitem` or `\section`.

If your aim is to print the citation label in italics, patching `\bibitem` is the wrong choice independently of any package such as `etoolbox`, `xpatch` or `letltxmacro` you load.

What could you do? Let's see: `\bibitem` has the definition you showed, so we know we have to patch either `\@lbibitem` or `\@bibitem`.

Using `texdef` we see

```
> texdef -t latex -s @lbibitem
% latex.ltx, line 6228:
\def\@lbibitem[#1]#2{\item[\@biblabel{#1}\hfill]\if@filesw
      {\let\protect\noexpand
       \immediate
       \write\@auxout{\string\bibcite{#2}{#1}}}\fi\ignorespaces}

> texdef -t latex -s @bibitem
% latex.ltx, line 6232:
\def\@bibitem#1{\item\if@filesw \immediate\write\@auxout
       {\string\bibcite{#1}{\the\value{\@listctr}}}\fi\ignorespaces}
```

Well. There are two cases: if `\bibitem` is followed by `[`, we need to see how `\@biblabel` is defined and we see

```
> texdef -t latex -s @biblabel
% latex.ltx, line 6278:
\def\@biblabel#1{[#1]}
```

so we just need to do

```
\def\@biblabel#1{[\textit{#1}]}
```

If there is no optional argument, we need to see how the standard label of the `enumerate` environment started with `\begin{thebibliography}` is defined. Very well:

```
> texdef -t latex -s thebibliography
% article.cls, line 575:
\newenvironment{thebibliography}[1]
     {\section*{\refname}%
      \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\refname}{\MakeUppercase\refname}%
      \list{\@biblabel{\@arabic\c@enumiv}}%
           {\settowidth\labelwidth{\@biblabel{#1}}%
            \leftmargin\labelwidth
            \advance\leftmargin\labelsep
            \@openbib@code
            \usecounter{enumiv}%
            \let\p@enumiv\@empty
            \renewcommand\theenumiv{\@arabic\c@enumiv}}%
      \sloppy
      \clubpenalty4000
      \@clubpenalty \clubpenalty
      \widowpenalty4000%
      \sfcode`\.\@m}
     {\def\@noitemerr
       {\@latex@warning{Empty `thebibliography' environment}}%
      \endlist}
```

Hmm, this depends on the class; let's assume the class is `article`. Fine! The label is still printed using `\@biblabel`, so the above trick is good in both cases.

So your task is just adding

```
\def\@biblabel#1{[\textit{#1}]}
```

to your personal style file; if the patch must be done in the document preamble, ensure to add the line between `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` (see [What do \makeatletter and \makeatother do?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8351/what-do-makeatletter-and-makeatother-do)). However this might depend on the class, but usually one can count on the fact that `\@biblabel` is what's to be changed.

No, patching commands is definitely not easy.

Comment: Thank you! By now I've solved my problem in a less elegant (but trivial) way. My intention was, roughly (not exactly) to print references, but *not* labels and not the word "References", in grey color, so a trivial idea was to redefine `\bibitem[x]{y}` as `\color{black}\bibitem[x]{y}\color{gray}`, and yes, I was looking for an easy and generic way. What I learnt from your answer is that it is considered valid to rely on how a command is defined -- when you say "it depends on the class" -- because there is no easy and generic way.