# unicode-math and redefine a built-in math command

Tags: macros, luatex, unicode-math

I'm trying to redefine a math command (let's say `\int`) so that it will always do more (let's say `\int lol`) using the following trick: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/47353/15659

**BUT**, now I want to use the package `unicode-math` in LuaLaTeX and it don't work any more.

---

Minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{unicode-math}

\let\oldint\int
\renewcommand\int{\oldint lol}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\mathbf{B}\left(P\right)=\frac{\mu_0}{4\pi}\int\frac{\mathbf{I}\times\hat{r}'}{r'^2}dl
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\AtBeginDocument{\let\oldint\int\renewcommand\int{\oldint lol}}` should work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For technical reasons, much of the work of `unicode-math` related to defining the meaning of symbols is performed at begin document. In particular, `\int` is among the symbols defined there. So use

```
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \let\oldint\int
  \renewcommand\int{\oldint lol}%
}
```