# How to save a command before modifying it?

Tags: macros

If a command \commandA exists, and I do

```
\newcommand{\commandB}{}
\let\commandB\commandA
*a redefinition of \commandA*
```

the modification on `\commandA` also affects `\commandB`. But I would like to save "the original command A" as commandB.

How can I do that?

Comment: As long as `\let\commandB\commandA` occurs before the redefinition of `\commandA`, then the original definition of `\commandA` is saved in `\commandB`

Comment: The order of statements is important... Storing should occur very early, in most cases

Comment: With `\let\commandB\commandA`, the meaning of `\commandB` does not depend on later modifications of `\commandA`.

Comment: Thank you all. I now understand that my problem comes from the *a redefinition of \commandA* part.

Comment: See also. [macros - Can I redefine a command to contain itself? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47351/can-i-redefine-a-command-to-contain-itself) for some updates. e.g. the introduction of `\NewCommandCopy` command etc.

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps this analogy will help to understand why one should use `\let\commandB\commandA` before `\renewcommand{\commandA}{...}`.

If a file should be kept before accidentally modifying (deleting?) it, it should be stored to some other place or copied to another name, so a `cp -a fileA fileB` (with Un*x commands) is making the copy of the original file and naming it `fileB`. For a short while both files do exist and are identical.

Now `fileA` can be edited etc.

The same is true for `\let...`, but `\let` is **not** like a pointer in the `C` programming language, pointing to the same memory location or like a symlink in the file system.

1. First safe the definition of `\commandA` to some other name, say `\commandB` with

   ```
   \let\commandB\commandA
   ```

This will be done immediately, i.e. `\commandB` has the same definition like `\commandA` and will do the same operation like `\commandA`.

2. Now do the eventual change of `\commandA` with `\renewcommand{\commandA}{...}` or `\def` etc.

This is a technique applied very often, in order to extent the definition of `\commandA` (i.e. before or after its code) to use its definition inside the redefinition, i.e. call `\commandB` to get the original effect.

Please note that for commands with optional arguments `\LetLtxMacro` from the `letltxmacro` package by Heiko Oberdiek should be used, not `\let`.

`expl3` on the other hand provides `\cs_set_eq:NN` etc. commands.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the [phfnote](https://ctan.org/pkg/phfnote?lang=en) package. I'm going to show how to do with all of the [escaped character codes](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Special_Characters) such as the cedilla `\c`, some of which take arguments. In the preamble, use

```
\usepackage[preset=reset]{phfnote}
```

Before redefining anything, save all of the old commands:

```
\phfnoteSaveDefs{origcmds}{H,c,k,l,b,d,r,aa,u,v,t,o}
```

Then you are free to define them as you wish. Right before you need to use the old versions, write

```
\phfnoteRestoreDefs{origcmds}
```