# Can this summation and zeta be created in LaTeX?

Tags: fonts

[image]

Can the above `\zeta` and `\sum` symbol be produced exactly in latex? If yes what package to use? Kindly help.

Thanks.

EDIT: This is not a duplicate. I am looking for a math typeface which gives summation symbol exactly as show in the image above.

Comment: What have you tried? What have you got? Why is this tagged `pdftex`? Is it really engine specific?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to look up a symbol or identify a math symbol or character?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-symbol-or-identify-a-math-symbol-or-character)

Comment: Try the `newtxmath` package. (Couple it with the `newtxtext` package.) Its glyphs for `\zeta` and `\sum` come pretty close to those in the screenshot you posted.

Comment: @Mico I said that in the comment. But the summation symbol appears too large over there. Any idea how to make it exactly appear like the one show here?

Comment: If you think this is not a duplicate, can you clarify what you mean by "exactly as shown"? Can you mention in the question that you've tried some other font, and what you found wrong with the symbols you got from that font?

Comment: @S.C. - Sorry to have wasted your time. I had no idea you were so picky about the *size* of the `\sum` symbol. (The symbol's shape is OK, though, right?)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. With your reputation you should know you should provide a MWE.
2. Why are you asking how `\zeta` and `\sum` symbols can be reproduced in LaTeX, if you already know their name?

If this code doesn't solve your problem, please edit your question and be more specific:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\begin{document}
\[
-\frac{{\zeta}^{\prime}(s)}{\zeta(s)} = \sum_{m\geq 1}\frac{\Lambda(n)}{{n}^{s}}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

*Edit:*

As Mico said, this is the result with `newtxmath` package:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{newtxmath}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\mysum}{\text{\raisebox{-2pt}{\scalebox{2}{$\Sigma$}}}}
\begin{document}
    \[
    -\frac{{\zeta}^{\prime}(s)}{\zeta(s)} = \sum_{m\geq 1}\frac{\Lambda(n)}{{n}^{s}}
    \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Eventually, you could create your own math operator.

*Second edit*

As you correctly pointed out, my first solution (`\mysum`) doesn't become smaller when it was not in display style.

I have created another command (`\mynewsum`) that scales according to the size of the `\sum` operator.

If you prefer my first solution for display style, you can use a mix of the previous two (see `\myfinesum`).

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{3}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\mysum}{\raisebox{-2pt}{\scalebox{2}{$\Sigma$}}}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\mynewsum}{\scalerel*{\Sigma}{\sum}}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\myfinesum}{%
\mathchoice
  {\raisebox{-2pt}{\scalebox{2}{$\Sigma$}}}%
  {\scalerel*{\Sigma}{\sum}}%
  {\scalerel*{\Sigma}{\sum}}%
  {\scalerel*{\Sigma}{\sum}}
}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabular}{l>{$\displaystyle}c<{$}>{$\textstyle}c<{$}>{$\scriptstyle}c<{$}>{$\scriptscriptstyle}c<{$}}
\toprule
&
\text{Display style}
&
\text{Text style}
&
\textstyle\text{Script style}
&
\textstyle\text{Scriptscript style}
\\[10pt]
\midrule
\textbackslash\texttt{mysum}
&
-\frac{{\zeta}^{\prime}(s)}{\zeta(s)} = \mysum_{m\geq 1}\frac{\Lambda(n)}{{n}^{s}}
&
-\frac{{\zeta}^{\prime}(s)}{\zeta(s)} = \mysum_{m\geq 1}\frac{\Lambda(n)}{{n}^{s}}
&
-\frac{{\zeta}^{\prime}(s)}{\zeta(s)} = \mysum_{m\geq 1}\frac{\Lambda(n)}{{n}^{s}}
&
-\frac{{\zeta}^{\prime}(s)}{\zeta(s)} = \mysum_{m\geq 1}\frac{\Lambda(n)}{{n}^{s}}
\\[10pt]
\textbackslash\texttt{mynewsum}
&
-\frac{{\zeta}^{\prime}(s)}{\zeta(s)} = \mynewsum_{m\geq 1}\frac{\Lambda(n)}{{n}^{s}}
&
-\frac{{\zeta}^{\prime}(s)}{\zeta(s)} = \mynewsum_{m\geq 1}\frac{\Lambda(n)}{{n}^{s}}
&
-\frac{{\zeta}^{\prime}(s)}{\zeta(s)} = \mynewsum_{m\geq 1}\frac{\Lambda(n)}{{n}^{s}}
&
-\frac{{\zeta}^{\prime}(s)}{\zeta(s)} = \mynewsum_{m\geq 1}\frac{\Lambda(n)}{{n}^{s}}
\\[10pt]
\textbackslash\texttt{myfinesum}
&
-\frac{{\zeta}^{\prime}(s)}{\zeta(s)} = \myfinesum_{m\geq 1}\frac{\Lambda(n)}{{n}^{s}}
&
-\frac{{\zeta}^{\prime}(s)}{\zeta(s)} = \myfinesum_{m\geq 1}\frac{\Lambda(n)}{{n}^{s}}
&
-\frac{{\zeta}^{\prime}(s)}{\zeta(s)} = \myfinesum_{m\geq 1}\frac{\Lambda(n)}{{n}^{s}}
&
-\frac{{\zeta}^{\prime}(s)}{\zeta(s)} = \myfinesum_{m\geq 1}\frac{\Lambda(n)}{{n}^{s}}
\\[10pt]
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Oops. How to make sure that this "sum" symbol only appears like this only in the displaymath mode? (that is the $$ $$ mode). Because if i use this command in the normal mode where i want "sum" to appear small, it doesn't happen :(

Comment: @S.C. You're right, I have to improve my answer, but please wait because I have no time at the moment... Maybe someone else will answer before me...

Comment: Em, thanks for taking time and helping. I too thought of the same idea, but each time i don't use displaymath, i have to change the command from \mysum to \mynewsum :( This looks a bit hard :)

Comment: @S.C. No, you can simply use `\myfinesum` everywhere, please look at this command in my last edit.

Comment: BTW, after defining `\myfinesum` when i give the command `\renewcommand{\sum}{\myfinesum}` why does it show an error?

Comment: @S.C. You can't redefine `\sum` with a command which uses `\sum`. You have to save the old `\sum` under another name and then use this name in `\renewcommand`, see here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/47351/101651.