# marginpar text alignment

Tags: horizontal-alignment, marginpar

I'm currently using the book class and I'm using `marginpar` to cite sources. I would like the marginpar on right pages to be aligned left and the marginpar on left pages to be aligned right. Is there any way to do this?

Note I cannot use marginnote due to a package incompatibility.

[image]

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book}
\usepackage[paperheight=5in,paperwidth=6in,top=.7in,bottom=.7in, inner=1in, outer=2in, marginparsep=.1in, headsep=16pt]{geometry}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\marginpar{This is the outside margin. I would like it to be aligned left (as it is).}\lipsum[1] 

\clearpage

\marginpar{This is also the outside margin. I would like it to be aligned right}\lipsum[2] 

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This automates [Ben Stern's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/417264/105447) using the KOMA Script test `\ifthispageodd` (through `scrextend` given the use of the `book` class) and defining an `\alignedmarginpar` which aligns right on left pages.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book}
\usepackage[paperheight=5in,paperwidth=6in,top=.7in,bottom=.7in, inner=1in,
 outer=2in, marginparsep=.1in, headsep=16pt]{geometry}

\usepackage{scrextend}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\alignedmarginpar}[1]{%
    \ifthispageodd{%
        \marginpar{\raggedright\small #1}}{%
        \marginpar{\raggedleft\small #1}}%
    }

\begin{document}

\alignedmarginpar{This is the outside margin. I would like it to be aligned left (as it is).}\lipsum[1]

\clearpage

\alignedmarginpar{This is also the outside margin. I would like it to be aligned right.}\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: It should be ragged on both sides, isn't?

Comment: @Sigur, that's not what I understood from the OP. The text of the two marginpars suggests the alternation of the alignment is the desired result. If your reading is correct, the last comment I left for BenStern was undeserved.

Comment: Ragged, but to different directions. OP wrote *would like the marginpar on right pages to be aligned left and the marginpar on left pages to be aligned right.* So, the result should be one opposite to the other. So use `\raggedright`.

Comment: @Sigur Aligned doesn't mean ragged necessarily. The OP states on the even page note "I would like it to be aligned left (as it is)". Indeed there is no way to justify the text and align it right. I'm inclined to agree with you that `\raggedright` on the other side would be more elegant. Given these considerations, do you think this is the proper reading of the OP? (if so, I'll gladly edit).

Comment: Well, let's wait the OP comments. But in my opinion makes more sense to have symmetric outputs, so ragged right/left.

Comment: @Sigur, I did agree with you it would be more elegant! :) (I'll edit, you are right it is a "bonus" even if not asked for).

Comment: @Sigur, our symmetry yearnings are satisfied now.

Comment: I'd use a small font, since the width is not too big, just to see how pretty it is: `\raggedright\small #1`. Also, it is more visible the ragged in this case.

Comment: This is great, but @Mr Tsjolder has provided a much simpler solution below.

Answer (score 6):

There is an optional argument to `\marginpar` that allows to specify the left-side text. This allows to create the `\alignedmarginpar` solution from [gusbrs' answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/417276/67448) without the need for additional packages:

```latex
\newcommand{\alignedmarginpar}[1]{%
    \marginpar[\raggedleft #1]{\raggedright #1}%
}
```

Comment: This is brilliant, and should be the accepted answer. (I tried it, it works!)

Comment: What if `sidenotes` uses the `\marginpar` command? How can I tell it to use the new command?

Comment: @Atcold If you want to overwrite the `\marginpar` command, you could use `\renewcommand` instead (see e.g. [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47351/can-i-redefine-a-command-to-contain-itself)).

Answer (score 2):

Put a `\raggedleft` right before your `\marginpar` text.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book}
\usepackage[paperheight=5in,paperwidth=6in,top=.7in,bottom=.7in, inner=1in,
  outer=2in, marginparsep=.1in, headsep=16pt]{geometry}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\marginpar{This is the outside margin. I would like it to be aligned left (as it
  is).}\lipsum[1]

\clearpage

\marginpar{\raggedleft This is also the outside margin. I would like it to be
  aligned right}\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image: demo of latex output]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! This does indeed achieve the result for this particular marginpar, but it requires that you know which side the marginpar will be beforehand and is all too manual in this respect. And somewhat error prone. Still, a welcome +1.

Comment: Revising, those are fair criticisms.

Comment: I appreciate your well intended revision. But now, you have all marginpars raggedleft. On both even and odd pages, which explicitly is not what the original post asked for. Your original answer was partial, but went in the intended direction. The revision now leaves your answer as not solving the problem asked for. Have you taken a look at the answer I left automating your initial proposal?

Comment: My mistake, I somehow confused myself.  Reverting.  Thank you.
I was trying to figure out a solution that didn't need another package, but I think you're right that this needs more automation.

Answer (score 1):

To complement @gusbrs and @egreg's excellent answers, should you want to replicate the behavior of `\marginpar[inner margin text]{outer margin text}` which allows to typeset a different text depending on the margin in use (for `twoside`d documents), you could also go with the following definition using the `xparse` package,

```latex
\documentclass[twoside]{book}
\usepackage[paperheight=5in,paperwidth=6in,top=.7in,bottom=.7in, inner=1in, outer=2in, marginparsep=.1in, headsep=16pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\raggedmarginpar}{ O{#2} m }{%
    \marginpar[\raggedleft#1]{\raggedright#2}%
}

\begin{document}

\raggedmarginpar{This is the outside margin. I would like it to be aligned left (as it is).}\lipsum[1]

\clearpage

\raggedmarginpar{This is also the outside margin. I would like it to be aligned right}\lipsum[2]

\clearpage

\raggedmarginpar[Points towards main text.~$\Rightarrow$]{$\Leftarrow$~Points towards main text.}\lipsum[3]

\clearpage

\raggedmarginpar[Points towards main text.~$\Rightarrow$]{$\Leftarrow$~Points towards main text.}\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

[image: Third page]
[image: Fourth page]