# Change colour of italics font for the whole document

Tags: fonts, color, default

I would like to see the following in my latex file: once I use the `\textit{...}` command, I would like to see that this text does not only get the italics font, but also gets the colour blue. I want to apply this on the whole document. Instead of having to specify it for every part of text that should get this font, is there a way I can specify it in the beginning of the document such that it is applied to the whole doc? Basically I want to change the default properties of the `\textit{...}` command.

Comment: Well you can. But it would be better to define a semantic command, e.g. \myemph which sets its argument in italic and blue and to use this than to redefine \textit.

Comment: In case you really, really want to redefine `\textit` which I strongly advise against, see: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47351/can-i-redefine-a-command-to-contain-itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very easy with (Xe|Lua)LaTeX:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}[
  ItalicFeatures={Color=blue},
]

\begin{document}

Some text \emph{emphasized} and \textit{in italic}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

With `pdflatex` it's a bit more complicated:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\itshape}{%
  \not@math@alphabet\itshape\mathit
  \fontshape\itdefault\selectfont
  \color{blue}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Some text \emph{emphasized} and \textit{in italic}.

\end{document}
```

Be careful of not using `\itshape` between paragraphs, though.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a command, called `\coloremph`, which builds on the `\emph` to allow the emphasized material to be rendered in a color. The default color is `blue`, but that this may be overridden by providing a different color in the optional argument of `\coloremph`.

With this setup, any "inner" emphasized material will be rendered in the upright font shape, but with the color of the surrounding emphasized material. Uncomment the directive

```
%\renewcommand\eminnershape{\upshape\color{black}} % optional
```

if you want the inner emphasized material to be typeset in black.

Here's the full MWE (minimum working example):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,svgnames,x11names]{xcolor} % for lots of predefined color names
\newcommand\coloremph[2][blue]{\textcolor{#1}{\emph{#2}}}
%\renewcommand\eminnershape{\upshape\color{black}} % optional

\begin{document}
Hello, World.

\coloremph{Once upon a \emph{very strange} time, \dots}

\coloremph[Coral3]{Once upon a \emph{very strange} time, \dots}

\coloremph[MediumPurple]{Once upon a \emph{very strange} time, \dots}

Hello World.
\end{document}
```