# Changing italic color

Tags: fonts, color, italic

I would like to change the color of italic throughout a document. This problem was solved here

[Change colour of italics font for the whole document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/416066/change-colour-of-italics-font-for-the-whole-document)

It appears the solution for pdflatex does not work anymore in TeX Live 2020. The code below does not work on my system. Does anyone know how to fix this

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\itshape}{%
  \not@math@alphabet\itshape\mathit
  \fontshape\itdefault\selectfont
  \color{blue}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Some text in \textit{blue}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\let\oldtextit\textit 
\renewcommand\textit[1]{\oldtextit{\color{blue}#1}}
\begin{document}
Some text in \textit{blue}
\end{document}
```

You have `\oldtextit` in case you need colorless italics.

If you want the result with `\itshape`, add the following line in the preamble, after the packages:

```
\let\olditshape\itshape 
\def\itshape{\color{blue}\olditshape}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this does not appear to affect anything written with `\itshape`such as references generated with bibtex.

Comment: I've edited my answer so it works with `\itshape`. See again.

Comment: Yeah, I also tried this. But this does not appear to work with bibtex.

Comment: Maybe a more specific example of what you want would be helpful.

Comment: Hm, specific in which way? I would like all text that is in italic to be typeset in blue. Your solution works for all text that I put in italic with `\textit`, but does not appear to work for text in italic that is generated by some other means, such as a reference generated with bibtex or the text in a mathematical theorem written with the amsthm package.

Comment: `\documentclass{amsart}
 \usepackage{amsthm}
 \newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]

\usepackage{xcolor}
\let\oldtextit\textit 
\renewcommand\textit[1]{\oldtextit{\color{blue}#1}}
\let\olditshape\itshape 
\def\itshape{\color{blue}\olditshape}

\begin{document}
Some text in \textit{blue}
\begin{thm}
Some mathematical theorem ... 
\end{thm}
\end{document}`

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to edit the above comment correctly. On my system the text in the Theorem is in italic, but not in blue.