# How to get \nameref{} to be displayed in small caps?

Tags: cross-referencing, cleveref, small-caps, nameref

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}

% PACKAGES LOADING

\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath, mathtools, amsthm, mathrsfs, amssymb}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed} 

% THEOREM DEFINITION

\newtheoremstyle{mystyle0}{0}{}{\itshape \setlength\parindent{0pt}}{}{\scshape}{}{ }{\thmname{#1} \thmnumber{#2}.\thmnote{#3}}
\theoremstyle{mystyle0}

\newmdtheoremenv[skipabove=20pt,skipbelow=10pt,innerleftmargin=0.0cm,innerrightmargin=0.0cm,innertopmargin=0.0cm,innerbottommargin=0.0cm,backgroundcolor=White!10,linecolor=Black!60,linewidth=0.5mm,hidealllines=true,nobreak=false,roundcorner=2.5pt,startinnercode={\deffootnotemark{}\deffootnote{0pt}{0pt}{}}]{theorem}{Theorem}[]

% REFERENCES SETTINGS

\usepackage[colorlinks=true,urlcolor=blue,linkcolor=black]{hyperref}
\usepackage[capitalise,noabbrev]{cleveref}
\hypersetup{allcolors=Blue}

% DOCUMENT

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}[A Fancy Theorem Title]\label{theorem1}
    A fancy theorem.
\end{theorem}

The following expression, in blue, \nameref{theorem1}, should appear in small caps.
 
\end{document}
```

**I would like `\nameref{}` to match the style of the theorem name (i.e., it should display the theorem name in small caps).** I have tried adding `\renewcommand{\nameref}{\scshape{\nameref}}` and similar commands but none of them worked. As you can see in the picture below, the output is in small caps.

[image]

Thank you all very much for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/420501/error-redefining-nameref-using-let). I just need to include this in the preamble:

```
\AtBeginDocument{
  \let\namerefOld\nameref
  \renewcommand{\nameref}[1]{\textsc{\namerefOld{#1}}}
}
```