# Problem with unicode-math and renewcommand

Tags: unicode-math

Dear Stackexchange users,

I want to write my thesis with lualatex and as I'm using lualatex I want to use to packages build around it. But I stumpled upon a strange effect: I wanted to redefine the partial-Operator to be upright.
So I wrote a renewcommand-line. But if I try to compile the following document

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\AtBeginDocument{\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}

\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\partial}{\symup{\partial}}}

\begin{document}

$\partial \symup{\partial}$

\end{document}
```

I get the following eror

```
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].
```

and there is no output pdf produced. Has anyone any idea why this happens?

Regards Jakob

PS: The \AtBeginDocument has to be infront of the renewcommand as otherwise the renewcommand does not have any effect. The explanation for this behaviour is (see [explanation](https://github.com/wspr/unicode-math/issues/463):

```
unicode-math waits until \begin{document} to setup the default font and the default definitions.
```

Comment: `\AtBeginDocument{\let\oldpartial\partial\renewcommand{\partial}{\symup{\oldpartial}}}`

Comment: `\renewcommand{\partial}{...\partial ...}` is defining an infinite loop.

Comment: Macro redefinitions that include the macro itself in the definition need to be made with the `\let\old...` trick, because otherwise TeX ends up in an infinite loop. `\renewcommand{\partial}{\symup{\partial}}` tells TeX to replace every occurrence of `\partial` with `\symup{\partial}`. But then there is a new `\partial` and so that is replaced with `\symup{\partial}`, etc, etc. See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/47351/35864

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. I'll keep that in mind for future documents.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to renewcommand the command. unicode-math has an option to change the symbol:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\unimathsetup {partial=upright}

\begin{document}

$\partial \symup{\partial}$

\end{document}
```

[image]